# What should the table stakes for a question to be asked on Stack Overflow be?

Tags: discussion, questions

The renewed vigor in "finding ourselves" has led me question some of the principles I've always thought Stack Overflow "was".  The recent backlash against homework questions, "beginner" questions, and questions that don't show any research are some examples of recent community discussion.

Our unspoken rules have varied slightly throughout the years, but one of them has been that as long as a question adds value to the corpus of programming knowledge (even if only through its answer) it is "welcome"<sup>1</sup>.

This implies value, but you won't see that on Stack Overflow's help page -- it's implicit.  One of those things that we can't point to, but we all assume is there.  Sort of like a donut hole, if you're the philosophical type.

That got me to thinking, what are the table stakes for a question to be asked on Stack Overflow?  What are the minimum things we expect out of a question that gets asked? What *should* be the minimum expectations on our end?

The following are what I believe (from being around the community) to be our minimum requirements for questions; and how they dovetail into the tenets of Stack Overflow:

1. Questions should be written so that they have value for future visitors. If a question isn't likely to be searched for (because of how it's written), it should be edited or closed
2. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum; it's a Q&A site. There are a whole subset of programming related topics that aren't suitable for our format (example: List of X, "What's your favorite", "translate this for me", "[C# vs Java](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)")

3. All information needed to solve a problem should be contained in the question itself
4. If you don't understand your question well enough to articulate the problem you're facing, you're not yet at the point where you should be asking about it on Stack Overflow (example: Massive code dump followed by "Any suggestions?")
5. Questions should be focused around a single topic
6. Questions should be about a practical, articulable problem a person faces (we don't have a close reason for this)

**What do you think? What should our minimum requirements for questions be? What are we missing?**

### Why I am asking

I ask because currently, **we have no close reason for #1 (no value to others) or #2 (discussion-based)** -- our close reasons don't shut down all opinion based questions, just those that aren't backed up by experience or expertise (even though we tend not to allow the latter, we don't have any close-reason justification for it).

For #3 (self-contained problem), #4 (minimal understanding), and #5 (single-topic focus), we have close reasons that cover some of that ground; but not only are they not enforced consistently; they are actively ignored by higher reputation users. A close reason is only as good as its enforcement.

<sup>1</sup>: "stays open", downvotes are another matter.

Comment: `That got me to thinking, what are the table stakes for a question to be asked on Stack Overflow? What are the minimum things we expect out of a question that gets asked? What should be the minimum expectations on our end?` I thought [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages already cover this pretty well. Do you disagree?

Comment: [Is it possible to apply CSS to half of a character?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23569441/456814) got upvoted to high-heaven due to ***popularity***, but as some people around here say, popularity doesn't necessarily imply quality. In a previous life, I would have downvoted the question for not demonstrating any attempted solutions (with actual code), and since the asker invited suggestions, [I said as much](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character#comment36307787_23569441).

Comment: Honestly everything is summed up for me as: "have you run a few queries through google first?" The internet is a far different place than it was five years ago, in no small part thanks to the vast archive of very good SO Q+A threads. It continually surprises me how *bad* of a query I can throw at google and still have my exact answer returned in the form of an SO thread. So like you say, questions that add value to the corpus of programming knowledge are great, but we (and by extension, google) have covered the hell out of the "easy stuff" at this point.

Comment: Dovetail question?: [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770/456814).

Comment: *"For #3,#4, and #5, we have close reasons that cover some of that ground; but not only are they not enforced consistently; they are actively ignored by higher reputation users. "* Which close reasons are you talking about here and how do you know that they are ignored by high-rep users? Overall I think you pretty much nailed it with that list (from my POV).

Comment: Pretty sure #2 #3 #4 and maybe #5 were addressed by WSOiN answers, but /shrug. Everything old is new aagain. The Wheel of Time turns.

Comment: For anyone curious about what "WSOiN" is: "[What Stack Overflow is Not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139317/163250)".

Comment: #4 is, I think, a central point in the differences of opinion between those who want an _archive_ and those who want to _mentor_. I don't think it's accepted even close to universally as a question requirement. "Unclear what you're asking" and "too broad" both address it somewhat, but they are, as you say, far from consistently enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Was writing a question and I decided, it was *sort of* a duplicate of this question.  Maybe.  There are no answers and 33 upvotes on this one, so perhaps it is worth providing my "answer" in light of my "considerations" (vs. opening a rhetorical question with my own answer on a similar topic).

But I'd like to talk about something that's perhaps not discussed so much.  What about an expert in some language(s)--who is in a situation of trying to do some kind of thing with a language they don't take very seriously <sub>*(coughJavaScriptcough)*</sub>.  This person has no problem articulating themselves, but has a deliberately narrow scope of interest.  Despite being more articulate than the average homework asker... at the end of the question the punchline is still "gimme teh c0dez" situation.

Briefly:

> What's the difference in "gimme teh c0dez" when it comes from a savvy person who places an arbitrary limit on their interest in the subject, vs. a homework asker who does the same thing?

By my nature, I don't sit around thinking I can't figure something out if I spent enough time.  If I read the spec, if I studied the code, if I looked at it...I could understand the whole thing.  In a less exaggerated sense than students who don't want to do their homework, I'm saying the same thing: *"help me, lazyweb, because I don't want to reverse-engineer the universe to get from A to B"*.

Before I ultimately got all dramatic and griped to the fake-Internet-powers-that-be for a meta effect, I was getting downvoted for [what I thought was a legitimate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858171/are-there-semicolon-insertion-dangers-with-continuing-operators-on-next-line).  *(Now artificially upvoted; it's not any epic question, it just didn't deserve to be -6 in the negative, IMO.)*

But it was marked as a duplicate of something that was essentially "go read the spec for automatic semicolon insertion, there you will find the answer".  I wrote back:

> No, that's not my question. One is allowed to ask a question where the implications of a specification are wondered about. If not, then many-if-not-most C and C++ questions are a duplicate of Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents

I thought a bit about the downvotes, though, and about perhaps the challenge people might feel in answering such a question directly.  Let's imagine for a second that JavaScript is not a blight on human technological civilization that you only touch when circumstances force you to.  Imagine you think that explaining the nuances of JavaScript semicolon insertion is teaching a man to fish vs. feeding him for a day.  **Then my question sucks**, because I am a parallel to the homework asker...if I only get that *one* thing right I'm asking about, then I will miss the bigger picture and may never truly master JavaScript.

So that's why I related to the "what are the stakes" question.  What if I don't care about truly mastering JavaScript and just want that answer?  How does one judge questions and a stubbornness about wanting "this answer" vs. learning "the bigger picture"?  Is it okay to ask about one issue?

My bias is perhaps going to be obvious because I think my question was fine.  I think asking people to translate the spec to answer it is fine--vs. me having to internalize the spec and all of its implications.

Will I ever be a JavaScript master?  No.  Do I ever want to become one?  No; I'm a C++ person *(who got a serious re-education the last years by studying and participating in the rapid and educational butt-kicking of the fanatics on this site; which could and should be friendlier)*...and I'm messing with Haskell right now, while dabbling in Rebol and Red for the last couple of years.  I'm waiting for actual programming to come back in style.  I probably hate JavaScript as much as kids hate homework.

I'm sure this must bug JavaScript monks--the most likely to know the answer to something I might ask about.  I'd be bugged if I was trying to correct an issue and someone said "no, I just need to do this one thing".  The homework tag was eliminated based on the idea that a question can be judged in a vacuum; what I ask is "can the questioner set limits on their interest in learning".

My answer is yes; that the table stakes can be set as part of the question as how it's framed.  One is not required to understand the entirety of a system or its specification.  As much as it may bug those with an educational bent, *the stakes are the question itself*.  Not your future in programming, not what potential problems you may hit in the future.

(You may of course remark on those issues.  *"If you don't consider X, you will likely wind up lost."*  But still, an answer to the question is the answer that answers the question.  End tautology moment.)

Comment: (Why is a +0.5 vote not possible?) Does prior experience in other languages mean you can ask on what turn out to be minor typo errors? Minimal understanding? "No research effort"? Posts and comment discussions ending with "Just give me the answer man!" are (or, IMO, *should*) *heavily* downvoted, because they do not show an intent to *learn*. For your topical question, your "deliberately narrow scope of interest" is actually not appropriate for a site ".. for professional and enthusiast programmers". (Only 88 characters left--I feel I could re-write this somewhat less negative sounding- too lo