# Should rep-hunter answers be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, voting

I have occasionally downvoted an answer when I was frustrated that a high-rep user (who knew his stuff, obviously) had taken the time to answer a basic, obvious duplicate, rather than find a similar question to mark it as a duplicate of.

I'm feeling divided here. On one hand,

- the consensus certainly seems to be that reputation addicts are causing harm to the site
- mumble something, poetic justice?

On the other,

- helping hapless newbies is somehow noble
- finding suitable duplicates is **too damn hard** and I couldn't blame somebody who tried to find a dupe, but gave up
- mumble something, jealousy?

I hope the community can guide me and perhaps develop some sort of consensus on this practice. If enough of us downvote "quick and dirty" replies, maybe some of them will stop?

Comment: And I meant to DV as the other post: [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459) but I keep forgetting the dupe vote dialog needs to first resolve the link after a copy-paste before I hit 'vote'.

Comment: Keep in mind that "enough" needs to be more than 83% of users, otherwise the posts have a negative score, but a positive reputation change.

Comment: Hmm, but I think the rep-whoring aspect brings something new to the table.

Comment: How do you know that is it rep-whoring? I suppose that if you take your time to find a near enough duplicate and see that an answerer did not search, or you think they didn't search because you think that the near duplicate is good enough and they should have found it too you can vote however you wish.

Comment: Can I state that I absolutely hate the term "rep-whoring"? It's insulting and far too often I'm seeing it be used to attack well-meaning users.

Comment: @BradLarson - I'd agree.  I do think there is problem behavior trigged by the quest for reputation, but it comes more from the awarding rep for potentially destructive (or at least annoying) actions like edits.  Unless it's plagiarized or pointlessly duplicates an existing one, an answer should be judged on its utility and accuracy.

Comment: I apologize for the term; I avoided using it in the question but I've seen it used here a lot so it slipped into the comment.

Comment: I see a recurring pattern with a particular user in one of the tags I follow.  He answers within a minute or two with working code for common FAQs but often tailored to the particular question (but then often also not particularly well tailored).

Comment: So the real question here is really, have I read too much into the recent discussions here about attempts to limit this sort of behavior?

Comment: For the record, I do not downvote unless the question clearly shows no attempt at googling first.

Answer (score 5):

If it's really *that* obvious that it's a duplicate question just vote to close. Downvoting should signal a bad answer or bad question, not a duplicate.

Due keep in mind, there's clearly a bunch of ways to ask the same question but use different terminology. Sometimes this is due to the immaturity of the developer asking and others it is due to a different frame of reference. Different terminology will be found by different people and sometimes viewed as a different question altogether even if conceptually they are not.

As an example, we might talk of mixins in the Python definition of what it means to be a mixin. Likewise, we might talk of multiple inheritance in the OO sense in Python (for it does support it.) Technically, both can be refering to the same thing and thus be the same exact question. However, you might get different results and different answers because of how it was phrased.

Comment: Hmmm, since the effort to find a duplicate is at least on par with posting an answer to a simple question, should points be awarded for that as well?  That could modify the rep-hunter behavior significantly, if indeed that is truly the motivation for the person who answers.