# Person downvoted every post on a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I answered a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728681/opengl-lwjgl-is-jmonkey-for-me/24732143#24732143. A few minutes later, I got a downvote.

Now fine, I got a downvote, that is okay with me if someone thinks it is a low-quality answer. However, what annoys me is that the person appears to have downvoted every single post in that question, including the question itself (I had already upvoted the question) (and all the answers).

maybe that person did just think that they were bad quality, however is that sort of thing allowed - Just randomly downvoting every single post in a question?

Obviously, I cannot be sure it is the same person, however I would have thought it was since it would be unlikely that three seperate people would just happen to have each done one downvote on just one post in a question.

So, I guess what I am asking is what should be done about such things, if anything?

Comment: Hoping the serial votings reversal algorithm kicks in? Upvote a bit yourself? Flagging for moderator attention?

Comment: @Trilarion No idea if that is the correct sort of thing to do, which is why I am asking here.

I would not want to abuse the system or waste moderator time if it did not warrant it.

Comment: The question is off-topic as OP has no specific problem but just vaguely asks if it's ok if he starts using jmonkey now. The correct response from you would have been to ignore it or flag it (as you can't closevote yet) as either primarily opinion based or too broad. Someone probably downvoted everyone as the question and all of the answers are not useful to the community - which is a legitimate downvote reason, and I agree with it in this instance. As it got you to stop and think about the situation, I'd say it worked. Try not to answer off-topic questions from now on...

Comment: Have you seen, the question is now on hold on because of "opinion based". Did you know that some people here strongly discourage answering question that are perceived as bad question. They even go so far as downvote good answers to bad questions. While asking on meta about reasons is in principle the right thing you'll risk even more downvotes.

Comment: @i4mpi I will keep answering "off-topic" questions as long as it helps somebody. If other people wish to attempt to ruin my reputation because of it, then shame on them. I am simply somebody who is helping people in need of help, and if they are in need of help then I will help them to the best of my ability.

I understand but do not agree with your opinion

Comment: In that case you may get [banned from answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) by having too many downvoted answers.

Comment: @Stijn Fair enough. I will be careful as to what I answer in future.

Comment: @Joehot200 then you have misunderstood the purpose of StackOverflow. SO is **not** here to help individual askers, it is intended to be a repository of programming knowledge that is useful to a general audience of programmers, and not just the original asker. Think of it as a programming wikipedia, you wouldn't try to answer each question of an individual person (who might severely lack reading comprehension) directly in a wiki article. It just doesn't scale. If you can't agree with the SO rules on this, please don't post here - seek other programming forums where you can "help people".

Comment: You have _no way to know who down-voted_. Making assumptions is not encouraged.

Comment: @Joehot200, I get your point about helping people, and I'm generally tolerant with this, [especially for questions that some consider off-topic because their subject is at the fringe of development and sysadmin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262787/372643). However, the Q&A format of SO doesn't really work for open-ended questions like the one you're mentioning. That question (now deleted) was about recommendation regarding which of two points to focus on first when learning a technology. That tends to be very much open to debate, unfortunately, unlikely to have a possible best answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The likely reason that the question and answers were downvoted is because the question is off-topic (too broad and opinion-based).

Some people are of the opinion that bad questions should not be answered and such answers also deserve downvotes because they encourage asking off-topic questions.

There is nothing you can do about it, it doesn't break any rule.

Comment: Well, the downvote button on an answer reads "this answer is not useful". I fully agree with this as the answers are basically just anecdotes and vague recommendations. While I didn't downvote any of the answers (I reserve my votes for worse posts) I think the downvotes are definitely justified.

Answer (score 16):

> is that sort of thing allowed - Just randomly downvoting every single post in a question?

If all answers were downvoted, that doesn't seem random, not at all.

There may be many reasons for this, not least that the question and answers and low quality/off-topic.

This is not serial voting (which is defined as votes against a person).

> what should be done about such things, if anything?

Nothing. Nada. Zilch.

This is how the site works.

Comment: I'm not disputing the fact the question in this case was bad, but there seems to be more negativity on SO nowadays, more than a few years ago. Saying "*This is how the site works.*" sounds like simply ignoring the problem. The site rules may have worked well until recently, perhaps with a smaller user base, but that doesn't mean they're fully adapted to what SO has become.

Comment: @Bruno - I'd agree that what is considered acceptable has narrowed down. Significantly. Additionally, after 5 years of seeing low quality, zero effort questions, people no longer try to be nice about it - they get tired of it. You may be interested in reading about [eternal September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) for similarities.

Comment: @Bruno - as to your point about "this is how the site works", my point is specifically about voting and the people can and do vote as they wish. We can only offer guidance. I disagree that people are voting any differently than they have in the past.

Comment: I get the impression that there's definitely more of that ["downvote on answers because the question doesn't feel right" attitude](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265482/372643). There may also be some sort of "downvote victim becomes abuser" effect to a degree. Some had their initial efforts sometime downvoted with little to no explanation, so they probably feel they should inflict the same on others when they see something they don't quite like. As you've said in the past, voting guidelines are vague on purpose. That's certainly part of the problem, "not useful" can have different meanings.

Comment: @Bruno - like everyone else, you have access to the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) - if you can show the problem in numbers, that would make a great meta post.

Comment: Sure it would, but that's also part of the problem. I've always been mainly an answerer on SO, trying to provide relevant content on SO. That negativity has pushed me towards Meta.SO recently, which is certainly much less enjoyable. Compared to writing good technical answers, it feels like a waste of time unfortunately. I'll admit I generally enjoy technical stuff in my spare time, but writing SQL queries in the SE data explorer just for the purpose of some Meta.SO discussion seems like going one step too far. Meta is just too time consuming for what seems to lack overall purpose.

Comment: In addition, we all participate on SO freely. A query in the data explorer might give me actual numbers and tell me with more data whether I'm right or wrong, but that won't tell me much about how regular members *perceive* the way SO has become. I'm afraid it's how users *perceive* the general attitude (rather than hard facts) that encourages them to stay or to go away.