# Should users be penalized 1 rep for upvoting a question that gets closed as OT?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973308/big-gap-on-bottom-of-website), for example, is an off-topic question that is getting upvoted. I downvoted and flagged it, just as I did [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546960/tool-to-automate-converting-inline-css-to-external-css) only a few days ago.

I propose that users who upvote a question that gets closed as OT lose 1 rep.

Comment: A similar penalty for closing a question that was later reopened was proposed - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167404/shouldnt-there-be-a-reputation-penalty-if-a-question-you-closed-ends-up-being-v - a while back

Comment: @ChrisF But that is problematic if the question *improves*. Since edits (albeit, theoretically) don't degrade a question, questions should never lose an upvote-worthy status.

Comment: My posting of the link wasn't meant to imply endorsement of the idea (or otherwise), it was just for information.

Comment: The first question is not off-topic. CSS questions are on-topic.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It most certainly is off-topic. He's fixed it on his site and now the problem is not reproducible anymore. This is exactly why we require reproducible code in the question itself.

Comment: @animuson, then it should have been closed as not-reproducible.  Though since the problem was there when the question was asked, it was on-topic then (as is the case with many not-reproducible questions).

Answer (score 5):

We don't all agree what should be on or off topic. The broad guidelines are clear, but some cases can be subjective.

I don't necessarily see the benefits of penalising someone for supporting a question, just because 5 others (or a mod) don't think this is a good question (not everyone necessarily understands the problem to assess whether it's on or off topic). If there was a mechanism to penalise those who upvote closed questions, we should also have a mechanism to cancel other's close votes (i.e. a vote for -1 close).

Your two examples are also rather different:

- One is [a question that was asked 1/2 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24973308/372643). It's currently off-topic because it's a "help me debug my code" type of question. However, if more details were added, this probably wouldn't be a bad question, and that would make it more general and on-topic.
- The other one is [a 4-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2546960/372643) that visibly has been of value to some users. Users were probably more tolerant back then.

Remember that the official policy is "*vote how you wish*", taking great care in *not* clarifying what "*this is useful*" and "*this is not useful*" (for answers). There's a bit more details in the tooltips for questions, but the idea remains the same. If you start penalising voting habits here, that could be a precedent for a number of other similar voting penalties with which you don't agree. (Note that downvoting answers has a cost simply to prevent abuse.)

Comment: Note that upvoting bad questions is also abuse.

Comment: @devnull That's not the same thing at all. People don't upvote questions that *they* think are bad.

Comment: Your comment seems to indicate that you are _new_ to this site.  Cheers.

Comment: @devnull No need for that sort of comments. If I remember well, you were one of those who voted to delete [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13135230/372643) *after improvements* (see [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265482/372643)): precisely the kind of people who should refrain from voting to close/delete when they don't really understand the subject of the question.

Comment: The post cited by you is a pretty good example of a self-answered Q&A.  This is essentially what a couple of edits to the original post have done.  The fact that the post doesn't have an accepted answer would perhaps only justify the claim.  Moreover, this isn't my personal blog that I would stop you from posting or answering or voting on any crap.  Feel free.

Comment: If [this is an example of improving a post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13135230/3), then I admit that I don't understand what is the difference between _improving_ and _radical change_.

Comment: @devnull I have no idea why you'd call this self-answered. This was answering the initial question at the time. The initial question was indeed "*So I wanna know that the real meaning of the parameter 'protocol' in SSLContext(String protocol);*", which is precisely what I answered *anyway* (before and after edits).

Answer (score 1):

As that first example points out, a question can start out on-topic, but then it's found that the problem is not-reproducible, so it can then be closed as *off-topic->not-reproducible*.  **No one should be penalized because of lack of psychic ability.**