# Edits to closed question approved, then question deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764798/android-sdk-ide-on-android) question which was, at the time, closed as 'not a question'.  I felt that it had some value, so I spent some time editing it in an attempt to address the reason for closure. I also fixed a broken link in the accepted answer. My edits were approved.

I wished to contribute a more up-to-date answer, but I don't have the rep to re-open. At that point, I made the mistake of raising a custom flag to request the same. This flag was rightfully declined and I now have learned that asking for mod intervention is only appropriate for issues that cannot be handled by The Community. Thank you.

Then however, the question was deleted. How can I know the [mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/269610) that was used (e.g., mod, system, review votes) and reason?  I know that time spent fixing up old questions is [appreciated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265482/attempts-to-improve-old-off-topic-question-met-with-downvotes) in general, but I'd like to learn more about the specific conditions where it might lead to deletion and thus end up being a waste of time.

Comment: I fail to see how your edits solve any of the problems with that question.  It looks a bit nicer, but it's no less close worthy.  Don't spend time polishing turds.  Spending time editing a question *that still isn't going to be a good question after your edits* is generally just wasting your time.  Spend your edits making good/okay questions great, or turning questions that aren't actually appropriate into ones that are actually appropriate, instead of turning very bad questions into still pretty bad questions.

Comment: But it was deleted. So although your opinion is that it remains close-worthy, that doesn't explain why it was suddenly deemed delete-worthy after my edits (but apparently not before).

Comment: Presumably your edits (or something else) drew enough attention to it for people to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The question was deleted by 3 10k+ users with the delete question privilege.

Comment: 3 turkeys? Good to know. Go ahead, ban me.