# If answers are already provided, UNCLEAR reason for Hold/Close be prompted to read answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have a suggestion.

In reference to this question.  Not linking on purpose to avoid voting.

> How to sum up a row using Excel VBA OR using an Excel formula, if the
>   number of cells in that row could vary - and then place its answer in
>   the last cell on that row - and then repeat this for every row?

I've seen where people ask a question, poorly worded, or in some other way, not a good example of a question.  Possibly needing to be closed do to being Too Broad or Off-Topic.

What happens is strange.  People will answer the question, as it's really very simple and easy to answer, which might in part be reason for why there isn't code associated with it.  Then people will vote to close or put it on hold for being "Unclear".  The question already has answers, that work, and are valid.

**The Suggestion:**

If there was something in place, where **when you flag as "Unclear" and there are already answers, prompt the user for a DIFFERENT REASON TO CLOSE**. .  Much like the way trying to delete a question with answers works.   Basically, suggest they look at the answers to see if it makes sense then, in case they didn't see the answers.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I'm not suggesting REMOVING that option entirely, but providing a check to make sure the person voting understands that some people DID understand it.  And prompt them to perhaps READ The answers.  If they still vote to close for Unclear, Fine.

The question I'm referring to took me 5 minutes to read, and answer.  I spent a little more time providing details to the user on how to proceed and handle some foreseeable problems.  The flags, and moderator attention and debating, put a bad taste in my mouth as well as others.  Negative perception of the site, and someone actively trying to REMOVE ANSWERS from the person who needed an answer, not only voting to delete them, but commenting on how they never should have been answered.  Not very welcoming, friendly, helpful or anything positive..  That seems AGAINST THE SITE'S GUIDELINES to me.

I don't have a problem with the site's guidelines, and if I answer a question that "shouldn't be answered", let the question be closed for whatever reason.  I don't mind the reputation points going away if I received any in the first place.

edit: removed side discussion that really is a whole other issue as it's already been discussed and agreed upon.
[Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions?lq=1)

I've read through the guidelines, and understand them.  That's what the flagging process is for.  I'm just saying that by letting questions be put on hold or closed for being UNCLEAR when there is an answer already proves that the question WAS UNDERSTANDABLE...  (again, this isn't always true. but would require the people voting to close to READ the answers, or simply not vote to close on questions they just don't understand)

Comment: Assuming that a question is clear solely because it has answers is a horrible assumption. Plenty of people provide "I think this is your problem" types of answers all the time, where it is just a complete guess **because the question is not clear**.

Comment: I can see that as being a reason to not discount the Unclear option.  It would take READING the question and ANSWERS, and if you still don't get it, go ahead and flag it. I don't believe that's happening.

Comment: If you understand the question, why not try editing it into something that is understandable? Guess what, we even have [badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator) for doing that!!

Comment: Because it was so simple, I couldn't imagine it not being clear.

Comment: `In the case I'm speaking about, I received 2 Downvotes for what was a good answer, and 2 upvotes to compensate`  If it's the question I think it is, you spent *far* too much effort on that question, and I'm frankly surprised it has 3 Re-open votes.  It's a "Here are my requirements, now go surprise me with answers" question.

Comment: I would be OK with "Too Broad" or something else as a reason, but unclear is nonsense

Comment: It's more like, a novice user asking a question that wasn't good practice . I understood it, answered the way they asked and then provided a better solution, hopefully teaching them something useful.

Comment: While not closed as unclear (and it certainly could have been), please don't make me go through extra steps to close questions like these:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795627/how-to-fire-multiple-inner-join-with-update-command-in-mysql.  No matter how bad a question is (not just speaking of your example or mine), invariably *someone will always try to answer*, whether for rep, being helpful, or just taking a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: I feel you there.  I just wish there was something to protect people from having good answers for decent, if not perfect or advanced questions from wasting their time as well.

Comment: @peege In what possible way is an answerer harmed from having the question closed?  All the closure does is prevent new answers; if there's already a great answer that answers the question, no other answers are needed.  Closing is very different from deleting.

Comment: @peege Regarding your edit: Was that the full body of the question? If so, it seems more like "Opinion-based" to me, as a "convenient" answer could be one of many answers, and most answers would be based on the opinions of the answer, and voted on in much the same way. In my opinion, it should be closed. Maybe not as unclear, but as "Opinion based" or "Too broad" either one.

Comment: Yes, that was the original question.  And I'd see it closed for Too Broad or Off-Topic as it's too open to ideas, before Unclear.  That's my point.

Comment: @peege I agree the question is not unclear to someone who has used the involved tools. However, using this one example as a reason to block "Unclear" on answered questions is a bad idea. As Servy and Bill have said, there can be random, wild answers as a guess. And if this were implemented, the OP could self-answer with a random guess as to their own problem in the hopes of keeping their question from being closed as "Unclear", which would be even worse than this. To be honest, if the OP has an answer that satisfies them, most don't care if the question is closed.

Comment: If you're going to include the question for reference, you should at least show the original question, *as it was when it was closed*:  `How to sum up a row using Excel VBA OR using an Excel formula, if the number of cells in that row could vary - and then place its answer in the last cell on that row - and then repeat this for every row?`  As it stands, it looks like you're trying to state that the question was closed with the text you quoted, which simply isn't the case.

Comment: I just realized that also.  My mistake there and thank you for pointing it out.  corrected.  I still feel that it's clear.

Comment: I just don't get why you're fighting so hard to open a question, when you're not even sure which version of it got closed.

Comment: Revising my statement, peege: The _original_ text of the question was terribly formatted and much harder to read and understand. As it stood when it was closed, the question was _rightfully_ closed as unclear. As it stands after pnuts' edit, the question is _much_ clearer and easier to read. I can definitely see why some people voted to close that question, and I can see why it could very well be reopened now.

Comment: I just pasted the wrong text in.  I fixed it, and it makes no difference, because they are both easy to understand.  I'm not trying to re-open the question at all.

Comment: My point is a logical one, if people are understanding something, it's not 100% unclear, and to say it's unable to be understood is flawed.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, my intention was to offer a suggestion that is fine to be rejected, no offense taken there, as I trust the community.  And other than that, offer a discussion, as I seek to understand it more fully, and was under the impression that was the purpose of the meta-site.

Comment: Using your own logic, peege, assuming that the question is not 100% unclear just because there are answers on it is also flawed. Especially if you assume this without looking at the answers, and the answers turn out to be answering multiple different questions.

Comment: The key is you need to read the answers before closing it for that reason.

Comment: The fact that it is understood by ME makes it not 100% unclear.  I am greater than 0

Comment: _"The key is you need to read the answers before closing it for that reason"_ Now _that_ is a logical statement. Unfortunately, it is not one that can be enforced. _"The fact that it is understood by ME makes it not 100% unclear."_ Which is the logic used by each of the answers answering different questions on the same question, in my example scenario.

Comment: right, hence my suggestion. . Like, you want to close as being unclear, where there are answers.  Are you SURE?  How is that aweful?  Maybe offer a suggestion to the closer to read the answers before voting.

Comment: _"How is that aweful? Maybe offer a suggestion to the closer to read the answers before voting"_ It's not. But that warning/suggestion will be ignored, and then there will be complaints that there is a warning getting between people and closing horrible questions that should be closed. The fact of the matter is that your intentions are honorable, but there really isn't a way to prevent this in the few cases where the question is quite understandable given knowledge of the technology. (PS. Consider editing your title to match your actual request. ex. Change "disable")

Comment: If that's the case, where I'm in the .01% or something, I completely understand. I still feel the question in question is clear, and shouldn't have been closed for THAT reason.  See my side points as to understand my motivation for posting this.  There's a policing element at play where it doesn't need to be.  I was hoping the suggestion could alleviate it.

Comment: @Servy, I think that is where I have misunderstood.  Probably because my answer was voted to be deleted with the question being marked as Unclear.  Which both seemed wrong to me.   I was under the impression that putting it on hold was the first step in closing it.  Perhaps if I wasn't targeted as a result of the Question, this wouldn't have come up at all.  It's annoying to help someone and have someone else come along and say something to the effect of." I don't get it, remove your answer too.."  I mean to add, I misunderstood the difference between delete, close and hold.

Comment: @peege Closed and on hold are pretty much exactly the same thing.  It's purely a different label, not a functional difference.  If someone is voting to delete answers, that is entirely separate from the state of the question.

Comment: @Servy, can I ask your opinion on voting down good answers and voting to delete them based off of already voting to close the question?  Because that's why I brought this all up.  They seem connected.  Someone doesn't like the question and wants to punish people for understanding it.

Comment: @peege Your question is fundamentally flawed.  You're presupposing that the answer is good.  If someone downvoted and voted to delete the answer, clearly they *didn't* think it was a good answer.  You also have no idea if the person who voted to delete was also the person who downvoted, nor do you have any idea if that person voted to close the question or even considered the question when evaluating your answer.

Comment: @peege You may find [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions?lq=1) to answer that last question to Servy. That has been discussed before, numerous times if I recall. :)

Comment: @Servy, that is true.  I don't know for sure.  but it all happened within a few minutes, and I would suspect that if the Answer was so flawed that it needed removed, that perhaps a comment would go with it.  I am assuming the connection, correct.

Comment: @Kendra - that was one of the strange rare times where I actually kinda agreed with Lance -- he's usually so far off the beaten path it's not even funny.  It made me feel weird.

Comment: @Kendra.  Thank you for that link.  I feel better knowing that is the group concensus.  Just getting shot down for answering a question and providing the person with reasons why the question wasn't even a good one IN the answer, to have it downvoted and voted to be removed makes me not want to participate on this site.

Comment: @peege You should not be posting an answer to explain why a question is a bad question.  You should be posting answers to answer the question.  If the question is a bad question you should be explaining that in comments and not answering it at all.  Posting a non-answer as an answer is most certainly grounds for deletion.

Comment: @Servy, I posted the answer AS ASKED, then offered suggestions for how to improve it.  I provided both.  I would agree totally with that last statement of yours.  As in, here is how to do what you are asking, but it's not a great practice, instead try using this solution.  The first because it explains the steps needed to perform what they asked.  The second to inform of the better practice.  I know I didn't include the link.  I just didn't want to get that question to have MORE upvoting and downvoting based on the meta-discussion.

Comment: One other point to bring up: Close reasons are based on questions *alone*.  They have to be; the point of closing a question is to prevent answers for some reason or another, and you judge which reason to use based on that alone.  Unless the question can stand on its own, without answers, it should be closed.  The existence of an answer is immaterial to the decision making process for closing questions.

Comment: @fbueckert, I agree. My point was that the label was wrong.  I actually don't have a problem with the particular question being closed for being Too Broad.  It's just strange to have people say "this is not understandable" when I can clearly understand it.

Comment: Then you're arguing the wrong points; you're very clearly trying to use answers to prevent a closure.  Since answers are immaterial to whether or not a question gets closed, do you care to change your argument?

Comment: @fbueckert, I don't know how else to state this.  Myself, and several other users UNDERSTOOD the question and somehow it was closed in front of our eyes, while discussing it, for being unclear.  None of us could understand how it was UNCLEAR except one of the people who voted to close it, whom had also attempted to help before being shown they misunderstood.  So to THEM it might have been unclear, but to at least 4 other people it was very clear.  So the REASON for closing it was incorrect, in that case.  I would argue to get the CORRECT close reason, and prevent the wrong reason.

Comment: @fbueckert, there was downvoting and delete votes for the answers as well as comments that you shouldn't help people who don't put in more effort.  But the question was extremely simple and only took 5 minutes for me to write up an answer in code, and solve it, implying that providing code wasn't really necessary in that case AND it was easily understood.  Others tested the code and agreed.  AS well as links to meta-discussions about "What drives me away from SO", and "why SO has become so negative as of late"

Comment: That's the argument you should be making.  That's not at all what this meta question is about, and you actually agree with how closure should work.  Focus on the question, and the action taken on it, not on trying to use an answer to justify keeping a question open.

Comment: Well, I was making the point that if there is an answer, it MUST be clear to someone, but that is a faulty assumption that I made, because I was certain, being the one who understood it.  After posting this question, I agree that in most cases it's probably apt.  I think the other people understood, and the reason I didn't post the specific link is because if it IS just an exception, I'd know by the way everyone replied to the general question.  It's NOT a good idea to deny someone from closing a question on Unclear even IF there are answers.  It can always be re-opened.  @fbueckert

Comment: @fbueckert, to clarify, I was arguing to divert the close REASON to the correct reason, not keep it open..  It might still need closed even if an answer was clear and understood, if the question isn't in the standards of the site.  Simply to avoid people having to say "Nuh-Uh, I understood it."  like I did.  And waste moderator time in re-opening on principal, as well as unnecessary downvoting as punitive means to stop people from answering, and upvoting to compensate..  Just label it as Too Broad, or Off Topic if that's what it is.

Comment: That's not your argument according to your question.  You're specifically using answers to argue that a close reason is invalid.  If you're arguing they used the wrong reason, you should clarify your question.

Comment: @fbueckert, I was suggesting to insert a buffer to stop people from just clicking Unclear, when they might not realize there was an answer, and prompt them to READ the answer, or at least glance at it, to see if the question made sense then.  So the question above it worded correctly to that effect.  People don't want to do it.  It's probably because most of the time, it's not worth it, and the question is unclear with people just guessing answers trying to scrap for an easy 10 rep.  I would fight to keep this particular question alive, but I defer to the groups judgment.  I'm new here.

Comment: @fbueckert, taking your suggestion and modified the actual suggestion to recommend reading the answers to decide if it makes sense at that point.

Comment: You should've just linked to the concrete question in dispute. This whole discussion here got a little sidetracked because it's trying to generalize. (Noone is gonna charge you with "attention whoring" etc. by mentioning a specific case from the start). -- Now I don't agree "punitive closevoting" is an actual issue. It seems also unfair to demand personalized closevotes in place of "unclear", when the OPs question was just as coarse. -- However in my opinion, a detailed answer (such as yours probably was), can often **salvage** or compensate unclear questions. -- Isn't it reopened meanwhile?

Comment: @mario, yes. Lesson learned, I definitely should have posted the link.  No, it's closed.  If it were to re-open, it should be closed for being too broad.  Honestly, I just hope the original question poster got to at least see the answer...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just because there's an answer to the question doesn't mean that the question is clear.

Comment: True, but the questions I'm referring to are completely clear.  Understood, and answered by more than one person, with several people already in the discussion.

Comment: @peege If the questions really are quite clear then it's unlikely to attract 5 unclear votes, and if it does, it can be quickly reopened.  The alternative is that the question isn't clear and the answers aren't particularly great because the question isn't well defined.  Either way, the system as it stands will sort it all out correctly.

Comment: @peege - I've seen plenty of cases, especially in the [sql] tags, where a user posts a vague question, and three or four people toss out wild guesses, hoping they're right.  Meanwhile, the question still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables unfortunately that happens far too often in that tag, it is very frustrating.

Comment: There are millions of users on here, and I'm pretty sure more than 100 who like to spend their free time editing and closing posts, instead of helping people.  Especially in Excel-VBA.  The users in that are typically as green as it comes.

Comment: @peege Editing and closing posts is a great way to be very helpful to people.  Posting bad answers to unclear questions instead of closing them is extremely *unhelpful*.  Many people seem to think it's helpful, which only makes it that much more harmful.  When the questions are clarified enough to actually attract quality answers, *then* answering becomes helpful.

Comment: Well, I agree with you, but I don't believe the answers were bad.  Ad-hominem doesn't work for me.

Comment: I believe the people saw a two sentence question, didn't want to think about what the person was asking, and clicked FLAG..  No code, so it must be a bad question.

Comment: @peege So you're blindly assuming, without any evidence to support your position, that other people are blindly taking action without any evidence to support their position.  The irony is just *dripping* from that comment.

Comment: It's not blind assumption.  There were comments deleted.  I can't state that ALL the people did that ,but it is clear that some did.

Comment: @peege Saying that editing posts and closing questions is universally not helpful is very much wrong.  Editing posts that need editing and closing posts that need closing is *extremely* helpful.  You may or may not feel that one particular example question needs to be closed, and that's absolutely something people can disagree on, but to universally say that closing is unhelpful and answer is helpful, in the general case, is very much wrong.  Since you have provided no specifics, I obviously cannot comment on whether some particular question merits closure, or whether the answer is good.

Comment: Would having a Message Box pop up saying "You are attempting to close a question as being too Unclear that has answers provided, are you sure?" be a bad thing?

Comment: @Servy   I wasn't saying that at all, I said I DO edit and close questions.  My point is that saying it's Unclear when it's understood by people is flawed.

Comment: @peege Unless the answers were posted after the user loaded the question, it's pretty unlikely that they would be unaware of the existence of answers.  If they choose to ignore the answers and didn't consider their effect on whether the question should be closed, a popup isn't going to change their mind.

Comment: I'm talking about cases where : The answer is posted, THEN someone else comes in and attempts to answer it, gets it wrong, and votes to close it.  That's at least ONE of the 5.  I know the other 4 I can't speak about.

Comment: @peege Saying that the question must be clear just because one person thinks they understand it is flawed.  Most questions that I see that are unclear aren't obviously unclear to everyone, rather 5 different people look at it and they all think they know *exactly* what it is, but they all think that the question is *obviously* asking 5 completely different things.  That's *far* more common than someone just posting gibberish that nobody can comprehend at all, and it's questions like these that most need closing as they attract lots and lots of low quality answers if left open.

Comment: The question was worded very clearly.  If you work in Excel, or VBA it would make total sense.  That's like me going into a language tag I know nothing about and voting to close all the questions because I don't understand them

Comment: @peege If you think that the question is clear, that's fine.  Don't vote to close it, and feel free to answer it if it's not closed, or vote to reopen it if it is.  I couldn't comment on whether that question is clear or not as I don't know what question you're referring to.  All I'm saying is that there are plenty of unclear questions with answers; we should not prevent closure as "unclear" just because there are answers.

Comment: "The quantities of populated cells in different rows of my spreadsheet vary.  What is a convenient way to sum each row, with the result being placed in the first available blank cell after the last cell (counting from the left) populated with data? "

Comment: To an Excel user ,that's as simple as it gets.  How can I sum a row? and put the sum in the end of the row?  One of the people who voted to close it suggested summing the whole column using '=sum(A:A)'

Comment: @peege So why does any of that mean that we should be prohibited from closing a question as "unclear" if it's answered?  If you think that question is in fact clear, I've told you exactly what you can do in my last comment.  Whether or not your one example is "clear" is irrelevant to your proposed policy change.  Having one clear question be answered doesn't mean every answered question is clear.  That's a fallacy.

Comment: I understand your point.  I'm not suggesting that ALL answers provided insinuate a complete understanding of the question.  Perhaps the incident in question is an oddity.  I've had it happen to me more than once, where a question is simple as can be and is closed for being unclear.  So I posted a suggestion.

Comment: @peege If you see a clear question that is closed as unclear, then feel free to vote to reopen it, or as other have suggested, edit it so that others can understand it as well as you understand it.  If the community as a whole feels that the post is clear, then everything will work out fine.  If you're really the only person who can understand this question, then it's correct for it to be closed.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't have the ability to vote on re-opening it, unless that is done by adding another flag, under the OTHER option.

Answer (score 16):

Questions and answers need to be useful to more people than just the poster. If you and the poster are the only two people who understand the question, how useful is it going to be to anyone else? If a question gets closed as unclear, edit it into shape. There will almost always be comments aimed at getting clarification. Use those to improve the question so that it's useful to a wider audience.

Comment: Within a few minutes, there were two answers, and at least 4 users in on the comments fully understanding it.  almost an hour later, the downvotes and close requests started coming in.

Comment: @peege That doesn't mean you couldn't improve the question. Also, because of this one case you want to prevent *any* question with *any* answer from being closed as unclear?

Comment: I would want the REAL reason for it to be closed, instead of using Unclear as a generic reason.  In the case above, Off-Topic (maybe) or (Too Broad), I'd see as fine reasons to close.

Comment: @peege Are you talking about the one question, or all questions with an answer? Because people have already explained that questions with wild guess answers can still be unclear. It's still a valid close reason in a lot of cases.

Comment: I don't have a problem with it still being used, but thought it would be a good suggestion, since it's happened to me more than once, and there were other users who commented on how easy to understand the question was in those cases as well.

Comment: I understand I am new to the site and don't understand the scope of problems that go on.  I'm just trying to contribute solutions where I perceive problems.  If it's been thought of and discussed and a common understanding is in place, I'm open to hear it.  That's why I created this question.   Either way it goes with the suggestion, I still don't feel that downvoting answers and voting to delete them is wise, for the reasons I mentioned above.

Comment: I disagree with "if you and the poster are the only two people" part.  I don't understand why that assumption keeps getting used. If anything, all it means is that 5 people wanted to click to close because those 5 people felt it was unclear.  There's nothing about 5 people wanting to close something that even remotely proves or even implies through logic that only two people understand it.  as in  [5 don't think it's clear] <> [only two understand and can benefit].  That is ad hominem.

Comment: @peege If five people understand the question it will get reopened without  being edited. Also, I don't think ad hominem means what you think it means.

Comment: I'll concede it's not best categorized as ad hominem, but it's certainly a logical fallacy.

Comment: @peege It's a simple statement of fact, not a deduction. If only very few people understand the question, it's not useful to a wide audience.  There's plenty of evidence that it's not easily understood, and so far no evidence that enough people understand it enough to reopen it. Are you sure you're not the one with fallacious logic here?

Comment: Where is it determined that because 5 people decide something is "unclear", that only few people understand it.  That is like saying that because 5 people have hearing impairment out of 3.8 million, only a few people must have clear hearing.  It's that point I am speaking about

Comment: @peege That's not what I'm using to support "only a few people understand it." Read again.

Comment: Sorry.  I've re-read it.  I'll give you that in most every case, Unclear means unclear, but in some cases, it's not the correct label.  This is probably one of those cases.  I'm not trying to revive the question, because the motivation of closing it was because it didn't show enough effort.  That was even mentioned in the comments.  "You shouldn't have answered this".  So it's not that it was unclear.  All the answers got quickly downvoted, and the question closed as unclear.  No big deal man.  I  was trying to find a better way to classify.  ftr, the Q&A are closed.  2 clear ans's removed.