# "Serial downvoting" of one question and its answers

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

This is something that I have never encountered before, so I'd like to bring it up. There are of course similar questions, but I haven't found one about this particular constellation:

One of my answers got a downvote (something that I usually try to avoid), so I had another look at it, to see whether I might have gotten something wrong and might revise or improve it. (Indeed, there was a small bug that I fixed now, but then) I noticed that **all** answers to this question had exactly one downvote.

<sub>(It's certainly not a "great" question, but it is reasonable (and, subjectively, interesting). The answers aren't great either, but reasonable as well, and each of them definitely helpful)</sub>

A look at the timeline of the post revealed that the downvotes happened nearly at the same time. A closer look at the reputation changes of the asker and the answerers showed the times for the downvotes:

```
2015-09-04 21:52:16
2015-09-04 21:52:23
2015-09-04 21:52:25
2015-09-04 21:52:28
2015-09-04 21:52:30
```

That was quick. There may be several explanations for this. Someone might have read the question and all the answers, and then might have thought "This is all crap" (without feeling the necessity to write a *better* answer), and downvoted them all. Or someone might have thought that the question was bad, downvoted it, and wanted to punish everyone who dared to answer the question. Or someone might be reeeally quick at reading and judging code snippets, and happened to find all answers "not useful" (although *each* of them solved the problem, in different ways). Or someone is on a downvoting-spree.

However, I don't really care about the downvote, but others might wonder what they did wrong there. I'm curious to see whether it will be caught and handled by this magic mysterious "anti-serial-voting-script", but would also like to hear what others think, or if any other action should be taken here.

Comment: The question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305652/code-for-repeating-elements-of-an-array-infinitely

Comment: @CRABOLO I wanted to avoid any meta-effects. But well ... as any critique here does not refer to the asker or the answerers, but only to the (anonymous) downvoter, it may be OK to mention it....

Comment: Not sure why they were downvoted... have upvoted all in that thread (gave me an insight I needed)

Comment: A side note: The "Related" section now was more helpful than the search and the "similar questions" proposals: [This question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284940/does-the-serial-voting-script-consider-a-question-basis-as-well?rq=1) seems to describe a very similar issue (although it refers to a different reasoning. In this particular case, I doubt that the downvotes are based on the *content*)

Comment: I once did this: down-voted all the answers to a crap question.  My mistake was leaving a comment that it was a crap question that should be closed, not answered, as ironically I then apparently became the target of serial down-voting by one of the answerers.

Comment: @CRABOLO, I've finished reading the post with the feeling: "that's great, at least someone is using meta to discuss about community problems instead of requesting help to fix their own problems", but looking your link in the comments was very sad :(   I believe that we should always avoid the meta effects. The question was too well described without the link.

Comment: That question is not a real question, but code writing request without summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty OP is having when solving it. In other words it is *give me teh codes* question which I believe should be closed. Best answer I imagine for this kind of questions is "Hint: use modulo operator `%` (and maybe some pseudocode example)". I would also like answer which would provide very detailed explain of how this problem could be solved so we would make sure that any beginner (possibly like OP) would be able to understand it.

Comment: @Zanon If somebody *really* wanted to know to which question I referred, he could have found it out from my reputation history anyhow. But I agree that the direct link might encourage a discussion about *the specific question*, and not the issue of "serial/bulk downvoting of (any) question and its answers". See the next comment ... ;-)

Comment: @Pshemo Also see above ;-) : As I said, the question was not "great", but legitimate: ~"How to create an array of size x that contains the contents of a given array repeatedly?" is a generic task, and even though it may have been "give me tah codes" for the specific asker, it is interesting for many programmers. There are several approaches, and they might be interesting for others that have the same question, and IMHO answers on SO are not for THE asker, but for everybody who has the same question.

Comment: There's also the possibility that [nearly half a dozen people actually all managed to get it wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913279/how-to-make-a-valid-li-link#comment49864102_30913279), and in that specific case, there were no glaring issues with the question and it was pretty clear what was being asked - which just makes it even more depressing.

Comment: @BoltClock I also don't see a glaring issue with the question that I referred to. I think it is a legitimate question and (also see the comment that I added there) wonder how it should have been written to be *not* off-topic. I think, even when nitpicking, a minor rewording from "*I want to write code for ...*" to something like "*What are the options, maybe with streams, also regarding performance, for...*" would have been sufficient to make it a "good" question. (Would anybody mind if I edited it? Or would it not be OK because of the "significant" change?)

Comment: I share your concerns on this, and about a subset of this behavior I have seen where 2 or 3 answers, all similar, exist for a question, all at 0 points as they are a couple minutes old.  Then one more answer appears, different text but exactly the same information, and at the same time all other answers have changed to a score of -1.  I just shrugged it off, considered it childish but tried to ignore it.  But just wanted to mention I have seen that kind of behavior as well.

Comment: @WDS This is sometimes referred to as "strategic downvoting": Letting own answers appear "better" (on top of) others. This was obviously not the case here, as *all* answers (and the question) had been downvoted (but I think I see why you mentioned it).

Comment: [Related meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I see that I may have kicked off a discussion that goes beyond the issue that I originally addressed. The question of "whether good answers to bad questions should be downvoted" is somewhat controversial. (But to emphaisize this again: I think that the question was not "great", but could at least have been "good" (with minor rewordings, maybe)).

Comment: Just had a comment instantly moderated, which I left below my answer after an unreasonable down-vote of Q&A (also related to serial down-votes) ...while I think that down-votes without having to state a reason provides one with the impression of having wasted one's time and it barely improves content quality, because one never will know what to improve. And with having to provide a reason, there won't be any serial-down-votes. The reversal script is a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Comments such as those are likely to be removed when flagged, because they do not constitute as actual feedback to the question or answer (this applies to any "why the downvote?" comment too). If you believe that you have been serially targeted, there are [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270/1233251) on how to proceed. However, this unlikely applies to all downvotes that you may consider "unreasonable". If the only problem is not receiving feedback, this is the main reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251

Comment: @E_net4thedownvoter it wasn't exactly serial down-voting (only my comment was referring to it), but sometimes it seems as if these would retaliatory down-votes, when I close people's duplicate questions. When demanding a reason, this would put an end to such down-votes and certainly also serial down-votes... or at least reduce it to a certain degree. When I close-vote, I also need a proper reason - and often even still help them, without any reputation gain.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Best to shrug those off. The system demanding users to provide a reason is not going to happen.

Comment: @E_net4isnotamoderator I also do not see this happening. It's just discouraging to invest time trying to help to keep the site clean, when one cannot defend oneself against the retaliation. > 25k reputation should not give access to site statistics, but permit to see who down-voted :)

Comment: @MartinZeitler This isn't quite the place to continue discussing this. Please consider posting a new Meta question instead.

Comment: @MartinZeitler There is an implicit reason that is given with **every** downvote, and it can be seen as a tooltip when hovering the mouse over the "downvote" arrow: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". In doubt, people would just pick any "dummy" reason for their downvote (and if they had the option to enter free text, just say something like "This is an utterly crappy Q/A" or so...).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do this (but I didn't do it to this question). When I see a question which is crap, and should also be closed, I downvote it, and vote to close it. And if other people answered instead of doing likewise, I downvote their answers, because it is *not helpful* to encourage people who post crap by providing them with answers.

Comment: It happens, though rarely, that a superb answer can overcome having started with a bad question. Though in those cases, I mostly wonder why they invested all that effort in their post, but none at all in fixing the question...

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned this as one possible explanation. The question does not have any close votes, though. And I think that in this case, the *intention* of the question is clear, and it is reasonable to answer it (otherwise I wouldn't have done so). However, my question here was not about the quality of one particular question, but about the "serial downvoting" aspect. So I'll accept this answer, because it describes what some people actually seem to *do* (even though I don't think that it is appropriate in this case, or the best thing to do in general - but that's a different story)

Comment: Then you use the voting system in the incorrect fashion. If you see a good answer to a crap question, you should be applauding the answerer for actually answering the question.

I agree with you if, say, said question is off-topic though.

Comment: -1 you are punishing people for answering a badly written question, on the grounds that they should have fixed the question first, no matter how good the answer is? So why didn't **you** spend time to fix the question instead of downvoting possibly good answers? Definitely this type of technique does not discourage users who post crap questions to continue doing so (they probably don't care about downvotes), nor encourages well meaning people to continue contributing to SO.

Comment: Sometimes I vote to close a question and I still answer it. Sometimes using a comment, sometimes using a real answer. Usually the questions which are asked by a programming noob. The fact that he doesn't have enough understanding to ask a good question doesn't mean I cannot help him.

Comment: No amount of editing can fix a 'send me the regex' question, and no answer to such a question deserves positive treatment.

Comment: Aha, punishing people for trying to help others.  It's people like you who make the world a better place.  Don't forget to look up the profiles of the people who posted answers, so you can apply additional downvotes to punish them more.

Comment: I tend to be very scarce in my downvotes (what can I say, I am optimistic), but I admit that sometimes I have been tempted to do so for "educational" purposes.

Comment: @DavidWallace: What makes you think they want to help the world? They might also just be out for themselves, trying to get reputation as a game or because it's great on their resume. In the years I have on SO, I've certainly seen dubious behaviors who only made sense if one aimed for reputation first (such as the fastest gun in the west syndrom, where an answer evolves from a one-liner to a a couple lines to a couple more lines etc... all edits within a minute of each other, just to grab the spot light and hold it).

Comment: You're absolutely right, @MatthieuM. We can't be sure of their motivation.  Best to be on the safe side and punish them regardless.

Comment: @Deduplicator: right, and there's even [a badge for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: That's the theory, yes. Unfortunately, many (actually much more than most) which fit the criteria for the badge don't fit it's spirit. The refiner-badges seem to be more successful, but I concede I never saw the stats or checked a representative sample of the latter.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett and others: The [answer by Flown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32309129/3182664) might in fact bring a "reversal" here. 13 upvotes still missing, though ;-)

Comment: The problem with this is that people upvote answers that have too low a score in their oppinion. You are provoking counter-upvotes which weight more than your downvote, which is not what you intended. Ignoring those answers hurts them more than downvoting.

Comment: // , Sounds like you have chosen to humorlessly game the system, @bmargulles, and to not judge an answer on its own merit.

Comment: @bmargulies You way that no amount of editing can fix a give me the regex question. But perhaps a good answer could prevent it being asked again. One day my mind was fried and I asked a stupid question. But it turned out to be my most popular question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353929/get-the-absolute-value-of-a-number-in-javascript. I believe this is because others hit the same wall of stupidity that I did. Just something to think about when down voting all the answers.

Comment: @DanWalmsley you and others are consistently confusing simple questions with crap questions. Simple questions are fine. Crap questions have no place on this site.

Comment: @bmargulies Down voting an answer because the question it answers isn't very good? People who share your views on this are everything wrong with this site. We should be encouraging people to ask and answer questions, that's how we grow. If an answer is bad, down vote it, if it is not bad, **don't** down vote it. Period. A good answer should not be down voted as punishment for the question being poor. No wonder people think this site is so [negative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: The downvote tooltip says "this answer is not useful". Are good answers to terrible questions useful? Is encouraging terrible questions useful?

Comment: @Rawling Think about what you are asking. Take the most terrible question in the world, the answer to this question **is** useful because it answers the question. The **question** is not useful, but the solution to this is useful (i.e. it is **of use**) to the person who asked it. SO "Are good answers to terrible questions useful?" The answer is of course yes.

Comment: Downvotes are down to an individual to award - or not. There's definitely a case to be made that the best way of closing the help-vampire/repwhore loop is to downvote both. I've not done it particularly myself, but I can well understand why someone might. I think it's down to how broadly you define "Of use" - to this supplicant? Or to the rest of the world.

Comment: `it is not helpful to encourage people who post crap by providing them with answers`. +1

Comment: @Ejay Haha I can reword that to: `It's not helpful to help people`

Comment: I'm with Reece, and it's this punitive spirit that's resulted in my spending much less time participating in StackOverflow.  If you think a question is bad feel free to downvote the question (and / or vote to close) and move on.  If you feel an answer is bad, downvote the answer.  But taking the extra step of punishing people who don't share your opinion about the question is pretty sad.

Comment: I'm with bmargulies, and it's this rep-seeking, indiscriminate spirit that's resulted in my spending much less time participating in Stack Overflow. Time and time again, people post answers to _obviously bad_ questions, because they care more about getting their rep score up than they do about the overall quality of the site. It's harder to delete bad questions when they've been answered, and it misleads future readers/searchers into thinking there's useful content in a Q&A when there's not (due to the low quality of the question).

Comment: Vote based on content. Your personal opinions of motive are more than likely misguided and are most definitely not applicable to answers if the content posted is useful. I am surprised there are still some hold outs on this issue, I was fairly certain that this was resolved.

Comment: It may be clear, but: Whether a question is good or not is partially subjective. (IMHO more than whether an answer is helpful). I think the question that kicked off this discussion was "OK". But regardless of whether the question is good or not, all the answers had been helpful/useful, so no reason for downvotes. Unless you somehow interpret this as "Not useful because they answer a question of which *I, personally, subjectively* don't like". I don't agree with that, but if others think that this is OK, there's nothing to prevent them from doing that)

Comment: Your drawn conclusion "not helpful to answer" has been historically argued and failed many times. It is nice to say, but it is fully inaccurate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho so... you personally contact each and every one of those people and specifically ask for their motivation for answering such a bad question? Otherwise I am not quite sure how you would know they're doing it for a bunch of internet points.

Comment: @nico: so... you personally contact each and every one of those people and specifically ask for their motivation for downvoting such a bad answer? Otherwise I am not quite sure how you would know they're doing it to be punitive.

Comment: @Peter the person who answered said that is his motivation, you said you agree with him. Don't know about the other users. I vote for the answer, not for (a perceived) motivation for which someone answered.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. You should only downvote when the answer's are useless. Just because the question is useless doesn't mean answer is useless.

Answer (score 35):

> I'm curious to see whether it will be caught and handled by this magic mysterious "anti-serial-voting-script",

Based on the evidence you present, it most likely won't because what you saw there is not in fact what we call "serial downvoting". [Serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) is downvoting which appears to **target the user** rather than the posts. Alice left a comment at the same time I got a downvote, therefore *she* downvoted me. So I'm going to go after her and downvote all her posts. That'll teach her! This is serial downvoting. Judging a question and its answers to be all worthy of downvotes is not serial downvoting.

Useless questions invite useless answers. So that answers get downvoted together with their question is not anything *suspicious* even if we disagree with the votes.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put "serial downvoting" in quotes. But I thought that it was somewhat ... suspicious or at least unusual that all downvotes appeared within a few seconds (which *is* kind of "serial", regardless of the actual definition...)

Comment: Poor [Alice](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1178021/alice-allergeek)!

Comment: Alice? Who the ... hell is alice?