# What to do if a question is crap and should be closed, but an answer is great?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Some questions are off-topic and should be downvoted and closed accordingly very quickly.
But sometimes, a user comes by and writes an answer before the question is closed. A very good, interesting, detailed, precise, original answer.

Such a question could be your classic "i need free libary `de here`plz", and the answer being an amazingly elegant solution native to the language. It happens. I don't have an example but it happens.
In that example, the answerer solved the X of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the question about Y being off-topic.

Thing is, while the answer may receive some well-deserved upvotes, the question will be stormed and closed promptly. But should it?

If I come across such a question, I could:

- Vote to close as crap and/or downvote it
- Ask for the author to rephrase the question so as not to be off-topic.
- Completely edit it myself, possibly going against the author's intent to make it fit for SO and fit for its answer

How to save these answers?

Comment: Either make the question not crap (by editing it) or downvote it. If the question is off-topic, vote to close it unless editing can salvage it. It is a risk the answerer took when they posted their answer on a off-topic question.

Comment: You speak of "saving" these answers, but questions being closed does not automatically mean a loss of all information within. Does this list of rules about question auto-deletion perhaps soothe your mind a little? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: ["The best way to 'rescue' a question is not with a good answer, but with a good **edit** *and* a good answer."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274924/839601)

Answer (score 7):

Option 1: You vote to close it. The question remains, the answer remains.

Option 2: You edit it to be a good question that calls forth that answer.