# Should only great questions get great answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

**I'm sure we've all done this**: you start answering a question, realise that you're going a bit beyond the scope of exactly what the OP needed to resolve their particular issue, but you keep going anyways, because *it's ok!* What you're writing is interesting and useful to everyone else who stumbles upon that answer!

I've personally found that [some of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111) [the best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit/6866485#6866485) are the ones that go above and beyond the call of duty, and I firmly believe that there is value in answers like this.

But now you've finished your great answer, it's 20-60 minutes later (depending on how long it takes you to write a really great answer) and you realise that you've put orders of magnitude more effort into the answer than went into the question. It's not that it's a *bad* question (you can read about those [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310800/is-it-the-question-or-the-answer-that-makes-a-great-archive) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298639/what-to-do-if-a-question-is-crap-and-should-be-closed-but-an-answer-is-great)), but it's a mediocre one. It has and will continue to have low views and nearly no upvotes, which means nobody is ever going see your answer.

Comment: Context: [my overly enthusiastic answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35587496/675721). I'm willing to concede that it was so beyond the scope of the question as to be off-topic and I probably should have stuck to strictly answering the question.

Comment: If the question is truly irredeemable, ask and self-answer a great question.

Comment: Am I the only one that can't see the wood due to the formatting?

Comment: And as for _this_ meta question, I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want us to tell you which of your groups we identify as, or...?

Comment: Use the suggestion from Jeffrey Bosboom and you even have a great dupe target if the question comes up again later!

Comment: haha @JeffreyBosboom the choose your own adventure was just to make it a bit more fun. But the question stands -- is there value? What's your opinion?

Comment: Good answers are like home-runs in a minor-league baseball game.  They don't happen often enough to decide the game and if they do happen then everybody quickly forgets them again.  But Babe Ruth just might show up and turns a lame pitch into a record-setting whack and make everybody go ooooh-wow.  He's not going to show up very often when every game is crappy.

Comment: Your answer looks more like a blog post than an SO answer to me. Some additional info is what makes the difference between a good and a great question, but there is a limit. You don't want to post a whole book on every answer - it becomes irrelevant/implied at some point

Comment: @Kendra The whole premise here is that the question isn't going to be applicable or interesting to lots of other people.  It being a good dup target for questions nobody is ever going to ask isn't really relevant.

Comment: @ZachSaucier in the case of my specific answer, it pretty clearly should have been a blog post. But in general, where do you draw the line?

Comment: I can hear this "tree" falling already

Comment: But now you've finished your great answer, it's 20-60 minutes later (depending on how long it takes you to write a really great answer) the OP has already got their copypasta answer and has deleted the question, which means...Nobody is ever going see your answer again, including yourself!

Comment: @CodeBling _"**If an answer falls in the woods and no one is around to hear it, does it still have value?**"_ We should have a tumbleweed badge for answers :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ We, well, sort of do. There's tenacious and unsung hero. And I have those badges? o_O

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271017/why-newbie-questions-bring-so-many-reputation-points-to-the-author)

Answer (score 5):

> If an answer falls in the woods and no one is around to hear it, does it still have value?

Heck. Yes. Even though the question might not be viewed by the two million plus users of Stack Overflow, you are forgetting about the other 7 billion people on Earth who use the Internet and the big group that constantly use Stack Overflow as a reference. Sure, you answer a question with low views... from users of Stack Overflow, not all views from all people.

Stack Overflow is not about making answers that everyone must see and put their attention too. Everyone has to look at the questions that interest them while new ones pop up by the second. Not everyone can just find ***your*** answer to that specific question instantly. They will have to search or find you profile and waste time. How about you think about the bigger picture: the Earth and its human inhabitants.

> If nobody else was ever going to see the answer, you shouldn't have spent all that time writing it.

The OP would take great pleasure seeing someone dedicate their precious time into solving their question... including the puzzled programmers out there. The answerer should be proud of what he did for others and the OP. Not thinking about how much time he wasted but ***about the time he saved others***.

> It's good that you posted the answer, no effort made towards helping other people is wasted effort, and someone will eventually see it.

There's the positive side! Someone ***will*** look at your answer, someone ***will appreciate*** your answer, and someone will ***save lots of time*** because of that answer.

> It's always good to put extra effort in to the answer, but if you're going to put extra effort in to the answer, you have to make sure it is seen.

This is Stack Overflow not Social Overflow. People will view the question eventually so why advertise. It will just annoy people and only some people will even consider visiting your answer. The best answers were written years ago, not minutes nor seconds.

> It's great to put in the extra effort, but SO is not the place for it. Answers should only directly address the question, no more, no less. The extra-curricular parts of the answer belong in a blog.

WRONG! Moderators are great examples of disproving this, writing answers that not only answers the question but provide more information to thoroughly explain their answer and lead the puzzled into the right path. There is nothing wrong with this.

Making detailed answers is okay, but making a one-liner that only answers the question is not.

> Choose your own adventure, i.e. What was the correct course of action here?

Be patient, enjoy the fact you are saving others time, move on with life and answer more questions like a boss

Comment: Well answered!  Excellent points, all.

Comment: It doesn't have value if the question gets axed though. And that is a high risk, making it not really a good idea to try and answer questions that have that risk of being closed and deleted. SO needs your time mostly everywhere else.