# Voting strategies

Tags: discussion, voting

I've recently asked this question: [How to deal with users not wanting to accept basic "rules"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350291/how-to-deal-with-users-not-wanting-to-accept-basic-rules)

The question received 9 downvotes, and a lot of comments saying it's cool to downvote correct/helpful answers, if the person who votes thinks the *question* wasn't very good.

So now I'm in a dilemma. Until the question that I've asked, I thought we should upvote if the content a very person posted was good and possibly helpful for the OP or any future visitor, and we should downvote if the content a person posted was bad.

The reaction on the question made me think twice. Although I still think I'm right, I think the community wants us to downvote perfect valid content (and a volunteer who posted it), because of content a completely different person posted (the guy who asked a question).

We receive too many bad questions on SO. Until now, I downvoted them, voted to close, sometimes commented what could be better and moved on (and  sometimes came back to see changes in the question).

Now I see that this behaviour is fundamentally wrong, because it seems like the people here want to downvote correct posts based on another person's posts. Since I realised that, I thought it would be a good decision to start downvoting correct posts whenever I don't like the question. And I don't like a lot of the questions posted here.

I've got 27.458 reputation points - The only step that interests me is the 3.000 reputation point mark, the rest is not too important for me. Thanks to daily growth of reputation, this will be 20-30 more per day. But let's forget about that for a second. So now I can downvote 24.458 correct, helpful answers on questions I don't like (boy I'll find them quickly) without risking any privilege I want.

I've already started with the experiment, and people start asking `why the downvote`. Should I point them to the question I asked previously, or does anybody have a better thing to point them to?

Please remember, as [JK.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/325727/jk) commented:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Based on Servey's answer, I will from now on downvote everything I see on a question I don't like. May it be the wording, the grammar, or whatever --> downvote (not the question, only the answers!).

Comment: TL; DR; If I read _voting_ and _strategies_ in one sentence that smells for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's a good start. I hope the question starts to smell for a lot of people!!!

Comment: OK, may be the TL; DR; was to shortcut from my side (and the dv coming along with it). You seem to have good intentions after reading deeper.

Comment: For me, I'm using a number of stock comments frequently to point out people what might be wrong with their questions and why I've been down-/close-voting these. You might also be interested to join us at the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to discuss that further with other users similar minded.

Comment: I will consider that @πάνταῥεῖ, I'd like to get more people read the question though

Comment: Just because a post is *correct* doesn't mean it's *helpful*.  Lots of correct posts aren't helpful at all.

Comment: Nobody said that @Servy. But if a post is helpful and someone downvotes it just because they didn't like the question, it's a ...

Comment: @Servy and there are lots of very helpful posts that answer a bullsh*t question

Comment: @baao So what's your evidence for asserting that lots of people are downvoting posts *that they think are helpful*.  There are lots of people that feel that answering really bad questions tend to not be helpful (which is a sensible enough thing to feel given that it's true *by definition* on SO) and will typically merit a downvote accordingly.

Comment: Read the comments on the question I linked to in above question, then see it's vote ratio! @Servy

Comment: @baao If the question is bullshit, then how is the answer going to be helpful?  Who's going to find the answer, and how is it going to help them, if the entire question is nonsensical?

Comment: When you hover over the down-vote button for answers, the text that pops up says: _"This answer is not useful"_. Isn't that alone sufficient grounds for down-voting an answer?

Comment: @Servy wait a second, I'll post some in the next minutes

Comment: @baao How does the vote ratio on your post demonstrate that at all?

Comment: But it's not only that. @Ðаn, I'm on the subway right now, I'll be coming home and will post a mass of bad, closeworthy questions we have here - with respected answers.

Comment: @ChristianDean https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY3lb.jpg

Comment: @baao And do those super rare useful answers to closed questions have a lot of downvotes?  Or are people only actually downvoting the answers to bad questions that aren't actually going to be useful.

Comment: @Ðаn maybe. There are lots of other questions pondering on this matter, eg [What to do if a question is crap and should be closed, but an answer is great?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298643/839601)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I think the community wants us to downvote perfect valid content (and a volunteer who posted it), because of content a completely different person posted (the guy who asked a question).

No, that's not actually what the community is telling you.  What the community is telling you is that answers to bad questions will overwhelmingly not be useful, *for precisely the reason(s) that the question is bad*.  Bad questions are bad *because they attract bad answers*, and often because it's *impossible* to provide a good answer.

If a question is unclear it doesn't matter how correct the statements in the answer may be, you can't possibly say that it's a correct answer to the question if you don't even know what the question is.

If the question is missing key details necessary for an answer, then then answer(s) are *by definition* also missing that key information.

If a question is Too Broad then an answer will *by necessity*, be incomplete, or will contain way more information than can be effectively conveyed in an SO answer (almost always the former, in practice).

If a question is duplicating frequently ask questions that have already been asked here thousands of times then the answers are just duplicating answers that have already been posted here thousands of times.

And so on and so on for all of the close reasons.

The point here is that in all of these cases the problems with the question *make the answers not useful*, regardless of whether the information in the answer is correct or not.

So sure, if you *really* feel that an answer is going to be *useful* (and not just "correct"), despite any problems that the question might have, then sure, by all means, upvote it.  But you most certainly should be considering how the problems with the question *affect the usefulness of the answers provided* when considering how useful the answer(s) actually are.  Some answers really can transcend a bad question, it's *possible*, but it's really hard, and quite rare.  (And honestly, in those rare cases it's usually worth fixing the question, as that will *dramatically* improve the usefulness of the answer.)

Comment: I've only read the first sentence, and already I see you don't understand. _it's impossible to provide a good answer_ I'm asking for `why are people downvoting good answers/content`!!! I don't ask for answers solving what is 1+1. Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: @baao And I'm telling you that *your premise is wrong*.  You're assuming that people are downvoting good content.  *They aren't*.  They're downvoting bad content.  You're just assuming that they're downvoting good content.

Comment: Ok, based on your answer, I will continue my experiment. Thanks for the clarification!!!

Comment: English is not my first language, maybe I'm bad at explaining. Maybe you see what I meant after our short conversation on your answer on a bad question

Comment: @baao No, you've merely made it clear that you don't understand the answer here.  You're making a bunch of false assumptions about what other people are doing, and criticising them for doing bad things based on *what you're assuming they're doing* rather than what they're *actually* doing.  I'd suggest reading the answer again, because by no means is it suggesting, "downvote every answer to every question that has a downvote" as you seem to be assuming it's saying.

Comment: No I don't do that. The dv on your answer (which I've immediatly removed) wasn't meant serious. But those kind of dv are exactly what I'm trying to criticise.

Comment: @baao And I'm telling you that *that's not a thing that people are actually doing*.  Criticizing a thing that doesn't exist isn't productive.  You're misinterpreting the actions of others.

Comment: Ok, I will step back from joining meta discussions, I'm too bad at explaining myself in english. I'll continue with what I think is right. Thank you again for your time, and don't answer questions that doesn't completely fit the rules from the help center. They might get downvoted for no reason, but it can't be a good answer if the question is bad. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly, the answer must be horrible for you

Comment: @baao Like I said, it's *possible* to have a useful answer to a really bad question.  It's *super* rare though.  That's a rather famous example of  such an unusual case.  But that it can occasionally be done doesn't mean that all answers without factual inaccuracies posted to low quality questions are useful, because the *vast* majority aren't.

Comment: Look at my vote history. I'm downvoting a lot, I don't like bad content. But what I'm complaining about, and what you are denying, is, that there are continuously asked horrible questions, answered with magnificent answers.  You can't deny that. If you do, you're not reading SO closely enough. Even if it's a -5Q/+5A, the answer will help masses of people. Downvoting the answer is simply wrong, even if the OP didn't speak english, couldn't explain himself well - but someone else could understand and explain. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Downvoting quality content is wrong, no matter what came before it

Comment: And if I'm asking what 1+1 is, and someone explained me in detail the Theory of relativity - you can't downvote it. In this case maybe tell the writer it's the wrong place - but don't downvote.

Comment: @baao I most certainly *can* deny it.  Like I said, it's not *impossible*, but it's rare.  There aren't tons of great answers to bad questions, and in those cases *the answers aren't getting downvoted*.  What you *are* seeing get downvotes are answers that  *aren't* useful, even if they are correct, that are posted to bad questions.  If a question is incoherent then an answer to such a question *isn't going to be useful*, because you can't possibly even determine if it answers the question.  Posting the information from such an answer to a *good* question could make the answer useful.

Comment: @baao Downvoting content that's not helpful is appropriate, even if the answer is correct.  Your example is a *fantastic* example of this.  Someone posting a detailed explanation of Relativity to a simple addition question *is not a useful answer* as it's entirely off topic, even if the information it contains is accurate.  It's an answer that could be useful *if posted to a high quality appropriate question that it answers*.  Refusing to downvote bad content just because the reason it's bad is something other than technical accuracy isn't helpful.

Comment: I actually now get your point @Servy The example of relativty against 1+1 was a offensive (offensive like in basketball, when the are not in the defense _ sorry, don't have the right word) one though.

Comment: Sometime after down voting user changes the question and improve it, in that case down voting stay invalid, there should be a reason to down vote that other people can also see, so that we can ensure if vote was down voted because of valid reason, and canceling the down vote will help and encourage the asking person to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I point them to the question I asked previously...

No. The previous question doesn't answer their question at all. You claim to disagree with you current voting behavior in that posts and all of the answers on that question say, "We can't stop people from voting that way". It doesn't explain your new behavior at all.

> ...does anybody have a better thing to point them to?

Point them to this question. Here you've explained that now that you know you can't be punished for it, you've decided to down vote answers you personally think are correct and useful on questions you think are bad.