# What to do when a user totally copied an answer and behaving like a troll on a question

Tags: support

Yesterday I answered a question, after then 3 people answered that question too. One of them was editing his answer like all the time. His answer was really low quality, and he had like +900 rep. Then he down-voted all answers on that question and wrote a comment to question " what's with all down-votes? ".

After then discussion started via comments. A guy who answered that question said to this troll "you copied my answer." I checked this guy's edit history and that guy was right, he copied his answer while editing. Then this troll guy said "you can check I answered before you". He thought people can't see his edit history probably.

After then this troll guy said really non-sense things on the comments and deleted his answer and comments. I was almost flag his answer but he deleted it anyway.

What to do when we face a problem like this? Is there any flag that "copied answer" or like this? Me and the guy who had original answer flagged his comments for "too chatty" but it doesn't matter, he deleted all of them anyway.

Comment: You don't **know** he downvoted all the answers as downvotes are anonymous.

Comment: @Paulie_D 'officially' I don't know, but everyone knew it was that guy.

Comment: Frankly, other than flagging for "plagarism" (be detailed and expect a 'decline') there is little you can do. Petty little people like this will gamify as much as they like. At the end, we're just talking about fake internet points...be the better person, downvote and move on.

Comment: [How do you know he is a troll?](https://youtu.be/zrzMhU_4m-g)

Comment: Hard to tell you what should have happened *in this specific case* without seeing any specific evidence. For simple questions it is extremely likely that two people would solve the problem in the same way, and if it plugs into some well-documented pattern, it is not surprising if even the variable names are the same across multiple answers.

Comment: Hmya, this happens.  Users tend to go a little nutso when they start to earn rep, "strategic downvoting" does get re-invented over and over again.  The sage advice that any old-timer would give you is to focus on Q+A that helps you to be a better programmer yourself and avoid participating in the rep playing game. It is the only way to get to contribute for *years* and not quit because you get bored out of your skull, mad at other users or rub too many other users the wrong way so they stop voting on your posts.  Only way to gain the rep that counts, the reputable kind.  He won't.

Comment: This is not a viable long term strategy for getting points. Flag it and let him discover it for him self.

Comment: Also take into account that some people prefer to downvote answers to bad or trivial questions - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions. So that may have been exactly such a case.

Comment: `[...] and he had like +900 rep [...]` I don't get why it matters. You assume he got all his reputation by "stealing" others answers ?

Comment: @ColinPitrat No, the point is he is not a new user here. That's why I wrote that.

Comment: @JDB "[he] looks like one"!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @Paulie_D said in the comments - just flag it. Use a custom moderator flag, and add some details about what is going on.

It's important to stick to the verifiable facts when flagging. The user might have "strategically" downvoted the other answers, but neither you nor the moderators can verify that it was really him. For all we know, it might have been another troll who passed by, who thought it would be funny to fan the flames with some extra downvotes.

After flagging, move on. Trolls thrive on attention, so don't give it to them. Leave it to the moderators to handle it behind the scenes.

Comment: I should say that we can't do anything about someone downvoting all the answers to a question. If they're not targeting someone, we can't see who voted, nor can we change those votes. Perhaps someone believed that all answers to a question really were wrong. Plagiarism we can look into, voting on the answers of a question (outside of voting fraud), we can't.

Comment: @BradLarson I used your comment as part of my answer.

Comment: Does it really need to be flagged? Hmm...not sure.

Comment: @Lankymart Plagiarism of an answer deserves a flag. As long as you're sure it's plagiarism. False accusations also warrant a flag.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd add my two cents. I saw the mentioned question, all the answers did indeed have a downvote, one of the answers had two, which I made a comment upon, as I didn't understand why it was downvoted (maybe it was a bad post and I didn't realise).

The reason I mention this, is there was obviously more than one downvoter.. so it's important not to be preemptive over who did the downvoting. Besides, if the user you refer to as a troll was the downvoter, there is nothing your can do. Taken from the comments.

> 

I should say that we can't do anything about someone downvoting all the answers to a question. If they're not targeting someone, we can't see who voted, nor can we change those votes. Perhaps someone believed that all answers to a question really were wrong. Plagiarism we can look into, voting on the answers of a question (outside of voting fraud), we can't. – [Brad Larson♦ 12 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317770/what-to-do-when-a-user-totally-copied-an-answer-and-behaving-like-a-troll-on-a-q#comment314161_317771)

The only other thing you can do in this type of situation is flag any comments that may be abusive and perhaps post a link to the [SOCVR room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), which I believe you did. That way you can be sure that any abusive comments will receive a lot of flag attention. You will also receive support and sometimes that is half the battle.

If the person is badgering and abusing people in comments, a custom mod flag may be worthwhile to alert the mods of the behaviour outside of the ordinary flags. This way, if  a user's behaviour is brought to mod attention repeatedly they can act accordingly with disciplinary measures if needed. Although repeated offensive flags will also do this, I believe.

I am always reluctant to recommend mod flags, unless absolutely necessary, as they have so many flags to deal with and whatever we can manage as a community is better done so, as a community.

Answer (score 4):

So annyoing - have seen it all : Stategic downvoting, continously carbon copies of answers (including my typos and errors) - I'll go with @HansPassant, there is really nothing you can do, but it is the #2 road to get sick of SO if you are going to be upset about it (#1 is of course the repetetive slap in your face if you keep on reviewing :)

Though, it seem to happen mostly on low rep questions with focus on ordinary issues answered 1000 times before - the copists seems not to dare to copy unique answers on more complex issues, guess they think it is too obvious. So my advice would be to focus less on the easy "why is my for loop not working" questions on the major tags. Those kind of questions does not have potential to "nice answer" and so on anyway - they are answered and forgotten.