# @mention downvoters

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

Can you call out downvoters with @metions in comments? It really annoys me when someone comes past and downvotes the question and all the answers, then leaves without any comment as to why.

Would be great if you could comment say *@downvoter, would you mind clarifying why you downvoted my answer?*

I can't find anywhere this has been asked before, however I may be looking in the wrong places.

Admittedly the post that caused this one wasn't the best question at all, yet I put time into my answer, including a breakdown into what each part did, so it annoyed me more than usual. And then in my search I found this - [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) - which made me feel more justified.

Comment: Please, don't waste your and our time seeking for clarifications on each downvote you get.

Comment: @MarounMaroun it's not the first don't worry - just this particular one seemed a little unjust, and I wished I could get some insight as to why

Comment: Like it or not, downvotes are a risk that you take when you answer [low-quality questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872105/hide-parts-of-site-on-mobile-devces). Even if people aren't downvoting answers based on the quality of the question, it's very easy to see how they might have a different interpretation of the question and therefore feel your answer is not adequate.

Comment: Like it or not: It is the downvotes that are the lowest quality one can express. Most downvoters react from own inability to understand intelligent Q&A. There may also be a feel of power behind lo-level reactions against creative minded people.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That this doesn't exist is intentional.

- A comment asking downvoters to clarify why they downvoted is redundant. The system already reminds lower-reputation downvoters that they can leave feedback, and the veteran users already know it.

  There's many legitimate reasons for not leaving feedback when downvoting, including the threat of flamewars, retaliation and harassment; lack of time; or lack of willingness (because what's wrong can be looked up easily.)
- Stack Overflow has always relied a lot on crowd-voting: the idea is that if a downvote is cast unjustly, *other voters* will fix the problem. Hence, it is not relevant nor desirable to get the original downvoter (or upvoter) to correct their judgement.

  I don't have the scientific data to tell how well this is working, but my gut feeling is it's working much better than we tend to think when we get stung by an unjust downvote that doesn't get corrected right away. That's not to say there aren't wrongs that never get righted - they just may not be numerous enough to warrant a change to the system.
- A way to directly reach the inboxes of those who downvoted you would very likely be misused. Downvotes tend to have a very negative emotional impact on many individuals, and some of them choose to lash out in response. Even though people seen doing this would be disciplined quickly by moderators, it's likely we'd see a lot of it happening in the brief period before the moderator can step in.

Comment: Fair enough, guess I lucked out on this one

Comment: "unjust" is -2 not -1 (friendly reminder from one answer downvoter to another - guy you voted down gets -2, it's you who gets -1)

Comment: @gnat oh, I meant that as an abbreviation for "downvote". Will fix