# Is this correct use of the downvote on answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956703/fetch-sql-data-in-array-in-php), the OP posted an issue he was facing. His example, while not affecting the **actual** issue he was having, included some deprecated code.

In answering the OP - myself and others have solved the **actual** issue they were facing, and also recommended they look at replacing the deprecated code.

A user though has downvoted all the answers given like this because they don't include a full example of the alternative, non-deprecated code - despite this not being the issue faced.

Is this fair use of the downvote feature when dealing with answers?

This is not a duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) - as this concerns answers **not** questions.

Comment: The whole thing looks like a typographical error, unlikely to help anyone anyway, which could explain why peole are downvoting.

Comment: Well, I don't hang out on the PHP and MySQL tags, so I don't know if this is par for the course or not, but when I look at the linked Q&A, it seems like it is in the running for "Worst of Stack Overflow, January 2017". I can easily see why someone would downvote *everything* there.

Comment: Interesting that this is first time ever one tries to read data from MySql using PHP... or maybe (just maybe) OP did not even try to search for similar questions nor tried to write code that at least *looks plausible*. I know nothing of PHP, but I seriously doubt arrays are constructed with `echo`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov they can be if your building a Javascript array via PHP code where you have to echo the javascript code, much like if you wanted to run a database Query with PHP without an AJAX call but have the query data accessible via Javascript. not the best way to do it (should really use AJAX to avoid malicous database inputs breaking the page) but it works

Answer (score 6):

> Is this fair use of the downvote feature?

Yes. They didn't target a person serially with that voting, and that's the only requirement.

Someone could downvote an answer of yours because the coffee they just had was a little bit too bitter.

The only requirement SE places on votes is to not serially vote on a person.

Now that doesn't mean you should go and downvote everything you fancy. If you'd like to be a *valueable* contributor to the site, downvote things that are unhelpful, poorly researched or wrong.

Comment: While it is true that you are *allowed* to downvote a post for a completely irrelevant reason, it is not true that you *should* do this. There is a difference between permissibility and appropriateness.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is. You can downvote from the moment you feel that an answer is bad.

In general, be careful when answering bad questions: bad questions can lead to wrong answers. It is sometimes better to vote to close a bad question instead of trying to answer (*see also [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)*)

---

Furthermore, from [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question
>   asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable
>   alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also
>   include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in
>   the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations,
>   assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable,
>   but fuller explanations are better. Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

---

Comment: I don't see how any of the answers given that were downvoted haven't adhered to those suggestions. Yes - an answers explaining the deprecated code would be better, but surely then that answer should be upvoted (which ironically it wasn't) rather than the others downvoted.

Comment: @thebluefox *You* think that the answer(s) were good answers.  That's your opinion.  Apparently others disagree and think that those aren't useful answers, in this case, by the sound of it, because they don't actually properly the question asked.  That's a sensible reason to downvote a post.  Factually correct information that doesn't answer the question *isn't a good answer*, and is a good reason to downvote a post.

Comment: They do asnwer the question asked, @Servy - they just don't fully address other issues that happen to be in the code example given by the OP. It's obvious I'm fighting a losing battle. I simply feel its a negative way of using the voting system.

Comment: @thebluefox Failing to address critical problems sure seems like a good argument for why a post isn't useful.  Votes are there to indicate that a post isn't useful.  They think that it's not useful, so they're using the voting system correctly.  Why you think a post that *isn't* useful should be upvoted, not downvoted, seems quite strange.  That'd be rather inconsiderate to all future readers who would end up being directed to an answer with critical problems in it.

Comment: @Servy My argument here isn't that these answers should be upvoted. I'll freely admit that the answers provided offered the bare amount required to _solve the OPs issue_. Any answer that went further than that and addressed other issues present, but not asked about, should rightly be upvoted as being the most useful answer.

Comment: @thebluefox So you realize that the answers aren't useful answers, but have a problem with them being downvoted to indicate that they're not useful answers, even though the purpose of downvotes is to indicate that an answer isn't useful?  Solving the problem *in a way that isn't useful* **isn't useful**, and indicating as much is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Again, I didn't say they weren't useful answers, I merely stated that other answers may be _more_ useful and therefore should be upvoted as such. An answer's usefulness stands in its own right, and should not be impacted by other answers.

Comment: @thebluefox *You* think it's useful.  Clearly someone else disagrees.  And no, an answer's usefulness *isn't* isolated.  An answer sitting next to a much better answer *makes that answer less useful*.  Other answers affect the opportunity cost of the answer you are voting on.  They could be reading that other, better, answer, instead of the answer you're voting on.  That *does* affect the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: @thebluefox Realistically I would expect there is canonical "read from MySql  in PHP" answer of *much* higher quality than answers posted in the linked question. So bar for "ok" answer would be quite high to start with and downvote for partially correct/not-the bets practices is quite justified in my opinion.

Answer (score -4):

Fair? Maybe not, but I do not think it's a matter of justice, and more about the awareness of who is voting.

If you think you gave a good answer, that may have helped other people, then do not worry with who are downvote you.

Comment: Obviously the down voters of this answer read something different in this, maybe due to the English grammar but I read it as *don't care too much about this down vote, if your answer is good, future visitors will up vote it*. Which is not a terrible point of view...

Comment: @rene Yeah I read that the same way it seemed to be a valid point

Comment: English is not my native language, but that's exactly what I meant.