# Down-voting to promote the right answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

There is an oldish question that is a valid question and the currently accepted answer is a hack and while it probably did work at one point, there is a far simpler and native fix proposed by someone else (I have no dog in this fight btw).

I commented on both the answer and question. I upvoted the right answer but I am wondering if it is 'proper' to downvote all the other solutions to help the right one float up top? I feel bad somehow down-voting answers...

Comment: Answers that aren't useful, are wrong, or are of poor quality all qualify for downvotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

Comment: True story but it still feels wrong downvoting an answer that either did work once or still does work just in a convoluted way. Yes technically 'poor quality' at the least.

Comment: why is it wrong to grade something that is bad as bad? We aim to build a long lasting repository of knowledge. With that in mind, a hack (when a better solution is available) isn't of great quality or really useful.

Comment: Kinda depends on the topic at hand. In some cases an older version of software X is still widely used, and therefore answers supporting it may still be useful, even if they aren't correct for the new version. Doesn't mean you can't downvote it because it isn't useful to you.

Comment: *"I feel bad somehow down-voting answers..."* Get out of here.  Leave.  Am disgusted with you.  Go to your room.

Comment: Answer doesn't work [anymore] and/or is overly complicated – what more reasons for downvoting do you need?

Comment: Both of the duplicate suggestions are wrong. This question doesn't mention the question quality as a factor at all. It even states "... that is a valid question".

Comment: The problem with a "hack" is that they tend to be hard to judge.  Do you *know* that it is inferior or do you assume that the answer you understand must be the better one?  Don't kill what you don't know, vote what you know, let that be the guide.

Comment: @Patrice something that might seem horrible practice today might have been completely legitimate at the time. Consider providing a helpful answer at 2010 that got outdated at 2011, doesn't make sense that people would continously keep downvoting you into the future, imo.

Answer (score 6):

> I am wondering if it is 'proper' to downvote all the other solutions to help the right one float up top?

No. I don't think so.

Your vote should reflect the quality of the post, strictly. Nothing else should matter. If the answer is otherwise not of poor quality, i.e. would not deserve a down-vote in isolation, then the fact that another answer is accepted and/or better in some way does not matter. It still doesn't deserve a down-vote.

Of course, conversely…if it does deserve a down-vote in and of itself, without consideration of other posts around it, by all means, help us out by improving the signal-to-noise ratio on the site and give a down-vote.

Judge each post on its own merits, good or bad.

Comment: Many times I've found solutions that are *not* the one with a mass of "this worked for me, other solutions are wrong" comments. So unless you are absolutely an expert, please don't. Especially if they comment "this is a hack". I recommend you comment saying "This is a valid hack but in $NewVersion, you can do ___