# Handling a user who downvotes *all* the answers out of spite

Tags: discussion, voting, behavior

This may not come often, but I still wonder. Some users have a pet peeve. It may be aimed at doubly tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) posts, or just an aversion to other ways in which posts are off-topic.

At times, they can systematically go around and downvote all the answers on a question due to said pet peeve. Of course I have no way of knowing for sure. But all the answers being downvoted in a matter of seconds, with correlation to said user's appearance makes me fairly confident it's them.

While it's the general consensus that their vote is their choice, I can't help but feel this sort of passive-aggressive behavior is damaging to the community. That we should discourage such vindictive behavior. If only to make SO more welcoming to those who are only starting their participation by answering.

Is there something that can or should be done?

Comment: Who are we to argue said user didn't find the answers not useful? or not of the quality standard they feel belongs? Just cast your vote and don't worry about the others. (unless you suspect something fraudulent is happening, in which case you can raise a custom flag and explain)

Comment: Lots of assumptions here, so it's hard to discuss.... what if this user sees a flaw in ALL the answers and downvotes for that reason? You might think it's a pet peeve.... he might be onto something :/.

Comment: Hmya, he is the Darth Vader of the [c/c++] tag.  I'd have to recommend *not* talking back to him, given that this seems to be the only reason he's still visiting SO.  Flag the obnoxious posts, moderators know him well and will get tired again having to deal with him.

Comment: @KevinB - All the answers proposed different approaches. Each valid and demonstrates a different approach to the problem.

Comment: @Patrice - The only thing the answers had in common is the question being answered

Comment: @StoryTeller And maybe this user is knowledgeable enough to see a different flaw in all of them. My point is that voting is a personal thing, so it's hard to pin down as "clear abuse" often :/ (according to Hans' comment there might be a history of abuse for this user though, which would make my point a bit invalid :P)

Comment: @Patrice - Without blowing my own trumpet, I'm fairly knowledgable about the topic myself.  There is no objective flaw in *all* the answers.

Comment: In most cases i've seen, this kind of voting is often due to a problem with the question that the voter feels the answers should have either waited for clarification or performed some moderation action instead (such as closure.) You could certainly argue that the answers to a useless question are not useful. whether or not that's right is a matter of opinion. Fortunately we only get 40 votes a day, at most 30 on answers, so the harm any one person can do is rather limited and easily outweighed by others voting.

Comment: @StoryTeller and you may be onto something, indeed. It's just hard to say since we don't know IF all these votes are theirs, or their reason for downvoting. (I do agree it looks fishy and weird though)

Comment: @StoryTeller What matters is whether or not an answer is *useful*, not whether or not an answer is objectively correct.  Even though you don't think there is any factually incorrect statements in those answers, whether they are *useful* answers to the question is highly subjective.  Or heck, maybe they're just mistaken in thinking that the answers have technical inaccuracies, in any case, your course of action, as mentioned by others, is to reflect your own opinion of the quality of the posts with your own vote, because you can't affect other's opinions or their ability to reflect them.

Comment: @Servy - They all solve the problem in the question. I fail to see how they can be considered not useful to the question, given that.

Comment: that's like just your opinion. My opinion is "correct" isn't a high enough bar for something to be useful. It's certainly an important aspect, but it's not the whole picture.

Comment: @StoryTeller Without knowing the question (and it not being my area of expertise) I couldn't comment on whether or not *I* think it's a useful answer.  The point remains though, *they* think it's not a useful answer.  You think it is useful.  You are both free to reflect that in your own votes.  Different people have differing opinions on what constitutes a quality/useful answer.  Note that "solves the problem" is also necessary but not sufficient for an answer to be useful.  Lots of answers solve the problem in  a way that's not useful (say if said answer has security vulnerabilities).

Comment: @KevinB - Being useful may be my opinion. Addressing the problem in the post is an objective fact.

Comment: As @Kevin said, in most of these cases the voter think that the problem lies with the question; and that most answers to bad questions are not useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller Right, and that's not what votes are for indicating.

Comment: @KevinB - TIL. As I recall SO was formed to provide an open platform for quality answers to programming related issues. When did a high degree of subjectivity (the "usefulness" each and every one us defines differently) become the major selling point?

Comment: The only guidance we have for upvotes and downvotes on answers is "usefulness," which in and of itself is entirely subjective.. For questions we get a little bit more guidance, in that we should downvote unclear or poorly researched questions as well as not useful questions.

Comment: @Kevin, not just StoryTeller's opinion.  When you get an answer from [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Becker) then just about everybody thinks that is a useful contribution.  And it was.  It is deleted now.  StoryTeller is trying to play it square and avoid naming names.  That's not helping him much.

Comment: @StoryTeller Quality is subjective.  If you want to have a repository of quality content, you need people to judge content for its quality, which means making subjective judgement calls on the quality of the content provided.  How would you intend to create a repository of quality content without having anyone judging the quality of the content?

Comment: @Servy - This is an industry with well established notions of "quality". The concept is heavily researched and mostly in concensus. I don't buy your argument.

Comment: @StoryTeller The fact that many people share an opinion doesn't make it a matter of fact, it just makes it an opinion that many people share.  Yes, you're right that many aspects of the field involve reasonably widespread consensus on what quality answers are to various problems.  That's why SO works, *usually* the community agrees on what a quality answer is.  That doesn't mean it's not subjective, or that everyone is *obligated* to agree with those common opinions (or even that every aspect of the field has a consensus).

Comment: As Hans points out, I have a pretty good idea of what question inspired this discussion and who might be behind these votes. Not hard to tell from the comments left there, and not the first time we've been flagged about them doing this. At this point, the only thing that would stop this behavior is suspending them from the site. The question is: is it suspension-worthy behavior if you punish everyone answering questions you don't like, even if the answers are well-written, on topic, and factually correct? The votes clearly aren't on the content of the answers, but no specific user is targeted.

Comment: @BradLarson: "*The question is: is it suspension-worthy behavior if you punish everyone answering questions you don't like, even if the answers are well-written, on topic, and factually correct?*" I would say yes. [Downvotes should not be used as a tool of *punishment*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/734069). They should show whether the content is good or not. You downvote content that isn't good. You upvote content that is good. Good content posted in response to bad content is *still good content*.

Comment: @KevinB: "*unless you suspect something fraudulent is happening, in which case you can raise a custom flag and explain*" If someone downvotes every answer but their own, we consider that fraud. If someone downvotes every answer from a certain person, we consider that fraud. If someone downvotes every answer from a certain tag, we should also consider that fraud, yes? And if someone downvotes every answer from a closed question, I don't see why that shouldn't be considered just as fraudulent. In all cases, they're using downvotes for something other than its intended purpose of grading content.

Comment: eh, i'd still argue that could be a form of grading the content.

Comment: @KevinB: It could be. And serial voting could also be someone who just happened to walk through someone's posting history and find fault with every answer they've ever posted. But the longer that goes on, the less likely it is to be true.

Comment: it's very difficult to walk through someone's post history without a bias, even if you're consciously trying to not be biased about it. You're there looking for trouble, and you'll likely find it. I think that's something that should be avoided, and if it gets caught by the filter, it probably should have been.

Answer (score 10):

I've taken the approach of downvoting every single wrong answer in a question, often because the question is *woefully* incomplete, or the advice being given out is just **garbage**.

It often is the case that "every single wrong answer" is "every answer".  More times than not, this accompanies a close vote on the question to make it clearer so that other answerers aren't getting spurned.  Additionally, I do leave comments on answers in those situations to explain what's going on.

This isn't me being passive-aggressive.  This is me sending the clear message, "Perhaps you shouldn't be answering this question until you either understand what's being asked", or "This answer is entirely incorrect."

Saying that this is done out of spite is presumptuous of you, and frankly insulting (although I take no real offense).  I don't do any of this to spite anyone.

Comment: And I sometimes pull up a user's activity page to monitor their edits. It's not fraud, it's that their edits are unhelpful.

Comment: The Quality Police is getting to be a pretty destructive force at SO.  You are just repeating the same tired old refrain, one that has done absolutely nothing noticeable about improving the site's quality.  Y'all just *hope* that it might do something, but you have no evidence at all that it does.  And, yet again, it did not.  The question was shite but it was answered by highly skilled experts.  There are few with more creds than Pete Becker, nobody should ever be deprived of his hotel towels.  It is really, *really* time to sing another song.  The old one is **not** working at all.

Comment: @StephenLeppik:  I've done that as well, *just* to establish a frame of reference as to what their edits are and what's going on with that noise.  It's happened more than once that I've questioned someone's edits.

Comment: @HansPassant:  The times that I've done this, I've *intentionally* and *deliberately* left really good answers alone.  I'm only handling the poor ones.  Note that also I neither know or nor care about the specific case being addressed here, since I wish to answer this in a more broad sense.  While I get you may not like what's playing on the radio, you haven't volunteered to change the station.  I'm up for a new tune if you've got one to play.

Comment: @Makoto: "*This is me sending the clear message*" That's really the big problem with using downvotes like this: you *aren't* sending a "clear" message. A downvote can happen for any number of reasons. Which means that the person receiving it can assume essentially *anything* about why that downvote happened. If the receiver of a message doesn't get the same message you sent, then the message *isn't clear*. Downvotes are a terrible means of message transmission. Or at least, it is for this message.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  I suppose it helps that, in those cases, I do leave a comment in to say, "Hey - this is wrong and this is why."  I don't mind adding that in to the answer above just to make it clearer.

Comment: @Makoto - I'm not asking about voting that looks normal. I myself have downvoted a bunch of answers on questions in the past. They all had the exact same mistake. In this case, the only common thread between these answers was the OP being answered. The only reason I came to suspect anything was because the person in question left an incredibly nitpicking comment. So either the person is **incredibly** narrow minded, or they have a bone to pick.

Comment: @HansPassant If you personally think that downvoting content that isn't useful isn't a good way to improve quality, and think that upvoting unhelpful content is a better way to increase the quality of the content on the site, other people won't be able to stop you.  But saying that you think the content should be upvoted just because of who the author is, rather than based on the usefulness of the post, is *actually* voting fraud.   You can personally say that you'd rather vote based on the author of the post than the usefulness of the post, but that's not what the site's policy says.

Answer (score 1):

We as a community give people wide latitude in their votes. While the text says "useful" vs "useless", people can use whatever reasoning they like to justify their own voting patterns.

At the same time, we recognize that certain voting patterns are malicious. We recognize at least the following cases to be fraudulent and therefore punishable:

- Strategic downvoting:

  - Downvoting answers other than your own.
  - Temporarily downvoting a competing answer.
- Downvoting a post because of the poster, rather than the content.
- Upvoting questions/answers from a friend.

But if you generalize these, what you come to realize is that, in all cases, the purpose of these votes is *not* to assess the content of the post. Strategic downvotes are done to improve one's own chances at upvotes, not to allow better information to outshine worse information. Punitive voting is done to punish/help a user, which is not necessarily beneficial towards adequately scoring the content.

Given this understanding, I would say that we can recognize other forms of fraudulent voting (even if it's not something that can be easily detected):

- Downvoting all answers/questions that deal with a particular tag. If I hate JavaScript, that doesn't give me the right to walk into the JavaScript tag and spend my 40 downvotes randomly downvoting them.
- Downvoting all answers to a question because of the subject matter of the question. If I am a C++ programmer with a hatred of all things C, I should not downvote an answer because the question asked about `printf`.

Is it easy to tell when any of these things happen? No. Voting is secret, after all, and you can't look into someone's head.

But that doesn't mean that they don't happen or that a *specific* case cannot be made that it has happened. I believe that these are offenses towards the site, and it should be reasonable for moderators to punish someone for misusing the site in such a way. So long as the moderators have collected sufficient evidence for it, of course.

Comment: First, was strategic downvoting really *punishable*? Second, what's wrong with downvoting because of a question's nature? If we make that punishable, does that mean that I shouldn't downvote the scores of "write my code for me" questions?

Comment: @StephenLeppik: "*Second, what's wrong with downvoting because of a question's nature?*" Perhaps "nature" is the wrong word. More "subject matter". I don't like immediate-mode OpenGL, and I think it does a disservice to the community to answer questions about it (thus enabling its use). Does that give me the right to downvote any content that talks about it?

Comment: @NicolBolas No. I'd say downvoting "because javascript" would be simply incorrect. not necessarily *fraudulent*, but if that's what someone's doing an employee would be able to tell. but what if by "nature" he meant the usefulness of the question? whether or not it's clear? whether or not it's asking for opinions, and the answers are all opinions? or requesting libraries and the answers are all library suggestions? i know that's not what happened in the case that spawned this question... but... it certainly happens. And i don't think that case is necessarily *incorrect*. certainly not fraud.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you're saying that if someone thinks that this content isn't useful, but you think it's useful, it's fraudulent of them to downvote that content?

Comment: @KevinB: "*I'd say downvoting "because javascript" would be simply incorrect. not necessarily fraudulent*" What exactly is the distinction between "incorrect" and "fraudulent"? If both of them are improper behavior that can get you banned, then they're essentially equivalent. We call serial voting "fraudulent"; by whatever reasoning that led us to do that, so too should "because JavaScript" voting be "fraudulent".

Comment: @NicolBolas Fraud comes with the side effect of personal gain. Downvoting all javascript answers provides no personal gain.

Comment: @KevinB: Downvoting all answers by a particular person has no (objective) personal gain either. Yet serial downvoting is considered "fraud".

Comment: Maybe it's simply mislabeled.

Comment: @NicolBolas serial downvoting is usually acting on a grudge.

Comment: serial upvoting is usually fraud. serial downvoting is likely just lumped into the same boat because it's caught by the same algorithm. Any voting activity directed at the user rather than the content is wrong.

Comment: @KevinB: But does that mean voting activity directed at a question's subject matter is OK?

Comment: @NicolBolas that wouldn't be based on the content of the post being voted on. but with answers, you do still need to consider whether or not it's appropriate for the question that was asked, as that's part of whether or not it's useful.

Comment: @KevinB: How is the subject matter of a question not part of its content? I put forward the `printf` example because I once had a policy of downvoting any answer that suggested using `sprintf` (a well-known security flaw; all instances of this function should be replaced by `snprintf`). That sounds like voting based on content. But what if I downvoted all answers on a question about `sprintf` that *didn't* suggest that they switch to `snprintf`?

Comment: If you're voting solely based on the existence of a tag or function, that's obviously not voting based on the content of the answer. It's no better than voting on the user's reputation.

Comment: @KevinB - And yet, that is the case at hand

Comment: @KevinB How is the example described not voting based on the usefulness of the answer?  You're asserting that they think the content isn't useful, and they're voting the content down *because they think it's not useful*.  How is that not voting based on the usefulness of the answer?  That's just you saying you disagree with their opinion of the usefulness of the answer, not that they're voting based on anything other than the answer's usefulness.

Comment: @KevinB: So you're saying that it's OK for users to arbitrarily declare that any answer which contains a certain technology is useless and therefore downvote-worthy? I have a hard time seeing that as something other than an abuse of the system.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you're saying that it's an abuse of the system for someone to think that a group of posts is useless when you personally think that it's useful?  That's an odd way to define abuse of the system.  Abuse of the system (with respect to voting) is defined as voting on a post based on something other than it's usefulness.  If someone really thinks the post isn't useful, they're not being abusive by reflecting that opinion with a vote.  You just think they're wrong (and you're allowed to think they're wrong and reflect your own opinion with your own vote).

Comment: @Servy: "*So you're saying that it's an abuse of the system for someone to think that a group of posts is useless when you personally think that it's useful?*" No. I'm saying it's an abuse of the system to use it to promote your own personal views, rather than making at least an *attempt* to be *objective*. That is, if your assessment of the "usefulness" of the material is bound purely by subjective impressions that are not necessarily relevant to other people, then it's wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas Your vote exists to express your own personal opinion of the usefulness of the post.  Your votes aren't there to express someone else's opinion of the usefulness of the post.  The whole idea of voting is that every casts their own votes based on what they, personally, think is useful, and the things that the most people think are useful rise to the top.  People *are* allowed to have differing opinions on whether or not a given post is useful.

Comment: @Servy: "*Your vote exists to express your own personal opinion of the usefulness of the post.*" If it's just your personal opinion, why is voting visible to other people? The purpose of voting is to have a quick way to see the assessment of others on the question. Therefore, ones vote *must* be based on things that are germane and useful to *other people*. I don't care if someone has a personal mad-on for people who answer bad questions or users of `printf`; I don't need to see those votes. I need to see the votes of people who are self-aware enough to take their ego out of their assessments.

Comment: Yes, people are allowed to have different opinions. But there's a difference between a valid difference of opinion, based by rational ideas and perspectives, and someone who has a viewpoint and wants to promote it through whatever means are available.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you don't think it's useful to see what other people's opinion of the usefulness of an answer is, then you're free to ignore a posts score and not take other's opinions of the usefulness of an answer into question.  Other people have found that seeing the opinions of others on the quality of a post is useful to them, and so they consider a posts score.  Again, you can think that an individual's opinion on the usefulness of a post is wrong, or even that they're judgement of posts in general is wrong.  That doesn't make their votes fraudulent.

Comment: @Servy: You're missing my point. There are good opinions and bad ones. We don't want people to vote based on bad opinions, as this tarnishes the usefulness of voting. Downvotes because you think answers to bad questions are a priori useless is a bad opinion, as is downvotes because you think `printf` is useless.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're missing my point.  You're more than welcome to think that someone else's opinion is a bad opinion, and you're more than welcome to use what you think are good opinions when you cast your own votes.  Someone else is not committing voting fraud just because you think their opinion is a bad opinion, just like *you* aren't committing voting fraud just because they think you're voting based on bad opinions.  Everyone gets to vote based on their own opinion of the usefulness of the post, and no one's vote is fraudulent just because someone else doesn't like it.

Comment: @Servy: "*You're more than welcome to think that someone else's opinion is a bad opinion*" There's a distinction between "I don't agree with that" and "that's a bad opinion". The former represents things you can debate over, matters of perspective and reasonable discourse. The latter represents things that are purely subjective without any critical thinking behind them. "because it uses `printf`" is the latter, not the former. We should not encourage people to vote due to the latter. Oh sure, we can't *stop them*, but we shouldn't act like things we can't stop are OK.

Comment: @NicolBolas We encourage people to vote based on what they think is actually useful.  We don't tell people to vote against what they think is useful just because someone else disagrees with them over whether or not something is useful.  No, you *don't* get to say that you *ought* to be able to stop people from voting in ways that you personally don't like, but that for practical reasons we can't.  If someone was actually voting on a post for some reason other than whether or not they think it's useful, then *that* is something that we can say we wish we could stop, even if we can't do it.

Comment: @Servy: The problem is that "useful" is sufficiently subjective that you can use it to justify almost *anything*. A single misspelled word? That's "not useful", since it makes the answer hard to read. You used the C-standard library in an answer to a C++ question? That's "not useful" because the C-standard library is stupid. And so on. Voting for reasons that other people are unlikely to agree with makes voting useless as a marker for whether an answer is good or not. Voting only works when people have at least broad agreement on what up and down mean.

Comment: @NicolBolas Providing unpopular opinions isn't useless, nor is it in any way inappropriate.  You can say as much as you want that you disagree with a given opinion, but you can't say that anyone is acting inappropriately merely because their opinion is unpopular.  You apparently don't like seeing unpopular opinions.  That's fine, you don't have to take them into consideration, but that doesn't make it wrong for someone to have an unpopular opinion, or to reflect it in their vote.

Comment: @Servy: Why are you talking about popular vs. unpopular opinion? Nobody but you ever brought up popularity. You seem to have erected some strawman version of my argument. I am not talking about "popularity" of opinions; I'm talking about *quality* of opinions. The opinion that is the C-standard library is useless is not a *good* opinion. It's not an opinion based on a well-reasoned argument; it's based on uncritical ideology. Voting should not be used to promote personal ideology; that doesn't improve the site.

Comment: @NicolBolas *You* are the one that brought up popularity.  You're the one that says that someone who's shared an opinion that other people are unlikely to agree with makes voting useless, and that voting only works when everyone agrees.  You don't get to decide whose opinion's are good and whose are bad, just as other people don't get to decide which of *your* opinions are good and which are bad.  Everyone gets to reflect their own opinion, regardless of what everyone else thinks of it.

Comment: @Servy: "*You don't get to decide whose opinion's are good and whose are bad*" Sure I do. Everyone does. Opinions get accepted or disregarded all the time. The question is whether you can reasonably objectively assess the opinions of others. "*just as other people don't get to decide which of your opinions are good and which are bad.*" And yet *you just did that*. You put forth an argument about my opinion.

Comment: @Servy: "*that voting only works when everyone agrees*" I said, "when people have at least broad agreement on what up and down mean". That's not the same thing as "popularity". Have you ever looked at an upvoted question and thought, "what the hell was the voter *thinking*?" Have you ever looked at a downvoted answer and thought, "what the hell was the voter thinking?" When that happens, the system is not working. It's not about agreement with the vote itself; I've seen posts that were downvoted which I wouldn't downvote, but I could at least understand *why* someone would vote that way.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, you can think that someone else's opinions are bad all that you want, just as other people can think that your opinions are bad as much as *they* want.  No one can say someone else isn't allowed to have a given opinion, or that they're not "good enough" to be able to reflect their own opinion in their own vote.

Comment: @NicolBolas Upvoting means the voter thinks the post is useful, and downvoting means the voter thinks the post isn't useful.  Everyone (other than you, who thinks that certain other people shouldn't be allowed to downvote posts that they think aren't useful) seems to agree on that.  Yes, I've seen *many* posts where I disagreed with other people's opinions of it's usefulness.  And when that happens, unlike you, I don't claim that those other people are committing voting fraud and should be punished just for reflecting an opinion that I disagree with.  I cast my own vote and move on.

Comment: @Servy: "*other than you, who thinks that certain other people shouldn't be allowed to downvote posts that they think aren't useful*" Again, the strawman. This is not about "certain other people". It's about "reasons for voting". You seem to have this binary mode of thinking, where if something is not OK to do, then we *must* punish people for doing it. And if we can't punish people for it, then it *must* be OK to do. There's plenty of grey area there, where things that are not punishable are still negatively useful for the site.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, you're not saying certain people shouldn't be able to vote, you're saying that people shouldn't be allowed to express opinions that you don't like.  It doesn't change the point though.  Even though you think it's not practical to enforce the fact that people shouldn't be allowed to downvote a post that they think is not useful if you personally disagree with their opinion, you're still saying that it's wrong for other people to express an opinion that you personally don't like.  It *is* appropriate for them to express their opinion, even if you don't like it.

Comment: @Servy: OK, then please explain how it makes the site better to have people downvoting technology they don't like. How does this help objectively good content supercede bad content? We aren't here so that every special little snowflake can express their own personal opinion. We're here to help create a useful knowledge base of information. And some opinions are *not helpful* towards that end. The purpose of having question/answer scores is to make the distinction between good and bad content clear. Any vote made for a reason that *doesn't* achieve that end is unhelpful.

Comment: @NicolBolas The whole premise of the site is that everyone is able to reflect their own opinions of the quality of a post, and that, *in aggregate*, the best posts will rise to the top.  We're not here so that Nicol Bolas can be the sole arbiter of what posts are good and bad, and that everyone who has a differing opinion isn't welcome to reflect it.  Not everyone will agree about everything, and that's okay.  You can think that someone's vote isn't helpful, and that's okay, but they still get to reflect their own opinion, even if you don't like it.

Comment: @Servy: You've dodged the question. How does it help the site to have people downvoting technology they don't like?

Comment: @NicolBolas It helps the site because it's more useful for everyone to be allowed to reflect their own opinion, and for people to make their decisions off of evaluating the opinions of *everyone* who has chosen to reflect one, than for one person to get to decide which opinions can and can't be shared, and for certain voices to not be allowed to be heard because it's a dissenting opinion.

Comment: @Servy: You could use the same reasoning to justify downvoting all answers other than your own: it is your opinion that all other answers are inferior and therefore should be downvoted. We don't consider that helpful towards the site.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you're voting because  you honestly think all of the other answers are not helpful, then you're correct.  If you're downvoting because you want your own post to appear above them *even though you don't think those posts aren't helpful*, then no, my argument doesn't apply to such a situation, as they're not reflecting their opinion of the usefulness of the post.

Comment: @Servy: And such a person can always claim that they're just downvoting unhelpful answers. They may even *believe* that. That still doesn't make it right.

Comment: @Servy: "*than for one person to get to decide which opinions can and can't be shared, and for certain voices to not be allowed to be heard because it's a dissenting opinion.*" Can you please stop building this army of strawmen to defeat? This is not about what "one person" wants or shutting down "dissenting opinion". This is about shutting down opinions that *don't help the site*, that make no attempt to objectively address the quality of the post.

Comment: @NicolBolas If they *do* believe it, then it is right.  If they don't believe it, then it isn't right.  That's because it's right for people to downvote posts that they think aren't useful, and it's not right for people to downvote posts that they don't think are useful.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, it's about shutting down opinions that *you personally think* don't help the site, and that other people think *do* help the site.  Determining the quality of a post *is inherently subjective*.  It's not *possible* to have an objective opinion (by definition in fact) *that's what makes it an opinion*.

Comment: @Servy: "*No, it's about shutting down opinions that you personally think don't help the site*" If they do help the site, then you should be able to explain how, beyond your belief that all opinions are equally valid. "*Determining the quality of a post is inherently subjective.*" Subjectivity and objectivity are not binary. Any human judgement will be subjective. But there is a difference between the *purely* subjective and subjective ideas that have objective defenses beyond mere personal preference.

Comment: @NicolBolas I *did* explain why they help the site.  The site is *better off* when people are all able to reflect their own opinions than when one person gets to decide who does and doesn't get to reflect their own opinions.  Votes are there to be cast based on whether the voter feels that the post is useful or not useful, and restrictions are not given as to what arguments they are and are not allowed to consider when determining a posts's usefulness.  You're free to use the metrics you feel are most appropriate, and others are allowed to choose their own.

Comment: @Servy: But since I'm not proposing that "one person gets to decide who does and doesn't get to reflect their own opinions", your argument misses the mark. So again, how does it help the site?

Comment: @NicolBolas But you are.  You're saying that you don't like someone else's judgement of the usefulness of posts, so they shouldn't be able to reflect their opinion on the usefulness of posts.  it helps the site to reflect their opinion because it's harmful for the site to let one person decide who gets to reflect their opinion, and gives less information to people looking to evaluate posts as they're refused access to certain people's opinions just because you don't like those opinions.

Comment: @Servy: "*You're saying that you don't like someone else's judgement of the usefulness of posts*" No, I'm saying that certain kinds of judgements are not productive or helpful towards the sites ends. That's a very different statement than merely not liking something. I've explained why I think those judgements are not productive or helpful. You haven't explained why they are productive or helpful; all you've said is that putting *any* limitations on judgements is bad. That's ideology, not reasoning.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, you've just said *that* you think certain kinds of opinions aren't helpful.  That's ideology, not reasoning.  If you don't think it's helpful for people to be able to see the opinion's of others, and if you don't think that that's helpful for them when evaluating posts, then why do we have voting in the first place?  You personally don't find certain types of opinions helpful, and other people find entirely different types of opinions helpful, neither of you get to decide who gets to reflect their opinions though.

Comment: @Servy: "*No, you've just said that you think certain kinds of opinions aren't helpful.*" I've explained throughout these comments exactly why those opinions aren't helpful. I'll summarize: voting based on purely personal biases makes it difficult to use vote totals to adequately assess the *actual* quality of a post. If a post is at -1, that doesn't mean it's bad; it may mean that someone didn't like the use of `printf` or whatever. That's not an opinion which is useful to anyone other than that person, so having it reflected in the score doesn't help others assess the quality of the post.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's just saying that if people vote based on an opinion that you disagree with, you personally think that the score of the post isn't in line with what you think it should be.  If you *prohibit* that person from voting, then *they* will feel that the post's score doesn't reflect its actual quality/usefulness.  So why would the site be better off *for everyone, not just you personally*, if people that disagree with your opinion on the quality of a post would be prohibited from voting?  In other words, why is your personal opinion on the quality of posts better than others'?

Comment: @Servy: "*That's just saying that if people vote based on an opinion that you disagree with*" ***NO IT'S NOT!*** I personally believe that C++ iostreams is a garbage API. But that doesn't mean I believe that downvoting all answers that use iostreams is a good thing. I can agree with the opinion behind the downvote, but that doesn't mean that I agree with the act of downvoting it for that reason.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you personally believe that the posts in that tag are useful, you're free to reflect that opinion.  If someone else feels that those posts *aren't* useful, they can reflect *their* opinion.  So again, why is the site better off if you're allowed to dictate whether or not someone else is allowed to provide feedback on what they think of the usefulness of the post?  Sure, you naturally think that the posts you think are useful are useful, and the posts that you think aren't useful aren't useful, but everyone who disagrees with you thinks that *their* opinions are right.

Comment: @NicolBolas So why does your opinion get to win over anyone else's?  Why do you get to be the arbiter of what opinions are allowed to be reflected and which ones aren't?

Comment: @Servy: "*why is the site better off if you're allowed to dictate whether or not someone else is allowed to provide feedback on what they think of the usefulness of the post*" Again, this is *not about me*. Stop making this personal. I'm trying to put forth an objective standard which can be applied to ensure that votes are meaningful.

Comment: @NicolBolas There already is a standard.  Users are expected to upvote posts that they think are useful, and to downvote posts that they think *aren't* useful.  That's the standard.  You're the one who's trying to say that because you personally disagree with someone over whether or not certain posts are useful, they shouldn't be allowed to cast their votes.  If you want to propose that we should be voting on something other than the what the voter thinks of the usefulness of the post, then what should it be?

Comment: @Servy: A simple standard would be "useful *to others*". The point being to not focus on one's personal preferences but instead think about what is good content for the "not you" demographic. By that standard, downvoting because you're on one side of a tech debate is wrong, since you're voting based on your biases rather than anything that's at least *trying* to be objective.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you think that they should only downvote the posts if they think that that content isn't going to be useful to other people, and that as long as they personally think that the content isn't useful to others, it's appropriate to downvote?  Sure, I took it as implicit in my previous comment that it was usefulness in general, not just usefulness for the voter, but  yes, you shouldn't downvote a post that isn't useful to you personally but that you think would be useful to others in general.  You should only downvote a post if you think that it's not useful *in general*.

Answer (score -3):

Downvoting all of a question's answers does not mean that they hate the question. It means that, in their eyes, none of the answers are worth a damn. Just remember that they're spending rep for each downvote.

Is it vindictive? Maybe. Is that wrong? No. *Wrong* would be, for example, threatening to track down the answerer and murder their family while they sleep. That is, *abusive*.

The one thing you could do would be, @reply them and invite them to offer a bounty if they don't like the existing answers.

Comment: "*It means that, in their eyes, none of the answers are worth a damn.*" It *may* mean that. It may also mean that they don't want the question answered. And there are people on this site who will do exactly that. Unless you're saying that, if I go through your history and downvote every answer, that merely means that in my eyes, none of your answers are worth a damn.

Comment: @NicolBolas how exactly would downvoting every answer stop answers from being on the question?

Comment: Yeah - doesn't make sense.  If I don't think that the question belongs on SO, I vote to close it or, if/when appropriate, vote for deletion.

Comment: @StephenLeppik: It doesn't necessarily do that. But it does punish them for doing so. And again, downvoting answer to punish answerers is a thing that happens.

Comment: @NicolBolas And since we currently don't have mind reading technology, we can't know why someone is voting the way they are.  If you're going to accuse them of having some particular intent with their vote, the burden of proof is on you to show that it's the case.

Comment: so lets say i downvote all the answers on a duplicate question. Prove that i did it to punish the answers rather than to indicate that I found the answers not useful. Sure, that's a very poor use of the limited votes available considering the question will likely not be deleted, but is it fraudulent? Now apply the same thought to an unclear question. or a low quality question.

Comment: @Servy: We seem to have some form of mind-reading technology. Because we have scripts to check for serial voting. That is, a sequence of voting that is aimed at a person, rather than at the content. How does it do that? It sees that you're casting votes on that person's stuff disproportionately. And we have no problem suspending people for doing so. I'm not saying it's *easy* to prove that something like this happens. But we should not pretend that it doesn't, nor should we assume that it is valid behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas In the one an only case of actual voting fraud recognized by the system, we do it in cases where there *is* significant and compelling evidence that the votes weren't cast based on the quality of the content in question.  So, as I said before, you have a significant burden of proof to demonstrate that these votes weren't cast based on the usefulness of the posts.

Comment: @Servy: How many votes does it take before the evidence is "significant and compelling"? Is there a number? A percentage? Or is it locked behind an algorithm we're not allowed access to? I'm not saying that we should develop some algorithm to find the type of voting discussed by the OP. I'm saying we should not *dismiss the possibility* of what the OP says being what happened. And that we should make it clear that, even though we cannot prove it in all cases, it's not something people ought to do.

Comment: you can't reply to downvoters, you have no idea who they are

Comment: @KeithNicholas in this case, the downvoter identified themself.

Comment: what case?  I don't see a referenced question?

Comment: @NicolBolas It's not a question of number of votes.  The community has come to the consensus that someone who just goes through someone else's profile and downvotes a whole bunch of their posts is extremely likely to not be evaluating the quality of those posts, and is instead voting based on a factor other than the post's usefulness, and there is enough data to make a reasonably likely assumption as to when someone isn't actually evaluating the usefulness of the post.

Comment: @StephenLeppik In this case it was stated that it is merely the meta OP's suspicion, so no, the downvoter has not identified themselves (at least given what's included in this meta question, it doesn't go into much detail).

Comment: @Servy: But that's not how the script works. If you just so happen to frequent the tag of another user, and you downvote every post that user makes, that too is serial voting. It doesn't matter if you find the post though their profile or because you happen to be in similar circles; it's still serial voting.

Comment: @NicolBolas As long as you're voting on a post's **content** (which it would be if were merely similar circles) then there is **absolutely nothing** wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas There are numerous factors that it takes into consideration when determining if the votes are fraudulent (although, as mentioned, the specifics are not public), and it's not just how many votes were cast on a given user.  It also considers the times of the votes as well.  Yes, you are correct that the script only determines a high *probability* that the votes weren't cast based on the posts' usefulness, and there are (hopefully sufficiently rare) false positives.  It's also why the votes are merely reverted, and no further action is taken.

Comment: So, can you come up with some other metric by which we can determine, *with a very high probability*, that a given set of votes were not in fact cast based on the voter's opinion of the usefulness of the posts?  It doesn't need to be perfect, but it should be quite low on false positives.

Comment: @StephenLeppik You are correct that it's not voting fraud in such cases.  What it is is an unfortunate case of a false positive in the vote fraud detection script.  The script *does* have false positives, and it's unfortunate, but they're infrequent enough, and the consequences for being wrong are low enough, that the community as a whole considers it an acceptable cost for having a voting script around to handle all of the cases it gets right.

Comment: @Servy: My whole point in bringing up the serial voting script was to show that we don't need to read the person's mind to find such misuses of the site; just the person's voting patterns. A distinction needs to be made between "stuff we don't want people to do" and "stuff that can easily be policed". Just because it's difficult in general to police what the OP is alleging, that doesn't mean it's OK to do it. Nor does it mean that it's wrong to flag the moderators if you have some reasonable evidence (as in this case) that it's going on.

Comment: I thought threatening to track down the answerer and murder their family while they sleep was how we showed appreciation for their answer... wait... no... that's upvotes, nevermind.

Comment: @TinyGiant - What are upvotes?

Comment: @StephenLeppik - I'm sorry, but after re-reading your answer, I'm kinda shocked you consider vindictive behavior as broadly acceptable. Is this really what you meant to say?

Comment: @StoryTeller we can't do anything about it, but you have every right to hate it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik - Not being able to stop something doesn't make it "not wrong". A person can hide their online trail via various nefarious means and come back to threaten someone repeatedly on SO. We can't stop someone so determined either. Does that make it "not wrong" anymore? Ability to police a behavior and it's qualitive properties have little correlation.

Comment: @NicolBolas And yet you've failed to provide *any* metric for determining that someone is highly likely to have been voting on something other than the usefulness of the post.  So again, you have no evidence that this person isn't actually voting on the usefulness of the post.  The opposite is in fact the case, you've said right in your answer that you think that they think the posts aren't useful, so *you* think they're not voting fraudulently, you just disagree with them over whether or not the posts are useful.

Comment: You can't ping a user who only downvoted, by the way. They'd have to have posted a comment first. And then you have to make that assumption that the commenter is also the downvoter.

Comment: @StoryTeller think about it like this: you might think it's wrong, but the moderators of this site probably disagree. You can't ban a legitimately useful user just for having a style that you don't like.

Comment: This is a community moderated site. We make policy and feature requests here, you know. That's part of what meta is for, after all. You are suggesting I should what, appeal to authority? That's not the spirit of SO, as I learned to see it.