# How to deal with answers to unanswerable questions?

Tags: discussion

I often come across questions where the OP does not provide enough information to craft a proper answer (see a recent [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978204/passing-data-array-to-funcion-angular-5)).

In my opinion, there's absolutely no way to properly answer such questions without the author providing more context or more information about the problem they are facing. Quite often, the question receives a number of downvotes and/or gets closed, which seems a reasonable thing to do (provided that an explanation is given as to why the question was closed, so that new users can learn from their mistakes).

However, sometimes this is not the case, and a bunch of answers appear, providing potential solutions while trying to guess what exactly the OP meant (see the link above for an example). One of those answers might, in fact, help the author, but I'm wondering what the best course of action is here.

Comment: _a bunch of answers appear, providing potential solutions_ you can vote on the answers if you think they arent helpful

Comment: @yivi Op seems to be asking regarding the "answers" that appear for such questions

Comment: @SurajRao sure, but there's no way for me (or anybody) to know if such answers are helpful or not (unless they are incorrect). To me, those answers should not even be there in the first place

Comment: @SurajRao You are right. My bad. Earl-gray concentration hasn't reached optimum levels yet.

Comment: Still, closing the question as quickly as possible is the way to go. So no more of this answers proliferate.

Comment: Sadly upvoted answers will protect the question from roomba. For that reason is very important to vote both on questions and answers to signal quality.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: *Answers should be voted up or down on their own merits.* let's take the example I linked, how would you rate the merit of the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Are those answers useful, according to you? If you believe they aren't useful, downvote. It doesn't need to get any more complicated than that.

Comment: @yivi if I had to give an answer, I would say no, they're not. Simply because there's no way to know whether they address the problem or not. I guess the best thing to do is simply to downvote them then

Comment: If these answers aren't useful, and the question is indeed off-topic; by closing the latter and downvoting all the posts that aren't useful you are clearing the way for deleting the whole thing further on if it doesn't get better; giving feedback that's useful for future visitors, and giving feedback to the OP so they know that they might need to improve their question. Voting is important.

Comment: There should be some kind of punishment for answering bad questions.  eg If a question gets downvoted and closed, then the answers all get the same number of downvotes applied by the system.  That'll serve them right.

Comment: @JK. that sounds a bit drastic, but having something similar in place would not be a bad idea

Comment: No, @bugs, but it might be a bit over the top if we say for example tracked down anyone who answered a bad question and put a dunce hat on them. I'd settle for having them automatically banned from answering questions instead.

Comment: If people are guessing at what the question meant, then it was asked in an unclear way, and the question should be flagged as such. If it is a well asked unanswerable question (something that I can't think of a good example for but I can imagine it's possible to ask one), then it is probably useful because people with the same issue will be able to find the post and learn that it is unanswerable -- A good answer to such a question would be an explanation of why the question doesn't work or cannot be answered.

Comment: I ususally leave a comment to ask for clarification, but not everyone can – you need a certain amount of reputation before you are allowed to comment (which I'd forgotten about and had to be reminded of by friends for whom the only way to contribute right now is to leave answers based on guesses at what an OP meant). The question you linked is, in fact, a very good example for this scenario: the accepted answer was provided by someone who currently only has 26 reputation.

Comment: @Kay, that's not the only way to contribute they have if they do not have enough rep to comment yet.. They an answer questions were guessing is not necessary, suggest edits, ask good questions... any of these things will take them quickly beyond the threshold for commenting. If they **do not want to do that**, they shouldn't be posting answers based on guesses, because those aren't useful contributions to the site.

Comment: @yivi I didn't say it was the only way to contribute, but that it's the only way for _these friends of mine_ to contribute right now. Not everyone can afford to "hang out" on SO until suitable questions come along / to be among the first to answer new questions. Comments/assumptions like yours (which basically imply these people are lazy or cannot be bothered) are actually what discourages some of them from participating in platforms like SO in the first place.

Comment: @Kay, I think that you said _"this is the only way they have to contribute right now"_, and I believe that's false. I'm not saying that your friends are lazy, I do not know anything about them. I'm telling you that you shouldn't be saying that is true that "posting answers as guesses" is a valid contribution method, when it's not useful.

Comment: I never said anything about "valid", I just contributed an insight which hadn't been brought up before. Namely that leaving comments – which is my preferred way of getting OPs to clarify confusing/unclear questions – is a tool that is not available to everyone. In any case, as the linked example shows, contributions can be considered "valid" or helpful by some users even if others believe they were only "guesses" (which they might or might not have been).

Comment: Related: [Real questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: Something else which hasn't been mentioned yet, which some commenters might not be able to understand based on limited or non-existent personal experience: sometimes questions are unclear because the OP doesn't know how to properly express what they want to say in English. Native speakers of English seem to have a harder time making sense of those than other non-native speakers. I've also seen seasoned devs not getting questions by beginners whose tech vocab was lacking (but intermediate devs being able to "translate" them alright). Maybe not all answers you think are guesses actually are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know these situations and this is my personally preferred course of action:

1. Leave a comment on the question requiring clarification (and possibly giving some guidance about what is needed ... sometimes, mentioning `[mcve]` is enough)
2. Downvote the question and vote to close (both can and should be reversed if the question is indeed improved)
3. Also **downvote answers that contain blind guessing**. Leave a comment explaining that, a good reference is [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the section about answering *well-asked* questions. This may sound harsh, but **even if this answer helped the OP**, that **doesn't make it a good answer**. The simple reason is that it's very unlikely to help future readers. Voting is the most direct feedback, so use it.

   if the person answering is still new to the site, I like to add some appreciation for his efforts in general and just explain his time spent would be more useful by focusing on "better" questions.

Note on 3.: Before downvoting, be sure you actually have enough tag specific knowledge to judge it really **is** blind guessing. If in doubt, let others decide.

Comment: @PatrickParker well, you should of course have enough specific knowledge to decide whether it's **blind** guessing or not ... I can't decide that on the question linked by the OP, but I sure can very often in the C tag, for example -- I added some more text, it's a good catch!

Comment: I agree with the note you added, but I think as long as the assumptions are clearly stated at the top of the answer it should not be down-voted on a "guessing" basis

Comment: @PatrickParker Well, it should depend on how "obvious" the guess is. I don't think the Q&A would benefit from a lot of answers being written by just guessing something, even when explicitly stated. But of course, if the guess is something quite common and happening all the time (like e.g. a missing string terminator in C), this would be fair game.

Comment: After all, I'm convinced it would lead to more quality if people would **always** wait for clarification if a question isn't clear enough yet. But I admit there can be exceptions to that.

Comment: "Before downvoting, be sure you actually have enough tag specific knowledge" - Many users *don't know what they don't know*. So this is dangerous. [Excellent post here](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/so-bounties/) discusses trigger-happy VTC & DV.

Comment: @jpp there are no doubt psychological effects causing bad decisions from time to time. But I'd argue if you stop to trust in people's judging and self-judging abilities *in general*, you're ultimately questioning this whole reputation based moderation model.

Comment: There's a problem with the note to point 2: [there are no effective measures to keep an eye on the question to "reverse" things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366406/how-to-deal-with-answers-to-unanswerable-questions#comment577125_366427).

Answer (score 2):

If it is impossible to ascertain which, if any, of the solutions solve the OP's problem, then one option is to **wait until there is clarity**. You can **comment** to seek clarification. Clarity often arrives, as in this case, when an answer is accepted.

At this point, you may **edit the question** to make the question clear. At the same time, you may decide to upvote / downvote answers accordingly.

The fact you are asking this question suggests you care about SO as a Q&A resource. By taking the above steps you are helping improve the quality of the Q&A.

---

If after an answer is accepted the Q&A is still unsalvageable, then you should **vote to close** and downvote the question. You may also downvote answers if you think they are unhelpful.

Comment: This seems to indicate that asking an unclear question is okay, as are answers which merely guess at the answer instead of/in addition to comments seeking clarification, since all will come clear once the OP decides to grace us with their acceptance of an answer. Seems kind of backwards.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, My answer takes OP's specific scenario as a starting point, where there are lots of answers and perhaps one has been accepted. You're right, commenting is good too - and I will edit that in. If the question is salvageable, salvage it. If not, vote to close & downvote. If you don't care, do neither. Some of the best questions, in my experience, are *salvaged questions*.

Answer (score -1):

If a question is impossible to answer, it's close-worthy because it has no value for the core goal of SO -- to provide practical solutions to recurring programming problems.

**Vote to close as whatever reason is most appropriate** (most probably, "unclear" or "no MCVE" in your case). You can downvote for being "unclear or not useful", too.<sup>1</sup>

If you see enough potential in the question to justify spending more of your time, also **explain in a comment**, concisely, that it's impossible to answer as it is, and what info is required to make that possible.

---

Previously, I tried to skirt this issue by giving a *"partial answer"*: answer what is possible and explain that the rest is impossible without more info (mentioning what kind of into that is).

Practice showed, however, that such answers are not useful in the long run:
they don't really solve any problem, and are not reusable 'cuz each such question is missing its unique part of info. So they have no value in the light of the aforementioned core SO goal -- and thus are not worthy to be here.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Because downvotes will stick even after an improvement, it's not useful to downvote it to oblivion though. Just a small negative score proportional to the question's hideousness will carry a message that the OP did a sloppy job and thus wasted community's resources (and also, perhaps even more importantly, that we do not take kindly to that, so they should do better next time without further poking), but there may yet be hope for their question if they improve it well enough and fast enough.</sub>

Comment: Please don't argue against (down)voting in general. People should be **encouraged** to vote, and voting shouldn't be based on the score shown but on the content. Scores will "self-adjust" if enough people are willing to vote and the question is edited in time. This is because a) the question will pop up again in the "recent" list and b) it's possible to revise a vote after every edit (which you should do if you commented to request clarification).

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's not possible to revise your downvotes after an edit because there's no notification. [The corresponding feature request was declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c), so we have to deal with the votes sticking for this reason somehow.

Comment: sure it is. Why do you need a notification for it? If you were just browsing and downvoting "on the go", that's fine ... others will upvote "on the go" once the question reappears in the recent list in good shape. If you actually requested clarification, I'd say you should have an eye on that question, at least for *some* time.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Likewise, [a feature request to be able to effectively "keep an eye of a question" was declined (well, officially, "deferred" indefinitely)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you). So, I likewise invented a way around: let others take charge in my place when they see the edited question.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't ever upvote questions that have a positive score already either -- The OP might always edit the question and make it a bad or otherwise useless question, and since my upvote would stick...

Comment: @DavyM I think you can answer that yourself...