# When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement, welcoming

Yes, it's another meta question about the ["Stack Overflow isn't very welcoming" blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

As someone who has been on this site for almost a decade, who has tried to post good questions, who has voted on content, who has worked the queues, all in the name of keeping the site's quality up... Jay Hanlon's post is an affront.

It tars me, and everyone who has ever used the privileges gained via rep they worked hard for, as Bad People, as enemies of the site; while portraying the endless hordes that only care about "gimme teh codez" as innocent victims. That's not acceptable.

I have never discriminated against anyone based on their age, skin colour, gender, accent, or whatever. I have discriminated against those who show no desire to make an effort to think, or read basic "how to ask" pages, or who just don't care. And I will continue to discriminate against those people.

If that makes me wrong, or evil, or  unworthy in Jay Hanlon's eyes... I honestly don't care. What I do care about is that by allowing the blog post to go up, Stack Overflow is endorsing his offensive point of view. That's not acceptable.

Stack Overflow the site, and programming in general, is a meritocracy. If Stack Overflow the company has a problem with that, perhaps they should consider stepping aside to let the people who do actually care about quality run things.

If they don't want to do that, then they - and Jay Hanlon in particular - owe us all an apology, and maybe, just maybe, some thanks for all the unpaid effort we put in to allow them to make a profit.

Comment: That interesting blog is becoming a tool for some people to defend poor quality question/answer. Like [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366710/bad-question-or-example-of-stack-overflow-not-being-welcoming) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366818/i-go-answer-banned-because-i-answered-instead-of-commented-but-i-cannot-commen). Maybe some day asking whatever question should be welcomed ;)...

Comment: Well, comments like *"just read basic string formatting first"* is something that's not very welcoming, even though it's probably on point. It's comments worded like that I would consider on the more unwelcoming side of SO, not the downvotes or closevotes. That's also why I didn't take offense from that blog post, I try not to leave comments like that and just silently vote on content instead.

Comment: Based on the title I was looking forward to giving this a big fat vote up, but then you went and blew a hole in your own argument by being such a douche about it. "untermensch"? *really?*

Comment: @ivarni That comment is a problem b/c 1) it's condescending and 2) it doesn't identify what "basic string formatting" is or where in the docs it actually answers the question.  A silent downvote solves the first problem but it does nothing to address the second!  An ideal solution would point the user to the right content without condescending them.

Comment: "_Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._" Or was ... this is the first to be update to "... a daycare center for people just about to start programming."

Comment: There may be a handful of contributors, like the OP here, who are skilled, and who politely offer criticism on poor questions.  Fantastic. But if you just ask an ordinary person on the street what SO is, they will say "It's that QA site where pratty whiners who know little jump in and criticize questions."  It's simply "petty", it's become a petty whining site.

Comment: @just.another.programmer Absolutely. But in order to reduce incoming vitriol it's often not a good idea to comment and downvote at the same time. Either way, both options are better than leaving condescending comments and I personally feel those comments are the bigger problem.

Comment: @Fattie *SO is loaded with very poor programmers who know very little* --> This is exactly caused by so many poor questions. Some users continuously answer homework questions and becomes a high-rep homework solver. Poor question is the root of the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't read the blog post to go against the users who care for quality. Thinking about changing the site design to educate new users more efficiantly sounds useful. Asking everyone to be honest to themselfes about their behaviour now and then sounds reasonable. No one is an angel. But nowhere in this blog post did I read that your hard work is not cherished anymore or that low quality is now accepted. But oh well, what do I know.

Comment: This is a rant. Nothing more, nothing less. The fact many agree with you means this will likely never get closed (and, if it does, it'll be reopened). The fact I agree with *some* of your concern doesn't matter. What we need are *constructive* posts, not vitriol.

Comment: There's loaded questions, and then there's *this*. Demanding an apology for perceived slights in the most confrontational way possible is one thing, but pretending it's an actual question with potential for feedback other than "we're very sorry, we concede all your points and it won't happen again" is another. I guess it's the price to pay for those comments being disabled -- now all the major opinions have to be littered across the site as "questions" instead.

Comment: Ian, you must understand and accept that you suffer from the Original Sin of unconscious bias. .

Comment: (I've tried to tweak the title to be a bit kinder - I do understand that some feathers are a bit ruffled, but if we can smooth our language a bit, I think that might help).

Comment: @halfer: I've rolled back the title, because I believe it changes the spirit of the post too much. I don't think Ian wants an end to all criticism of quality-concerned users; the post seems to specifically be about painting quality-concerned users as the bad guys.

Comment: @user2357112: I'll leave it with you, but can you remove "demonised"? The "when" is a problem too, in the sense of "when did you stop beating your wife?" - it isn't fair to articulate questions where the premise is highly questionable.

Comment: @halfer Why do you want to remove "demonizing"? Many of us feel like we're being demonized. Let's not beat around the bush.

Comment: @mason: just diplomacy, really. Sometimes to get the best outcome, we need to understand how our message is heard, and modify it strategically to ensure that other people's reactions do not prevent that outcome. For example, the language may have contributed to this question being closed once already, which is counterproductive if the post author wants to achieve his end aims.

Comment: (Aside: I sometimes mention something similar when seeing bitter diatribes from angry users in bug reports. As much as I can get away with, I say to them "you can insult me, or get your bug looked at, but not both `;-)`).

Comment: @halfer I don't really consider it diplomatic to remove "demonized" from the title. Users of Stack Overflow feel like they're being demonized by recent actions. To ignore that is to ignore the problem. And ignoring the problem isn't very diplomatic, is it?

Comment: @mason: my opinion stands, and I don't think my recommending kinder language is at all ignoring the problem. It is an ethical dilemma: how does one calm down a furious person, if telling them to "calm down" is going to wind them up further? I'll ponder that this evening...

Comment: The blog post didn't make me feel bad.

Comment: It's kind of weird how many people feel victimized by this blog post, but demand evidence that anyone feels less than welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It's strange that people demand backing data after they're being accused of mistreating a group of people?

Comment: Although I do get your point, your reaction is the other extreme then what you are opposing.

Comment: @mason nobody has accused you of anything.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The things that are vaguely criticized as "unwelcoming" are down+closevotes, which are **essential** for the site to work, and comments (which probably often are only *perceived* as "rude" because they try to clearly bring a message across). These are targeted at **individual questions** (and usually **not** the person who wrote it). The blog post criticized **the whole community**. Persons who try to help others (and, who may, admittedly, find it very hard to not too strongly criticize the person who *wrote* the blog post. He should **really** take some time to reflect...)

Comment: @liliscent FWIW [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366710/bad-question-or-example-of-stack-overflow-not-being-welcoming) was not an attempt to [defend [a] poor quality question/answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who?cb=1#comment580727_366858). My post highlighted a specific question to ask if the quick negative reaction to it was representative of SO not being welcome. It morphed into a question about *that* question and got closed before anyone else had a chance say something.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Except, they have. I've told people not to say "please" or "thank you". I've edited it out of posts.  I've encouraged users not to answer clearly off-topic or clearly duplicate questions. The blog post describes these actions as "unwelcoming". I downvote poorly researched or obviously duplicate questions. I downvote answers that contain inaccurate information.

Comment: @mason So, the blog post is describing certain *behaviors* as unwelcoming, and you're taking personal offense to that as though it were directed at you specifically. Can you see the analogy I'm trying to make between that and people feeling unwelcome when they receive rude and condescending comments, or pile-on downvotes? They take these things personally. Maybe we shouldn't just dismiss that when our own feelings are seemingly so fragile.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It's not that my feelings are hurt. Blog posts can't really do that to me. My issue with it is more the implication: if the company believes we're doing something wrong by engaging in those actions, then they're going to take steps to curtail those actions. And I believe those actions are a necessary moderation tool.

Comment: @mason That is not what this post is about and you know it. The post says people feel demonized and are demanding an apology. They're offended and their feelings are hurt. But now you want to claim it's all about the data and procedure. Ok, you're an emotionless robot and nothing bothers you. I stand corrected.

Comment: @BilltheLizard An apology would go a long ways towards admitting that they know they're wrong, that they know experienced users on this site are *not* the problem, that they listened to the wrong people, and that they're not going to take any action that would take away important community moderation tools. I don't think we're going to get such an apology, but one can hope.

Comment: The first thing I learned about being on the Internet is to never take anything personally.

Comment: wait.... people are really offended by the title of this Q?

Comment: @just.another.programmer But they *should* "just read basic string formatting first" and that is the best advice they could receive and it is *not* condescending. What chain of reasoning leads you call it so?

Comment: @philipxy You're asserting they should know how to "read basic string formatting" w/out any additional help; by extension you're saying if they don't know how, they're not worthy of help.  That's condescending.  Consider how difficult it might be for a beginner to do this w/out help: 1) maybe they don't know how to find the right documentation, 2) maybe they don't understand it, 3) maybe they lack the English language skills to read it, 4) maybe they inherited this project and it's in a programming language they don't know, 5) etc etc etc.

Comment: "Stack Overflow the site, and programming in general, is a meritocracy." That is a misconception. The site is sole property of a company. The content is free for all. And the questions may get upvoted or downvoted but that is only relevant for those believing in these unicorn points. The small part that is an oligarchy is actually the close/delete mechanism.

Comment: The issue that I have with the blog post is not that it complains about the "hostility" of the StackOverflow community; it's that it claims that minorities who post bad content receive such hostility because they are minorities. Minorities should not be able to  post bad questions just because they are minorities.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, Stack Overflow is owned by a company, but it is for the most part a meritocracy. It doesn't matter who you are: so long as you don't break the rules and you're correct, then your question/answer/edit/comment will be accepted. Over time, many people have done enough good work that they are well respected throughout the community, and their experience carries significant weight on non-technical issues.

Comment: I upvoted this because I agree with it, but I also have to vote to close because [your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There's a big difference between being quality-concerned, and being hostile. "Could you please explain what you mean by asking X?" or "You might want to look at page Y, I think it has what you're looking for" has more merit in a social question-and-answer community than just shutting people down.

Comment: Closed as “Primarily opinion based”? That’s quite silly, considering this is a Meta discussion.

Comment: My spell checker marks both "demonising" and "demonizing" as incorrect when in UK English. If I switch to US English, "demonizing" is OK, but "demonising" is still bad. Oh well.

Comment: Any website that holds high standards for both questions and answers is going to inherently have a high barrier to entry, to the point that after all the "low hanging fruit" has been dealt with, all that remains is expertise. This blog posts confuses this barrier to entry as implicit hostility, and it's ridiculous. It's not actually possible for a Q&A site to be open to programming newcomers if all of the common newcomer questions have been asked, answered, and archived.

Comment: What a great post. This should be on the blog, not the other crap they posted.

Comment: "If that makes me wrong, or evil, or unworthy in Jay Hanlon's eyes... I honestly don't care." That's OK; people higher up the chain now care.

Comment: Unpaid effort? But they give you give swag! I got swag! I got swag multiple times. You didn't? Well, I guess you are right then. **It is** a meritocracy :)

Comment: If this is what they want us to be, SE will end up like Yahoo Answers or Quora.

Comment: @mason " I've told people not to say "please" or "thank you". And this is one of the single biggest failings of Stackxx. The blind pursuit of purity and efficiency at the expense of fundamental HUMAN social niceties is one of the reasons new users don't feel welcome. If new users don't feel welcome, redefining what welcoming means dodes not change their feelings. FACT: New users often feel unwelcome. This is either a problem or it's not a problem. Pretending the fact isn't true is pointless. Defend a real position, which is that being unwelcoming is the cost of maintaining quality.

Comment: I agree with this... but I want to add something: 99% of people when they start coding are the typical "gimme teh codez" person. I think we all hate that behavior, but that doesn't mean we have to be extremely rudes.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing more to say than what you've said. You took the words right off my keyboard and phrased them more politely. Thank you! Oh, wait... Do you have a publically available blog or twitter or FB account where we can all shout that we're being discriminated against, so we can get the same notice?

Comment: I should also point out that this post has 3 close votes for *not being about discussion*, which clearly it is about that discussion. More censorship of those quality-concerned users? Maybe we should find a site to complain about being a minority?

Comment: @KenWhite Questions in this debate have been receiving overzealous, unjustified close votes regardless of where they stand with respect to the blog post -- Meta knows no bounds when it comes to trying to close [discussion]s. While I am highly critical of the way this question frames the issue, I agree that the close votes are out of order.

Comment: I have rarely asked questions, because the questions have usually been already asked and answered. I rarely answer questions, because of experiences where my answer has been downvoted whilst my code in that same answer has been copy-pasted to another answer.

Comment: I quite agree.  From my experience in [C++], much of the trouble is rooted ii abysmal pedagogy, which I dare to suggest appears to correlate with national origin. What can be done for students who are receiving inadequate or outright faulty instruction? Another societal disharmony I see is largely generational. Old people like me, graduates of the School of Hard Knocks, expect and respect a frank discussion. It is my perception that young people often regard it as their right not to be offended, and furthermore to judge what is offensive. If I am wrong, I am wrong, but that is my impression.

Comment: @barbecue "The blind pursuit of purity and efficiency at the expense of fundamental HUMAN social niceties is one of the reasons new users don't feel welcome"  Yes, but that's ALSO what made this site great to begin with.  I'm not here to feel good about myself, I'm here to get help with a problem then get back to work, or help someone else either their problem.  All those social niceties are exactly why Quora or YA are like they are, garbage.  They end up being a distraction.

Comment: @Andy while I reject the notion that it is impossible to use polite and cordial language while still efficiently answering questions, I agree that too much chatter and irrelevant discussion distracts from the answers. But what really makes this site better than others is not the lack of "please" and "thank you" usage, that's BS. What makes the difference is the quality-based curation of content by the users. Yahoo and similar cesspools are not cesspools because they allow "Thank you" posts. They're cesspools because they allow terrible answers. The two are not related.

Comment: @barbecue If it were only limited to pleases and thank yous, that'd be one thing.  But allowing those also seems to encourage more than just those social aspects, and you get a rants about how long the asker has been stuck on the problem or how frustrating it is.  And I think the more detached writing style encourages higher quality answers as well.  Do you find documentation (such as docs.microsoft.com) less useful because they only discuss the topic at hand?  I think there's a correlation between how causal q&a is and the quality of that q&a.

Comment: @Andy Casual and polite are not the same thing. When a newcomer posts a question and says "thanks" at the end, and is then penalized for doing so that's unwelcoming. It's not possible to be welcoming while also issuing what are perceived as punishments for doing things wrong. It DOES NOT MATTER what we think. The new user **perceives** it as punishment. It's irrelevant what we think, because we are not talking about our opinions, but the opinions of new users. which is the sole focus of this controversy. Being welcoming means changing the PERCEPTION new users have.

Comment: Apparently not ever, given the recent debacle too.

Comment: so·cial net·work
noun
noun: social network; plural noun: social networks
1.
a network of social interactions and personal relationships.
2.
a dedicated website or other application that enables users to communicate with each other by posting information, comments, messages, images, etc.

Comment: if you dont want to be social get off the social network. call it a Q&A if you want, but it falls under the dictionary definition.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens SE calls itself Q&A.  The goal of this network is not to interact and build relationships with people, its to get help with specific problems.  Go read the help, it states explicitly this is not a forum.  I primarily come here to find solutions to problems I'm having; I don't often answer questions. I do care about the quality of the site, because the newer posters are filling it with crap, making it harder to find what I need (either an existing question, or getting answers to questions). BTW how arrogant of you to presume to know my motivations when you know nothing about me.

Comment: dude. it dosn't matter that its not facebook. if it was like that i wouldnt be here. Q&A by its very nature is a social interaction, unless you answer yourself.

Comment: @Andy i apologize if you feel i was attacking you, i was generalizing. but to be fair, me not intending what i wrote the way you took it is the reason this discussion is here. written text lacks inflection and sometimes context.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens Please, spare me.  "I  would say you are here to feel good about yourself, by proving your smarter than new posters"  There's no room for misinterpretation there, that is a personal attack.  Now please go away.

Comment: @Andy i also agree, that there is some useless congestion, but with a few added resources as a place for people to start BEFORE asking questions would go a long way. so would some sort of sponsorship program, where a new user has to ask there question to someone who can help them ask a worthy question before posting it. like we have the triage que and the first question que, but neither of them work because crap still makes it through

Comment: @Andy as i said before i apologize, i did not mean to single you out. and you are right i don't know you. ( i could no longer edit the post in question to reflect an apropriate statement so i have removed it.) i dont mean to attack anyone.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens Stop tagging me; I have no interest in further communication with you.

Comment: I will stop tagging you. and bothering you. i will not "go away". and im giving you a huge mental hug! c'mere!

Comment: In my opinion, this post really captures and demonstrates the attitude and approach that's fueled what was highlighted in Jay Hanlon's post and the subsequent discussions.

Comment: Relevant, important and interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c) in a now deleted, related [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413491/is-stack-overflow-really-this-bad).

Comment: Referenced from comments to the 2022-08-20 MSE question *[Do you receive more and more downvotes on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381396/)*.

Answer (score 175):

I feel somewhat similar to you - it seems like this kind of spilled over without any direction on what needs to happen next in order to "fix" anything - but I feel like this is a stark overreaction to the blog post.

If nothing else, I personally interpret the blog post more as a "wake-up call" rather than anything that I should take offense to.  It gives me an opportunity to actually reflect on what I've said to others that may have come across as "unwelcoming".  And again, while I feel largely like you do - someone who's toiled and helped the site along in the name of Site Quality - I can still identify points in time in which I actually *was* unwelcoming to someone here.

I think the biggest thing that needs to happen is that **the victim/aggressor rhetoric that seems to be playing out here lately needs to end**.  Both sides have a stake in this discussion, and **neither gains anything if we suddenly start taking this personally.**

At some point I'm sure someone will start actually pointing out the real problems backed by some internal data metric, but for now...I think what I'll do is compile a list of what *I* believe are the problem(s) with the site and what ultimately led to this blog post.

If you *do* happen to feel demonized or vilified, then there's no harm in you taking a break for a while.

Comment: I don't want him to take a break for a while...

Comment: Having quality-concerned users "take a break for a while" in response to this would reduce site quality and reduce the pushback against the harmful proposals sold as "being welcoming".

Comment: Feeling upset/angry/frustrated and sticking around until you can sort your own feelings out is worse than taking a breather and taking a break.  Personally I don't think they'd stay gone indefinitely.

Comment: I think the point is that these high rep users shouldn't be feeling upset / angry / frustrated _in the first place_. Not demonizing their behavior would go a long way in that regard.

Comment: Getting your feelings sorted out is good, but speaking up promptly is also important.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  It's a bit late for that...the blog post has happened.  What has to transpire next is *some* period of sanity.  It's fine to feel however one feels in this period of time since yeah, it does seem like the high rep users are going to be upset about this.  That's *fine*.

Comment: The political power of victimhood is difficult to overstate, so it's going to be incredibly difficult to wean SO/SO users off of it.

Comment: @Makoto While getting up and walking away is a great thing, I have to disagree that a period of sanity has to start with the volunteers.  SE had all the time in the world to proof read and edit the blog post, and at some point, had to realize that it was going to spark a backlash.  Trusting us to act humanely and rationally when an SE employee says our attempts at quality curation [are pure garbage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/1197934) is...naive, at best.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I don't see anywhere where that post is disparaging our attempts at quality curation.  I *do* see emotion attached to the philosophy though, which only goes to further my point; you're feeling as if you're being vilified when you are just trying to curate the site.  Tacitly I find myself also disagreeing with the proposed solution, but this is only a symptom of another Problem™, and only goes to address but one dimension of the actual issue at hand.

Comment: @fbueckert:  What I'm saying is, maybe this is a good cue for you to go clear your head, too.  Come back and think about what needs to be done for the site later.  Even if it means you want to leave indefinitely.

Comment: If a user feels personnaly offended and demonized by a blog post to the community at large, a break is definitely in order

Comment: I suspect there are a fair number of really helpful users who have taken a break for awhile precisely because of the number of ungracious commenters who've made SO a place they no longer enjoy being a part of. I know I'm VERY much less active than I used to be and that's part of the reason.

Comment: @tvanfosson: There are more than a few really helpful users who have taken a break for a while because of the way the company is treating them.

Comment: Discrimination is currently a no-problem for SO and I think that *it is dangerous* to create a discrimination case when there is none and this is the case of the blog post. With this "artificial discrimination case" we risk to create real distance between people. Your "let they go/do" is wrong, this is a dangerous attitude that must be discussed and corrected.

Comment: Why should new-comers be preferred instead of experienced users ..? We old members of the community have got our part of the cake, and now it's the time for a new generation? Also, what kind of a site will be waiting for a break-taker, if you're on a break, say six months?

Comment: Sorry. I typically agree with what you write, but when every request for clarification of information to a question is being flagged in response to Jay's post, it simply proves that knee-jerk stupidity (sorry, Jay) isn't acceptable or useful. Jay's blog post was ill-conceived, and a stupid reaction to #metoo mentality where anything anyone claims is suddenly fact without evidence. Actually, while posting this comment I'm wearing gray socks, and if I get a negative vote or reply to it I'm going to claim bias against gray sock wearing posters. Lunacy prevails.

Comment: I have to agree, I think at the point where someone is willing to get this emotional, and openly identify a group of people they've judged to be worthy of discrimination, and then backed themselves to continue actively discriminating against that group, we're all better off with them taking a break.

Comment: @Makoto In your comment, you actually said that "it does seem like the high rep users are going to be upset about this. That's fine".  You have made a profoundly negative observation about the entire raison d'etre of SO. The voluntary contributions of our high rep users are precious. It can never be "fine" to implement policy that makes high rep users upset, thus disinclined to participate in the future... unless, well, are you saying that rep is not a meaningful indicator of meritocratic value? Which is it? Is rep meaningless? Or is knowledge and contribution of secondary importance on SO?

Answer (score 128):

> I have discriminated against those who show no desire to make an effort to think, or read basic "how to ask" pages, or who just don't care. And I will continue to discriminate against those people.

- This I totally agree with. I've seen a drastically increased amount of LQ questions since the beginning of 2018, and despite most of them being asked or instructed (***usually in a non-hostile manner!***) to read *How to Ask* and the *Tour*, they still don't do it. Either they complain, keep pushing us for help, or simply ask another (pretty much the same) question.

*(**NOTE:** I mainly hang around the [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) areas, so I speak from their point-of-view)*

Very many newcomers don't care when we offer them the help they need to improve their asking skills. I've been in the situation, dozens of times, where one of us have asked the newcomer to read HTA and take the Tour (I usually also try to tell them what's missing from their question), but where most of them (in fact almost all) decide not to listen, and instead they get frustrated or angry because we're not helping them. Their post keeps piling on downvotes from other users and eventually gets closed.

Downvotes do feel very hostile, it's true, and the overall *apparent* hostility of SO is a problem, however, it must be noted that it is very often caused because the OPs refuse to listen when we try to help them.

The blog post partially tries to address the "low-quality questions"-problem with what I actually think could be a very good place to start:

> We’re planning to test a new “beginner” ask page that breaks the question box into multiple fields – one for each of the key things answerers need to help:
>
> - “What did you want to happen?”
> - “What actually happened? (Include any error details)”
> - “Paste the shortest block of code that reproduces the problem. (We’ll format it!)”
> - “Describe what you’ve tried so far (including searches, etc.)”

However the post still does put a lot of blame on us - ***we who already try to help the newcomers improve their asking skills by telling them to read How to Ask and take the Tour, and to modify their question accordingly*** (plus occasionally some other help entries like *On-topic*).

Comment: @SurajRao : Thanks for the edit. I was typing from my phone and changing the text here and there so it got a little messed up (and there were also some autocorrect). :)

Comment: /raises hand/ I was one of the newcomers who did care when the SO community offered me the help I needed to improve my asking skills. Here a year later learning how to ask a decent question is one of the most important things I have learned from SO, in addition to finding the answers to my questions. In no moment was anyone ever rude to me, even though my first couple of questions were downvoted. It helped me understand I was doing something wrong so I could improve. I feel that the vast majority of people who find SO unwelcoming are the people you mention, who don't care to learn.

Comment: @DavyM : I'm very glad to hear that! Even though I don't ask many questions, SO was what made me better at asking decent, information-rich questions as well! I used to ask most of my questions over at MSDN when I was a newcomer (and those were not of very good quality), but SO was what really taught me how to write questions of good quality because it was here I got the most (constructive) criticism (and also by seeing that criticism on others' questions).

Comment: @DavyM. I bet one of the consequences of your positive experience is that you now *ask fewer questions*. A large part of learning how to ask a good question involves seeing things from the point of view of your potential answerers - which will then often lead you to the solution you were originally looking for. The cynic in me wonders whether this is what really worries the owners of SO. Their ultimate aim is always to increase site traffic. As far as they're concerned, ignorance is bliss, because well-educated users tend to ask fewer questions, and therefore visit the site less frequently.

Comment: @Ekhumoro You're right: I ask questions all the time, I just rarely manage to hit that submit button on the question. By the time I've finished making a good question and making the error as simple for readers to see and done my research, I've either figured out my own answer, or I've found a duplicate question. By the nature of the site, the longer Stack Overflow exists, the fewer questions that should be asked, because there are more and more questions that should already have people's answer before they ask if they look. Then those people will not get downvoted and SO will be welcoming.

Comment: @DavyM I'm a person who was terrible at asking questions when I first joined SO. However, I took the advice people gave me and improved. Honestly, if the people who find SO/SE unwelcoming are the kind of people that don't listen to constructive criticism, I don't even want them on the site. Granted, I'm a very low-rep user who *sometimes* answers questions, so maybe I'm not the best person to criticize question-askers. But people like that just lower the quality of the site, and that's something that I really do care about.

Comment: I too am found almost exclusively in the C# tag and thus have the same pov. the amount of bad questions (the ones where you google the title and have the answer) is just too much, if that continues SO will never get 'friendlier'. The only people we are 'unfriendly' to (try to give directions, somehow some people take everything personal) are the ones that don't want to learn, so do we care really?

Answer (score 85):

As someone else who has been on this site for almost a decade, who has tried to post good questions, who has voted on content, who has worked the queues, all in the name of keeping the site's quality up... I have a hard time seeing what you're affronted by in Jay's post.

> I have never discriminated against anyone based on their age, skin colour, gender, accent, or whatever.

That's great! Nobody said you did, but that's still great. As I've said elsewhere, I think this is one of the best things about the Stack Overflow community. We don't tolerate that sort of thing. But I don't see anywhere in the blog post where Jay accused anyone of those things. Here are a few of the things he did say about the community:

> Now, that’s not because most Stack Overflow contributors are hostile jerks. The majority of them are generous and kind.
>
> We felt protective of our current users, because we know they come here to teach, and most of them are fighters for good most of the time.
>
> I’m incredibly proud of the small part I’ve gotten to play in everything this community has achieved. Our users are truly some of the most generous people on the planet.

But he also asked us to face a few hard truths:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.
>
> And a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place.
>
> Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong. They get snarky or condescending comments for not explaining what they’ve tried (that didn’t work).

I also noticed several places where Jay (on the company's behalf) takes responsibility for some of the problems:

> The real problem isn’t the community — it’s us:
>
> We trained users to tell other users what they’re doing wrong, but we didn’t provide new folks with the necessary guidance to do it right. We failed to give our regular users decent tools to review content and easily find what they’re looking for. We sent mixed messages over the years about whether we’re a site for “experts” or for anyone who codes.
>
> In recent years, inclusion efforts (and other public Q&A work) have consistently been “fairly important,  like… roughly #3 on our list of priorities?” Which meant they got allocated roughly zero resources.

So, I'm having a hard time understanding the extreme pushback I'm seeing from the community against this blog post. As a user who has cast tens of thousands of downvotes and close votes, I don't think Jay owes me an apology for pointing out real problems with the site. I don't feel personally demonized. He's only pointing out that, as great a community as this is, *we can all do better*. Let's not kill the messenger here. Let's face facts instead.

Comment: The facts being exactly which? All the questions here on MSO asking for more than ancedotes did not receive anything resembling facts so far. BTW, it would be nice for SO (the company) to join the discussion here.

Comment: *"Nobody said you did [discriminate]"* - that's unclear. Jay's blog post contains the semantically ambiguous claim that *"women and people of color felt particularly unwelcome"*. That can be parsed as "women & POC were particularly likely to feel unwelcome" (I think this was intended) or as "women & POC felt that their demographics *are* particularly unwelcome" (i.e. women and non-whites collectively believe that the SO community collectively bears sexist and racist animus toward them and that we'd prefer white men only to participate). Looks to me like many folks read it the latter way.

Comment: @LutzHorn The facts are laid out. Do you dispute that "And a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place"? Or that people get snarky condescending comments?

Comment: @MarkAmery Then I would ask people to give a more generous read of the text of the blog post, instead of assuming worst intentions.

Comment: I'd like to see facts especially about the first point. The second can easily be validated by looking through comments, but the first can not.

Comment: "But he also asked us to face a few hard truths:" in fact there "truths" aren't hard for me, "Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.", I don't care, "And a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place.", I don't care, "Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong. They get snarky or condescending comments for not explaining what they’ve tried (that didn’t work)." ok this one bad, we must not be rude.

Comment: @LutzHorn Don't you think those two things are related?

Comment: Regarding the last quoted paragraph I'd really like to know what SO (the company) has in mind. What kind of guidance and tools are planned?

Comment: @Stargateur The fact that you don't care, and seem proud (?) of that, is worrying to me.

Comment: @LutzHorn Jay lays that out in the next several paragraphs of the blog post.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The are related because people *might* feel that SO is an intimidating, unwelcoming place if they get snarky condescending comments. We can argue if this feeling is justified. But this kind of comments do not necessarily have to trigger this kind of feeling. I want facts for this relationship and for the bad feelings people are said to have, not anecdotes.

Comment: @LutzHorn We don't need the condescension and snark, though. It's not required. How do *you* feel when someone is condescending and snarky to you? We don't need to analyze the relationship any further.

Comment: @BilltheLizard What Jay writes about in the blog do not help me in judging what kind of changes are planned. They can be effective but chilling. Or they can be make SO a better place for everybody, including people voicing their concerns these days here on MSO. So far I have no idea what SO (the company) will do and if I will like it or not. Details, please!

Comment: @BilltheLizard Good to know that you know how I feel. But let's all get back to work.

Comment: @BilltheLizard And that worrying me that you care of that, I'm not here to make people feel better (or worst), I'm here to produce a high quality content, and that will automatically make bad programmer and newbie feel unwelcome ! We exclude bad question from our system, this is SO goal, we don't want question about "why my code don't work" and co. And every years more newbie come and use SO as "debug my program thx", it's worst every day, and now SO want that we allow more that these already bad question ? This is what I truly fear, and this will make the end of SO faster.

Comment: @Stargateur Nowhere in the blog post does it say that SO wants to allow more bad questions. In fact, one of the proposals says "Let’s make it easier for new users to succeed... *We* set them up for failure, and our power users have been asking us to help them for ages. We’re planning to test a new “beginner” ask page that breaks the question box into multiple fields – one for each of the key things answerers need to help..."

Comment: @BilltheLizard The blog post *mentions* "condescension and snark", but provides no examples of what it considers to be snarky or condescending; the first example given of an action that's now apparently unwelcome (or at least makes Jay "sad") is downvoting duplicates, and there's a vague expression of intent to begin purging "unkind" comments from the site (a category which, read plainly, seems like it would include any time anyone's ever pointed out an error in an answer). Is it really surprising that many commentators, me included, fear the worst?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yeah improve site is a good thing. "...SO wants.." Not directly in the blog but we talk about this issue since already 4 days, read this answer from one SO employee for example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/7076153. They clearly want we nurse newbie. I see this as "we want more user to get more and more money". And the real problem of this post it's insulting every SO contributor of being sexist, racist, homophobic, etc... This article is politic, US side of the world, this is clearly a wrong thing. They open the pandora's box, now we talk politics in SO, wonderful !

Comment: @BilltheLizard As for the beginner ask page, it's an exercise in wrongheadedness, for reasons that I, TinyGiant, and others have been pointing out on Meta for months: it's a template that only debugging questions can be fitted into, and so sends a signal to new users that anyone who wants to ask another kind of question is in the wrong place and should go elsewhere. That's the opposite of being more "welcoming". But if we haven't been heeded when we've pointed that out before, I doubt we will be now; instead, we'll get the template that shoos away precisely the users we most want to keep.

Comment: @Stargateur: "*They open the pandora's box, now we talk politics in SO, wonderful !*" The problem with being "apolitical" is that some groups of people *have to be* political in order to exist and function. Their very real problems are lumped into a box people call "politics", frequently by people who want to then turn around and prevent talking about them by saying "that's political talk". Now, I'm not defending the blog post, but I don't think it's appropriate to attack it on the basis of "that's politics." Many people *live* politics, not because they want to, but because they have to.

Comment: @Mark Amery: I personally am conflicted on the whole downvoting duplicates thing. We treat duplicates as signposts, i.e. not a Bad Thing™, right? So I feel like in order for a duplicate question to function as one, and in order for the asker not to feel that their duplicate question *isn't* useful even as a signpost, it needs to not have a negative score. However, that does mean changing the meaning of votes on duplicate questions since research effort is *one* of the aspects of a question that votes are meant to reflect, and I can totally understand folks being uncomfortable with that idea.

Comment: You conveniently left out the more problematic parts of the blog. I dispute that people in marginalized groups feel less welcome. So far I have seen zero evidence to support that claim.

Comment: @Oleg Then you're the one conveniently ignoring problems. (I didn't reproduce the entire blog, but I did quote some of the parts people seem to have issue with. Maybe you should give both a more careful read.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Not helpful. If there's evidence, show it, rather than just casting aspersions on the moral character of those who are skeptical of the claim. That's the same tactic that the blog post used, and is what incited the anger that the community has directed towards it.

Comment: @MarkAmery It's so weird that you view that comment as "not helpful" and  "casting moral aspersions", but you refuse to see how the snark and condescension all over Stack Overflow is not helpful. It's almost like you have two standards.

Comment: @BilltheLizard *"refuse to see how the snark and condescension all over Stack Overflow is not helpful"* - again, neither Jay nor you has even tried to describe what would constitute a "condescending" comment that was previously considered acceptable but will now be deleted, nor point to any examples. You're putting words into my mouth - I haven't claimed anywhere that no problem with comment tone exists, and don't think so - but how am I supposed to form an opinion on whether some class of comments should be purged if the people demanding the purge can't tell me what those comments *are*?

Comment: @MarkAmery Jay did give an example in the blog post, and he asked for the community to start flagging things that they find rude, so it's up to us. Also, I talked about it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365811/1288

Comment: I think including a link to unconscious bias testing indicates that the "women and people of color" element is not tangential to the post.

Comment: @Oleg People shouldn't have to give "evidence" that their own experience is valid. If you haven't felt unwelcome, lucky you, but you seem to be trying to speak on behalf of all marginalized people.

Comment: @Benjol In a footnote. That's the very definition of tangential.

Comment: About 80% of the comments above can probably be settled with some "unwelcomeness" metric of some sort. We have none. We are randomly guessing

Comment: That's not what's going on here. This is a disagreement about what Stack Overflow should be. Is it a question-and-answer site for programmers to find high-quality answers to questions? Or is it a touchy-feely-fakey "community" where everyone can scratch each other's backs and feel "included"? These goals are not compatible. See top answers here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262791/#309018 and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/#256051

Comment: @Ben 1. Much as some of us would like it to be, the real world isn't binary. There's a whole range of values between the two options you pointed out. 2. These two goals are totally compatible. You just have to be willing to accept that there's a middle ground.

Comment: No, no. Having more than one goal always means one or both must be sacrificed to some extent. Always.

Comment: @Ben More binary thinking. Yes or no. Black or white. The real world doesn't work that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does. No man can serve two masters. It would be nice to have our cake and eat it, but that's cloud cuckoo land. Once upon a time we knew this, but forgetting is very en vogue at the moment.

Comment: @Ben One last time, you *can* have two separate but compatible goals. I'd like to both work in finance and retire a millionaire. I can do both. I don't have to sacrifice one to serve the other. There, my existence proof shatters your reality. Because binary thinking doesn't work in the real world.

Comment: Nonetheless **these** goals are incompatible, as evidenced by the failure to make it work here for the last four years, and in comp.lang.c as noted in the blog post. (I did consider adding the obvious exceptions required to make it a mathematically complete statement but you are clearly an intelligent chap and didn't need me to do that. Yet you chose to jump on it anyway.)

Comment: "I'm having a hard time understanding the extreme pushback I'm seeing from the community against this blog post."  I don't, because this is what, the 5th time in a year that SO says they are going to focus on the core Q&A (basically they've kept saying this since the Documentation project imploded). Lots of talk, then some practical experiments, but nothing that makes it to the main site. Time is ticking, users are leaving.

Comment: @NicolBolas I hope you wouldn't mind if I share your comment on being apolitical in my facebook and in real-life conversations with proper credits to you of course. That comment is hard-hitting and speaks truth in a lot of other situations and places other than SO too.

Comment: @BoltClock I never downvote duplicates and I don’t see any worth in allowing to vote on already closed questions in general. But I see why there are so many people doing it; it’s easy to jump on the bandwagon and vote like all others did, to get the badges Stackoverflow awards for voting *n* times. The solution would be simple, don’t allow to vote on closed questions, after all, when a question has been closed, the OP got the message (in case of non-duplicates) and doesn’t need more peer pressure and in case of duplicates there’s even less worth in allowing additional votes.

Comment: "Then I would ask people to give a more generous read of the text of the blog post, instead of assuming worst intentions." If the blog post intends to claim "women & POC were particularly likely to feel unwelcome" *without* claiming "women & POC felt that their demographics are particularly unwelcome" (i.e., there isn't anything about site conduct that actively turns "women & POC" away), then... either it *is* saying that "women & POC" have some special justification for feeling that way, or it *isn't* (which logically implies they're being irrational). *Either way, I count that as bigotry*.

Comment: "*It's so weird that you view that comment as 'not helpful' and 'casting moral aspersions', but you refuse to see how the snark and condescension all over Stack Overflow is not helpful. It's almost like you have two standards.*" It's not weird in the slightest, nor is a double standard involved. Snark and condescension are concepts *not related to* unhelpfulness and preaching; and you were (rightly) called out for the latter, not the former. It's not your tone that causes the problem; it's your refusal to bear the burden of evidence, nor to recognize that it falls on you.

Comment: Re duplicates generally, they generally *shouldn't* be downvoted. Once closed, either they rephrase the question in a way that can help future viewers of the site (by increasing the chance that they hit upon a search term that works for them), or allow the duplicate-linkers to collect related duplicate (or near-duplicate) links in a new way - in which case increasing visibility is deserved; or they don't, in which case they should be *deleted* as adding zero value to the site.

Comment: "*In a footnote. That's the very definition of tangential.*" Pardon if I am *thoroughly* unconvinced. There are exactly two reasons to include a politically contentious claim in an essay, when it is not needed to support the main argument: because one believes it is morally virtuous to state the claim in question, or because one seeks policy changes related to the claim (or both).

Answer (score 55):

The single post that we published could have probably been broken down into quite a few, where we spent more time talking about the individual reasons why people don't find the site to be welcoming, followed by what we could do there.

There was an underlying theme that presents itself with a rather heightened sense of urgency, people are increasingly and appreciably reporting that the site is not welcoming for a variety of reasons, and they're reporting this with their words as well as their actions.

It wasn't a question of whether or not we'd be overwhelming and very likely misunderstood, it was a question of how. I think we knew that no matter how we did it, our post talking about people not being sensitive to other people's feelings was likely to be taken as insensitive to other people's feelings by some. If we had a few more months to work on it, I'm sure we could have done a better job, but I'm pretty proud of what we published.

We were told about, and found:

- Blatant racism
- Blatant sexism, along with strong evidence of unconscious bias clouding dialog (assuming everyone not obviously female as being male being a good example)
- Blatant ageism
- People ... ***enforcing these crazy unwritten rules that good grief can't I even ask a question stupid moderators editing my*** .. or, essentially, feedback we've been getting since the dawn of Stack Overflow because the system is so very distant from anything else, and since the community makes many of the rules, it feels like walking on egg shells because who knows what someone might do wrong next time!
- .. more reasons that Tim wishes he hadn't stopped drinking

#### That's all a big problem in that we're actively unwelcoming in many cases.

We tried to stress a big part of that, and maybe it should have been a lot bolder and probably clearer:

***... it's not really your fault. It's our fault, as a company.***

I'll just rattle off some stuff that has been frustrating the heck out of me for a few years now, anyone agree with any of this?

- It's hard to find any kind of consensus on meta, and governance fails to carry over anywhere meaningful in the UI. This erroneously sets people's expectations.
- The /ask page has not been touched since we added that tiny bit of help in the sidebar *over half a decade ago*. (Jeff, you're preaching to the choir.)
- Review feels like a bolted-on game of mousetrap. If one more person feels bad due to a failed audit I swear I'm gonna *OH LOOK IT JUST HAPPENED AGAIN!*
- The mod dashboard is probably the one thing *on this planet* that needs less jQuery. I'm serious. No offense, Sam.

... I could probably complain my way through a case of beer shared with anyone that's been using the site since 2008 about this stuff. And if you're wondering why I'm rambling about that, it's to say that *we know and aren't minimizing this stuff, there just wasn't enough room to show it at real scale in a single post*.

#### I'm sorry that we didn't do enough to keep you from internalizing this.

I was worried about that, we worked hard on revising the post, and ultimately I think we got it in the best possible shape we could deliver in the time that we felt we needed to get it out.

But what you just did here is tell us something we did made you feel bad, we listened, and we'll get better at not doing that. ***That's what all of this is about***.

#### Default-public time!

A great thing about working here is, if it's not about strategy or financial stuff, I can talk about it without having to worry! We call that default-public.

When Jay approached me with the post I flat out told him that I can't ask a single thing more from anyone else working earnestly in good faith to keep the site running clean until we are positively willing to invest in the tools that make the absolute best use of the time they're willing to give.

He (and Joel) agreed on that, and we'll be putting our money where my mouth is very soon. It wasn't forgotten. I'm saying this only because I want to directly contradict the narrative that we didn't care, or didn't pay attention - we were just struggling to get things done while hoping for the best, like many do.

When we hit problems, like this one, we adjust - like anyone else, and will be putting more focus on what gets touched a *whole lot* by a small subset of users (review, mod tools) and get serious about overhauling pages we know to be problematic like /ask.

#### Seriously, I am sorry.

Not sorry like "oh hey I just stepped on your foot" but sorry as in I really regret that something I helped work on left you feeling like an apology was in order. So, you're getting one, for us making what you do feel insignificant and taken for granted. It's not.

That was just a really, really, ***really*** hard piece to write. I'm glad it's done, I'm glad it's out there and while I have not been this busy in *years*, I'm glad to see us coming back on track and having these discussions out loud in sunlight. I firmly believe in the course we're taking and I'll be out there helping people understand it and hopefully embrace some needed change.

Thanks for calling it like you saw it.

There will be more about all of this, and ways folks can actively ensure that they come off as nice as they intend to that don't cost anything, but we know the tools being under par and our slowness in doing anything about setting new user's expectations based on what they're about to submit have been a major cause here.

So if you didn't feel like we owned that part enough, I'm here to own it.

Comment: [Obligatory textbook example of blatant ageism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network)

Comment: @BoltClock: That example is at -90, with a massive community response against it. Does it really indicate a community or site problem?

Comment: 90 people saying it's not a problem doesn't make it not a problem. ;)

Comment: @user2357112: No, it's just tradition for me to link to it every single time the topic of ageism comes up. I remain *immensely* grateful and humbled that the community *all* had my back at that time, especially considering I wasn't even aware of the meta post for at least the first couple of hours. Having said that, I think it serves as a good reminder of both the two facts that 1) people can and do say such things, *and* 2) the community does take a very firm and overwhelming stand against those things.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you've addressed any of the concerns brought up in this (or the other similar) meta question(s).  You've just re-stated some of the things mentioned in the blog post and said, "sorry that that made you feel bad, but I'm glad I did it".  In effect, you've just validated all of the concerns this meta question has brought up.  You've made it clear that SE is more concerned with making the people providing low quality content happy, rather than concerning themselves with making people providing *high* quality content feel happy, and welcome.

Comment: @Boltclock you are younger than me?! Well screw me.... I never would've guessed in a million years. Or cared about it... Until we were all pointed as being implicitly biased towards these things...

Comment: Would you care to comment on how trying to enforce quality is [total garbage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/1197934)? Its extremely disheartening to see SE express that sort of viewpoint when we're struggling to figure out how to move forward. All it does is harden the camps into us versus you.

Comment: @fbueckert SE has many employees and they don't all speak for the company as a whole. I think it's safe to read that post as the opinions of one employee, but I've seen many other opinions expressed by other employees.

Comment: @joran I understand that SE has many employees and many viewpoints.  But we're supposed to be trying to be welcoming and inclusive, so to have someone who is supposed to understand what SE is all about disagree that hostilely doesn't fill me with much confidence.  It seems more like we're the troublesome users that need to leave than any sense of working together.

Comment: @joran When an employee uses an employee account to post on meta they *are* speaking for the company.  Yes, the company is made up of lots of different people, all with diffing opinions, but those people all *represent that company*, and are expected to act accordingly.

Comment: @fbueckert My point is that if you have issues with that post, respond to the author, rather than asking for responses from other employees.

Comment: @joran I did.  [He doubled down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366783#comment580245_366783).  And since he's an SE employee, and using his SE account, he's representing the company.  So I, for one, am *extremely* concerned that SE sees us as troublesome users that should just *help everyone*, quality be damned!

Comment: @fbueckert I don't understand how you can keep doing this. Each of your comments has slipped seamlessly from "a SE employee" to "SE sees/thinks X". Can't you see the distinction between the opinions of one employee and how that can't be generalized to the viewpoints of the _entire organization_?

Comment: @joran I don't see how you can see it as anything but.  They are individuals, yes.  I don't agree with everything my company does, but I certainly don't express it publicly. When an SE employee posts using their diamond, they are representing SE.  Which means SE as a company is responsible and accountable for it.  It's implicit approval, even if SE doesn't hold with that message; that's the responsibility and trust given to their employees.

Comment: @fbueckert Basically everything going on on Meta at the moment is making me utterly despondent. I feel like I have so little in common, in terms of basic values and reaching common understanding of what people even _say_ that I can't meaningfully participate, contribute or even observe this place anymore. It's unspeakably depressing.

Comment: This post by you just makes me even more nervous for the direction of this company. Why do you insist on listening to people who don't contribute? Why not listen to people who have contributed and worked their way up? We were all new at one point, so we know exactly what being new is like. You're just doubling down against real users in your post: that's very worrying. What I'd like to see is a post here or on a blog saying "We take back what we said, we're going to discontinue pointing fingers at experienced users."

Comment: @joran I'm sorry you feel that way. I acknowledge you feel that way, but I'll point out that it's probably not logical. You seem to not understand that company representatives represent the company. This is a commonly held tenet - if you use your company position to espouse your viewpoint, then you are speaking on the company's behalf.

Comment: @mason Is it really that unusual that we would listen to people who don't contribute to find out *why*? Nevermind anything else, that's just basic user acquisition.

Comment: @AdamLear Do you really need to work on user acquisition? Why is that such a priority? See, because I thought Stack Overflow was different that most other companies. Color me naive, but I thought the goal here wasn't to make money, even though it's a company. I thought it was to be a valuable resource to the community?

Comment: @mason It's both. We gotta bring money in in order to exist in the first place, but that isn't necessarily at odds with the community-serving goals. I honestly don't pay that close attention to our financials (I should, but I don't really have the mindset for that), but IIRC a large chunk of our on-site revenue comes from anonymous users via ads. Acquisition isn't all that relevant there. But, in order to serve the broader developer community, we should also pay attention to the groups that are currently not being served.

Comment: @AdamLear Listen no problem, but if after you listened and reached a conclusion that is unacceptable to the current user base don't you think it's more important to listen to them? That's just basic user retention.

Comment: @AdamLear Is it anonymous users as in people who actually made an account for the site? Or are you talking about people who haven't made an account and just read the content on here? The reason those people come here is that we have such high quality. If we remove those quality restrictions, those anonymous non-users who visit the site won't want to use it anymore. There will always be people asking questions, I don't think the company needs to go out of their way to attract new users.

Comment: @mason The latter. Nobody's talking about removing fundamental quality controls, that's a red herring.

Comment: @AdamLear Nobody's talking about it? I've seen talk about removing downvotes, removing close votes for duplicates, and statements telling us not to engage if we see low quality content. It's not a red herring. These are fundamental changes being discussed on Meta these last couple days.

Comment: @Oleg It's not an either/or kind of thing. This is a complex set of data and emotions to communicate and manage. Existing users being comfortable with the status quo doesn't necessarily mean that the status quo doesn't have problems. Non-users/new users being uncomfortable with the status quo also doesn't mean that everything needs to change to accommodate them. There's a middle ground here somewhere, which I think will largely be found by us going back to working on Q&A (which we haven't really done in earnest in years).

Comment: @AdamLear If you are actually going to work on Q&A then yes you might pull it off. If you want to start a social justice movement then a large part of the current user base will leave.

Comment: @mason Fair, there are ideas like that being brought up for discussion. I meant more that the blog post isn't intended to convey that we're adopting the Yahoo!Answers model or anything. I can't promise we won't have dumb ideas (or even dumb implementations), but I can honestly say that there are no set plans internally just yet (with the exception of work on Ask Question).

Comment: Then why say anything at all? Why was the blog post even necessary? I could have told you before it was even posted that it'd have a huge negative reaction. What good has it done?

Comment: @Oleg Fingers crossed... I've seen a number of "TBDs" under the Q&A heading on plans in the near future. :) Nothing firm, but we're allocating the time.

Comment: @mason To me, the goal was to more broadly speak about us (the company) acknowledging these issues that have been brought up on and off over time, with a focus on actually addressing some of them this time. Not just to the meta regulars, but to the broader audience "out there" (hence it being on the blog).

Comment: On that note, I gotta get back to work. This SQL will evidently not write itself, no matter how long I try to leave it alone for. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @AdamLear Speaking about it without action really accomplishes nothing does it? But if you're going to take action, you should have a firm basis for that action. All I saw was that the company has been listening to a few vocal users say they feel they weren't welcome. I see no evidence that it represents the norm.

Comment: @mason I don't have the numbers on hand, but I do know it's more than "a few". I can see how it could look that way, but this is not coming in response to *just* recent Twitter waves, for example. We're also collecting additional data - the community team and the data team are on it.

Comment: @AdamLear The site's regulars aren't (generally) fundamentally opposed to change in general.  In fact, most all of them have aspects of the site that they dislike and would like to see improved.  The issue is that the site was founded on the premise that quality is king; that this is to be a site with quality questions that get quality answers, and there would be lots of mechanisms in place to accomplish said goal, and that people would flock to the site because quality content drives users.

Comment: The problem is that what SE has been saying have all indicated that SE is looking to change *that core value of the site*.  People are indicating that it's more important for people providing low quality content to feel good using the site than for the site to have enforce a high standard of quality for its content.  This is mentioned in the blog posts's statements that research just isn't that important and we shouldn't be expecting people to do it, to the post linked by Nick above.

Comment: Probably worth keeping in mind that *there are no specific changes proposed at this time*, @Servy. Hopefully there *will* be, but that'll come with further discussion on meta and we can debate specifics as much as we like then. As for core values... Jay's post suggests rejecting "the false dichotomy between quality and kindness" - those are some $10 words, but I wrote [essentially the same suggestion 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/08/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/); I don't think it's all that controversial.

Comment: And Tim, I can't believe you would suggest that the mod tools have excessive jQuery; that's heresy! The *only* thing holding them back is the currently-insufficient levels of jQuery; in fact, we should probably have dropped this whole "public debate" idea until we at least *tried* fixing Stack Overflow's accessibility problems with the handy `$.inclusive()` plugin.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't have a problem at all with your statement that you don't need to be rude or uncivil in order to uphold the site's quality standards.  You don't need to be mean, you don't need to hurl personal insults, you don't need to attack people, etc.  But the site is generally quite good and not doing things like that often, and removing them quickly when they happen.  The issue is that people posting low quality content are offended by merely being told, politely, that they need to improve their question.  Some people consider the very idea of having quality standards to be unwelcoming.

Comment: In the past those outliers were told, when they complained about their low quality contributions not being well received, that the site is different; that there are quality standards that SO has that make it different from your typical internet forum.  Now there's a blog telling them that SE is trying to change that; that their feeling of welcomeness is more important.  Now yes, there aren't specific proposals yet, but merely the statement that of what goals the unannounced changes are attempting to accomplish is itself problematic, hence why you see such a strong reaction from the community.

Comment: Since day 1, there have been two cardinal rules on Stack Overflow, @Servy: [be nice and be honest](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/stackoverflow.com/faq). Those rules have never been in conflict, nor are they about to change; any implication to the contrary is in error.

Comment: @Shog9 Who said anything about getting rid of either of those things?  I'm not saying people don't need to be nice, or honest, I'm saying that it's important that people ensure that they're being nice *while upholding a high standard of quality*, rather than removing important quality standards in the name of being "nice", which is neither necessary, not helpful.  I'd also like to take a second to point out that being nice and honest aren't at the top of that page, it's preceded by an explanation of the quality standards expected of questions; those are cardinal rules too.

Comment: @mason *"Why was the blog post even necessary?"* - I do **not** attempt to answer this question, but I think the fact that the blog post was written shortly after [this "rant"(?) that has now been mentioned in several comments](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) is at least a veeery suspicious coincidence. I hope that, one day, people will recognize that there is *always* someone who's mewling. And some of them are *really* suffering. (If I said what I think about this "rant", this comment would be deleted right away, so everybody can give it a guess...)

Comment: @Marco13 I appreciate the link! Did not enjoy reading it however. Could positively feel the self righteousness and condescension dripping off the screen.

Comment: This answer is better than that post... just sayin' :)

Comment: I applaud wanting to improve. My issue with the blog post is the conflation of bias and negativity based on gender, race, nation of origin, etc., and bias and negativity based on poor quality questions and answers. They are completely distinct issues with different causes, effects, moral dimensions, urgency, and potential solutions. They should never have been conflated into a single topic. Both need addressing, but separately, at different times, to avoid false equivalence. There would still be disagreement, but I think we'd've gotten a lot more light and a lot less heat.

Comment: @joran don't worry too much, the blog post has a personal slur against Mark Zuckerberg slap-bang in the middle of it, presumably in an attempt to side with the in-crowd hating on him after the recent hearings. If even the "EVP of Culture and Experience" is putting mean insults in the middle of a blog post boasting about how the site has no slurs, and needs to shift from "don't be assholes" and "delete unkindness *now*", what does that say about the chances of that actually happening?

Comment: I have never seen even the smallest hint of racism, sexism, or "ageism" in the [C++] corner of SO.  Do not assume that I am blind to it.  I am not. Far from it.  I have no doubt that complaints alleging such behavior are on the rise. They are on the rise everywhere. I think this will pass, probably two generations from now, when I am dead. In the meantime, if my efforts are not appreciated, I know quite well how to withdraw them without comment or fanfare.

Comment: @Benjoi "This answer is better than that post... just sayin' :)"   -- Which ain't sayin' much. Just sayin'. :-)

Comment: "I'm sorry that we didn't do enough to keep you from internalizing this."  I am always astonished by apologies like that.  "Oh if only I had anticipated how irrational you would be, I would have said the same things differently. My sincere apologies for not anticipating your 'internalization.'" Either admit you were wrong, or defend your position, or say nothing.

Comment: Blatant racism? Blatant sexism?...  --> Ban the user = Problem solved. :: What strikes me as being odd is the way SO has put a lot of effort into the Blog by Jay Hanlon and even this response by Tim Post, but had they put that much effort in simply changing the "How to Ask" page and the instructions in the "Tour" to redefine what is considered "good" posting and "good" behavior on SO this entire discussions would be completely unnecessary.

Comment: Just *which* people  are "increasingly and appreciably reporting that the site is not welcoming for a variety of reasons", I'm inclined to wonder?  By far, the posts most likely to elicit negative feedback, which in turn may make the poster feel unwelcome, read as if they come from someone who is *not* a professional or enthusiast programmer.  Well, this community is not *for* them.  It says so on the tin.  Although I agree that there is no call for wanton rudeness, it is in no way surprising if someone feels unwelcome at a site that is not targeted to them.

Comment: Even if I accept that all the things you describe are major problems here at SO, **top down enforcement doesn't fix internal bias.** The only way to overcome prejudice is to work as hard as you can and prove them wrong by doing more than they believed you're capable of. Sometimes it might even take a generation or two to get past. This is exactly how Italians, Irish, and Asians overcame prejudice against them in the U.S. Those prejudices are so rare in modern America that they're effectively dead. SO cannot create utopia and shouldn't try. It can only enforce a basic level of professionalism.

Comment: This blog post was one of the few things that made me care about SO again, I felt like "huh, it's not just me".  I really appreciate swift and clear moderation on SO, and I don't think its too big of an ask for us all to consider how we speak to each other,

Comment: "People ... enforcing these crazy unwritten rules that good grief can't I even ask a question stupid moderators editing my .. or, essentially, feedback we've been getting since the dawn of Stack Overflow because the system is so very distant from anything else, and since the community makes many of the rules" - **This is the company's fault** for saying that the community is allowed to make its rules, but then denying proper means for the community to **communicate** those rules to new users **before** they post.

Answer (score 51):

I probably qualify as one of those "demonized" users. Can't tell if I can be reliably labeled as a snarky commenter stalking the newcomers but much of other things I do likely contribute to making it harder to post stuff at Stack Overflow - reviews, votes down and close, flags.

And I feel like the blog post is offending people like me for what we are doing, and this is not the first time they do so (and probably won't be the last time).

That said, I can't see them stop doing that. Because, if you think of it, as soon as they admit that Stack Overflow community is okay, they will face a bunch of uncomfortable questions: what can be done at their side to keep site sufficiently nice, what could be the root cause of the snark, what can help to really improve things etc.

These would be difficult questions and I can understand why they would prefer to stay away from addressing these. So far, other options I've seen that could help were: giving more power to experienced users to handle an inappropriate content and / or improving guidance for new users. Both these options seem to be quite effort consuming and rather difficult to do right.

In comparison, it is so much easier to point finger at the community and tell them to shut up - and if this doesn't happen it is also easy to say that they really tried and blame community for the failure. It's just such an easy way out and we'd rather expect that they will keep doing this.

Even in the (unlikely) case that they admit that this particular blog post was wrong, just wait for a few months and you will probably see something like that happening again. As long as poor content floods the site and as long as quality measures are insufficient to manage it, there will always be multiple snarky comments from frustrated site regulars making such a convenient target for the *eternal fight for niceness*.

I am afraid that the question that quality-concerned users should be asking themselves is, how to prepare to handle such offense in the future and what can be done to minimize the damage it makes.

---

<sub>As a side note, I don't feel that somebody owes me thanks for my moderation efforts because [these *do* pay me back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366783#comment579915_366783):</sub>

> <sup>I am in it mostly for selfish reasons: I want Stack Overflow to keep helping people like me - those who get their answers here after dumping their question into google search box. SO did it fairly well so far and I wouldn't want to lose that help. I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps. I don't want it to be flooded with thousand answers to single simple question about NPE / NRE. And I do what I can to keep SO content the way it is helpful to me...</sup>

<sup>Following the same reasoning I support [removal of "welcoming" fluff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Greetings, expressions of appreciation, personal notes etc may look harmless for a random passer by, but for folks like me who frequently seek for help over here these only make site harder to use by obscuring answers we're looking for. And since my searches often involve studying multiple questions this fluff is quite a big deal to me.</sup>

Comment: This is such a good answer, you're looking at it from a different perspective to most and it's thought provoking.

Comment: So you missed the part of the blog post that said that the community is awesome and it’s all their fault?

Comment: related: [Please scrap the highly-problematic "how are we doing" survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415648/839601)

Answer (score 43):

There is a paragraph in the blog "Let’s reject the false dichotomy between quality and kindness", that maybe should have been emphasized much more. The blog post isn't about stopping enforcing the rules about quality, but about avoiding unnecessary hostility.

The SE Q&A system has a whole bunch of quirks and features that can make the experience for a new user quite intimidating. Downvoting and closing questions are probably the most prominent ones. Those have good reasons to exist, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't try to improve on them without compromising their purpose.

We don't answer "gimmeh teh codez" questions, and they should certainly be closed. But that doesn't mean that there aren't things we could do that would make it easier for the subset of users asking those that are able to improve. And it doesn't mean that we should add hostile comments on their posts, that doesn't achieve anything positive.

Using the community moderation tools like editing, closing and voting to ensure the quality is a good thing, and I don't think the blog post is saying anything else.

Comment: What *does* it say? I still don't understand what SO (the company) is planning to change/add/implement on SO (the site).

Comment: "I don't think the blog post is saying anything else.", So you agree with this answer from SO employee, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/7076153 ?

Comment: Right. A good way to avoid phantom 'hostility' (lets be honest, most of the time its just crankiness and hissy fits - but we lack the tools to stop those from escalating) is to just be allowed to be nice and civil, while currently we're basically advised to behave like robots. Even if the blog post is far from concrete, I do like where it is going.

Comment: The implication in the question title that the only "quality-concerned users" are ones who prioritise citation and enforcement of site rules should be getting more pushback. If a more tolerant approach is capable of encouraging more new users to settle into SO and progress from being sources of low-quality contributions to being sources of high-quality contributions, *that is a quality-concerned philosophy too*!

Comment: The dichotomy is not false. It's not logically entailed that niceness and quality be in tension, but as a matter of brute fact, in our universe, on our planet, they are. https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/08/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the link -- it is a good post that I hadn't read. The takeaway it suggests, however, is not about tension: "The choice here isn’t between being nice and being right. You can be nice each and every time you guide someone to the right answer or the correct behavior, and doing so is not only better for the community morale, it’s also more effective."

Comment: if I could upvote this +100 I would.  Swift and clear moderation is not in opposition to kindness at all.  @duplode this to me is exactly whats missing.

Comment: @bigmadwolf Yup -- it is not a single axis. That is lost from sight all too often in this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 41):

I am not a professional programmer.  My degree is in electrical engineering.  I received it so long ago that Fortran was the preeminent language choice for the programming requirement.

Here it is, 30 years later, and I asked a PHP question.  It was asked out of frustration.  I'd spent several hours hunting the Internet for an answer.  It was missing ***one*** piece of information that would have been useful to answerers.

**And then I made the cardinal mistake of stepping away from my desk for 15 minutes.**

In that time over a dozen comments appeared.  About half were run-of-the-mill requests for clarification.  The rest..

- chastized me for missing the one piece of information,
- chastized me for what they perceived as not doing enough research (after 2 hrs of my own research I knew they didn't know what they were talking about),
- and chastized me for not responding to the comments fast enough.

I lost my temper, edited my question, and chastized them back.  My question was then edited by another to remove my response claiming that I was acting unprofessionally.  I actually laughed.  But I learned to expect that the community would hold me to a higher standard than it holds itself.

In comments a lengthy but civil discussion ensued about what I could have done better and the culture of the site.  One of the responders complained that it was an affront to him to spend his time answering questions that did not meet his expectations.  I walked away with the distinct impression that there are those on the site who think it's only for the worthy and wondering, if his time was so valuable, why he didn't simply downvote and move on.

30 minutes or so after I posted my question, the entire question was deleted by three of the users (thanks for clarifying that Yvette).

Full disclosure: the majority of the problem was caused by one commenter.

And curiously, another commenter actually answered the question — as the first comment.  He hadn't posted it as an answer because of the missing piece of information, and so he couldn't be sure it was right.

**Conclusion**

Your rant against the blog post only reinforces the value of the blog post.  The lack of civility on this site is deplorable.  Questions answered today (literally *today*) are still receiving mean spirited comments.  Honestly, it sounds as if you think Stack Overflow *owes* you something.

Frankly, the site appears to have become a home for people who find joy in despising newcomers.  Gratefully, it appears to only be a very vocal minority.

Comment: Was tha question deleted by a __moderator__ or delete-voted by users? If I read this correctly, you understand how annoying it can be if the OP goed AFK as soon as the question is posted?

Comment: @Cerbrus, that's a good question.  I made an assumption because I can no longer see the question.  As for being AFK... I participate on a lot of SE sites and this is the only one that can't be patient.  I've answered hundreds of questions between here and elsewhere and never once complained that a request for clarification didn't come immediately.  SE participants are all over the world.  Sometimes they don't respond for 10-12 hours.  To bad the folks here feel it's better to complain that their time's being wasted instead of just letting someone else answer the question.

Comment: This sounds really familiar. Was I involved here?

Comment: @JBH: So what essentially happened was that you made a post that was missing information, people behaved aggressively towards you, and you countered with aggression of your own. The root problem of this interaction was... your original post which was *missing information*. This goes back to my personal point, that [quality creates kindness, and lack of kindness comes from lack of quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366774/734069).

Comment: @JBH: That being said, that doesn't absolve the aggression your post faced in terms of comments, particularly the "you didn't answer fast enough" parts. I'm not even sure where that comes from. But responding in kind is also not helpful.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, you might have.  Your moniker looks familiar.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I did not realize the information was missing.  It's certainly easy from the answerer's POV to see that it is, but the original question seemed perfectly clear to me.  Justifying the site's poor manners because of an OP's imperfection is blatantly throwing the first stone.  I've downvoted your linked answer because it demands perfection from the imperfect and suggests bad manners can ever be excused.

Comment: @JBH: this site gets a _lot_ of traffic. Users are usually reading your question with an intent to answer within seconds of it being posted. Try to keep that in mind in the future ;-)

Comment: @JBH: "*Justifying the site's poor manners because of an OP's imperfection is blatantly throwing the first stone.*" I'm not sure what you mean by that in this context. My point is that good quality questions don't get this treatment. If you had provided that information initially, there would have been no comments about you not responding fast enough or that there was missing information. If you want to fix a problem, you have to know its root cause. And knowing that the root cause was an improper question tells us that making questions better will fix the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas, My reference in this context is that I don't believe for a second that any participant on SO (including you) has a 100% track record for asking perfect questions.  The whole point of Jay's blog is that the community continues to blame and punish the inexperienced for being inexperienced.  Please forgive me for being blunt, but another's incivility is not my fault.

Comment: @JBH, I know *exactly* where you are coming from. I say this as someone who answers more than asks. What *should* have happened is **one or two** people should post a single comment each on how you can improve your question and others upvote those. No drama, no extended conversation. We should have the patience to let you mull an hour or three before updating your question. But this back-and-forth in comments about the value of each other's time is deeply *off-topic* and should be flagged as unnecessary chat.

Comment: If you're able to find that specific example, will you let me know, please? I'm curious if it's the same thing I thought it was. Anyway, I'm sorry that a few people are able to influence the image of the community as a whole to that extent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic... Amen.  Note that the original Q was deleted.  It was asking if there was a more streamlined method in PHP for using the Null coalescing operator in the specific instance of `$_POST??''`.  The missing info was that `$_POST` was involved.  I asked generically about an example `$var??''`.  I had a lot of them, couldn't depend on a fixed var name list, and because it's `$_POST`, you can't simply pre-define the values.  I ended up having to pull the column name list from MySql and use it to create the var name list.

Comment: You know you can see your recently deleted questions with a link at the bottom of the questions section of your profile? Although after your description I'm already fairly certain that was the question I was thinking of. I remember feeling bad about how that whole thing went. I was the one who edited your question if it is the same one I'm thinking of. I hope I didn't call you unprofessional at that point, considering how much the situation had already declined by then.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Please don't worry!  Momentary irritation happens and I know perfectly well that the 99.9% are suffering due to the bad behavior of the 0.1%.  Frankly, my loss of temper was just as inexcusable as the poor behavior I was responding to.  I appreciate the reminder that I have a responsibility to be nice, too.  Cheers!

Comment: But regarding _"the community would hold me to a higher standard than it holds itself"_, on one hand I see where you're coming from, but on the other hand, the community is composed of individuals, each with their own set of hopefully non-hypocritical standards. Part of the larger problem may be that the various individuals have different impressions of what the community standards are.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If I recall correctly, that was basically one of the points Jay was making in his post, wasn't it?  No clear direction or a methodology for inforcing it if it existed?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: "this site gets a lot of traffic. Users are usually reading your question with an intent to answer within seconds of it being posted. Try to keep that in mind in the future ;-)" That's both unknowable and not the asker's fault or responsibility.

Comment: There's a point here, and that is that veteran users are too eager to jump on the comment bandwagon on whatever the first comment said. Often without reading the question carefully. And then if that initial comment isn't constructive, or if it is simply incorrect, it all goes downhill. When that happens, other users have a responsibility to step in and say "hey, there's nothing wrong with this question, because...". One user doing that, then suddenly people start to think before down-voting or posting further comments. This can stop the whole negative spiral and save the whole post.

Comment: @D_N This is a mild instance of something I see in Meta more often than I would like: after some dubious user-moderation practice is identified, advice is given to the affected party to adapt themselves to it, contorting their posts for the sake of approval if need be. The end result is entrenching the dubiousness.

Comment: what you experienced was more of a `PHP` culture than a `StackOverflow` cultural response. Do the same thing in `C++` and you would really have a reason to cry a river.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome meh. I monitor a not-so active tag, and TBH if the OP posts a question that needs clarifications, I'll kindly comment asking for them, and keep the browser tab open for 5-15 minutes. SO gets thousands of questions every minute, it's a completely different pace than every single other SE site. If the OP that goes AFK and hasn't responded or edited their post after 15 minutes, I usually proceed to DV+VTC and close the tab, never to see that post again. Sometimes I get a ping from the OP a day later, I'll reassess and VTR, but by then it's often too late.

Comment: What I mean is, new folks need to understand that nobody is going to monitor their half-baked question all day, let alone all week. Perhaps if the help center reinforced the need for a question to be *initially* as complete as possible, told new users to avoid going AFK within the critical 5-15 minutes after posting (by that time the question usually showed up in all chat feeds that monitor the tag and the regulars have all seen it), then things would be generally better.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, SO's "pace" is easily offset by its vast worldwide user base.  I'd need proof that the question-volume-per-active-user ratio is substantially different from any but the newest SE sites.  Expert users are available every minute of the entire 24-hour day.  Neither your immediate personal input nor an immediate clarification are necessary because the next guy who can answer the question is just waking up.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, SO is toxic for new users because veterans will VTC so quickly that the remaining 99% of the planet (literally) never even gets the chance to answer the question.  There is no rule in the [help] that obligates me to meet your personal timeframe.  And until there is one, you have no right to VTC simply because an OP didn't respond to a request for clarification as quickly as you would prefer.

Comment: It was deleted by 3 members of the community, not a mod and it's a classic example of where we go wrong as a community.

Comment: Linky? I can open deleted posts on stackoverflow. We need good examples not the bad ones we've been dealing with for the past few days.

Comment: "Honestly, it sounds as if you think Stack Overflow owes you something." Actually, that's the way many newcomers - and most proponents of the "SO is so unwelcoming" thing - act about Stack Overflow, as if they were *owed* an answer, a particular treatment, free coding services, and sometimes even particular ways of addressing them.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, What I expected when I started using SO was that its participants would abide by the conduct rules stated in, among other things, the terms and conditions of the site as provided by the site owners. If you feel it's unreasonable for SE to establish rules of conduct, please address that concern to them. The consequence of this and many other discussions was a substantial improvement (though some may say restriction) in individual behavior. I don't think SO owes me free coding or any answer. I believe its participants owe me adherence to the same rules I'm expected to obey.

Comment: @JBH I haven't said, nor implied, that establishing rules of conduct was unreasonable, why do you say that? What I say, is that the sentence from your post I cited, is mostly directed at the wrong group of people. The general "you" that is used, is really not the group, nor a person, that acts as if they were owed something. The rules - research, showing what has been done, being open to answer - we're expected to obey, are broken by askers in the vast majority of questions that are asked, *literally* today, on the front page of SO.

Comment: You say that people are uncivil, and that you expect them to obey the rules as you do, and that's fine, but you seem unaware that in the first place, askers rarely, if ever, even read what is expected of them, and much less respect it. All the attention was drawn on the comments, and the askers disrespect of the guidelines was mostly ignored. Hopefully the ask a question wizard will help with that.

Answer (score 35):

I agree with you.

Some people fail to understand something very basic:

**In most professions, you learn from your mistakes.**

**Stack Overflow is the same.**

I started participating on Stack Overflow not too long ago, but I had been using Stack Overflow for years before participating, mostly because I felt I wasn't skilled enough to answer questions or because I never had to resort to help outside of Google's scope.

My quick integration in Stack Overflow allowed me to notice a major problem which is a little ironic to me considering that Stack Overflow is programming-oriented:

A part of the community, such as Jay Hanlon, as portrayed in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), are **taking programming too lightly**.

It's fine that new users want to learn - **learning is great** - but **Stack Overflow is not a playground**. There are rules, rules that allow Stack Overflow to evolve rather than devolve. Like somebody mentioned once before, asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the absolute [last resort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593).

The world of programming is constantly evolving, programming is slowly becoming a major aspect of everyday life, **programming is going to shape the future, and do not take it lightly**.

The increase in the importance of programming is leading to an increase in users joining Stack Overflow.

Some of those users are passionate about programming. Some are just trying to get through school. Some are serious. Some are just looking for answers.

Some post questions without trying anything, just a blatant `halp me`, with very little effort. **That's not okay**. If a user cannot show that he or she has *tried* to fix the issue, if a user shows no will to *learn* the answer to his question, then is it really abnormal for answerers to not show the will to *teach*, but instead feel frustrated at the lack of effort shown?

#### Don't misunderstand

It's okay to make mistakes. New users may struggle with how to format code when asking their first few questions. They may ask a question that has already been asked, but written differently. They may forget to provide basic information about how to reproduce their scenario. **All of that is okay**, it's part of the learning experience.

#### It's normal that more questions are being marked as duplicate than before.

More questions are asked and answered everyday, meaning that it's one less question that can be asked.

If you make a forum about alphabet letters, eventually they'll run out of letters to talk about.

#### As time moves forward, this will not get any better.

A question that has already been answered using version A of a programming language/framework may not be compatible with the version B of that same programming language. But those questions may sometimes get closed for duplicates.

#### Seriously

Stack Overflow has a learning curve, just like Vim. If new users are angry with the way they are treated, it's because they haven't grasped how Stack Overflow works.

In my opinion, the real problem is that too much people are being dramatic about this situation, and it's making everyone overreact.

Stack Overflow is doing perfectly fine just the way it is. If you're not willing to take a bit of criticism on Stack Overflow, then you're not serious enough. Otherwise, be like me and embrace the [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3270037) may have been what you were referring to when mentioning a question is last resort

Comment: @NickA Thank you, that's exactly it. Added the reference.

Comment: Hmm.. deja vu about photographers/graphic designers being royally pissed at clients not taking their work seriously. Really unique perspective.

Comment: *just like Vim* ... exactly. Can't exit ...

Answer (score 30):

> I have never discriminated against anyone based on their age, skin colour, gender, accent, or whatever. I have discriminated against those who show no desire to make an effort to think, or read basic "how to ask" pages, or who just don't care. And I will continue to discriminate against those people.

I agree with this completely. The basic flaw in the argument in the blog post is that, in the vast majority of cases, I have **no idea** what the race, age, skin color, etc. of the poster is prior to taking moderation action on the post. Even in cases where I did know, it really didn't make any difference in what the appropriate moderation action is. I think that that part of the blog post was a rather bizarre (and decidedly offensive) argument, truthfully; I simply see no evidence that it's the case.

If there *is* evidence that someone is being abusive towards a specific user - whether based on race, gender, or any other factor - the solution is the same as it's always been: flag any rude posts as such, and maybe flag for moderator intervention explaining the situation if the user in question is clearly out of hand.

Personally, I try to focus on content, not users, when downvoting or voting to close. I think that, for the most part, I'm successful with that. Also, I do agree that there's sometimes too much of a tendency to leave snarky or sarcastic comments, which is clearly unnecessary. I think that that's the thing that the blog post should have focused on, *not* implying that people who moderate the site are somehow racist, sexist, or whatever.

I also agree that the blog post did show a certain lack of gratitude. I currently have 440 answers (vs. 30 questions) on the main site and multiple gold badges for reviewing, so it seems like at least *some* gratitude is in order there (especially given that I'm not being compensated for my efforts) rather than implying that I'm somehow a hostile jerk for trying to keep the site clean.

Comment: I appreciate someone finally saying this. I don't even know how it's possible to discriminate based on skin color on this site. If a question includes the user's skin color, it's probably noise and should be edited out. I could *maybe* see gender, since username can *sometimes* imply it.

Comment: I agree, especially with new users who are often user#### with a generic icon, that the answerer is unaware of the questioners race/gender/etc, but perhaps "minority" questioners are more likely to experience any unfriendliness more severely.

Answer (score 21):

The thing that affronted me the most is not the accusations but the fact that he didn't bother to back himself up:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

What the hell is he talking about?! I don't, and never have, felt SO as "unwelcoming", even when my posts get downvotes and/or are closed (and they still do occasionally). And I don't ever see the people I'm communicating with, so if they get discriminated, that absolutely must be something that I can see, not their race, gender or social status.

Then, based on these unbased and highly questionable claims, he's mandating us to do some serious change of course.

And there isn't even any feedback mechanism provided on the page, so I cannot even let them know how ridiculous this is!

---

Now, I wouldn't demand an apology for "insulting" anyone since that can be a humiliation for no clear reason (people can get "insulted" by anything really). But there's strong evidence that the posts's author did a sloppy job, and they can acknowledge that in a mild manner, e.g. add a banner saying that the post has proven to be controversial and shouldn't be taken at face value / as official standpoint. Or just go the SO way and fix the problems in the post outright ([we may even have a discussion about specifics](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog)).

Answer (score 20):

Hmm...

I honestly think it was a mistake to conflate the general quality control harshness with a very different sort of harshness that's found a place to root on Stack Exchange.

I'll admit that joining the two issues has some strong reasoning though.

There is a lot of harshness tolerated here, because it's been seen as necessary to fight a rising tide of poor content. I've spent enough time in the review queues to understand why people start getting harsh and at times a bit rude about the quality of content. There's only so many times you can close yet another post about centering a div, before you want to snap. I get it.

On the other hand there's a different sort of user who seems to enjoy being harsh. Rather than wishing for a higher quality of content they seem to enjoy the opportunity to feel superior. The opportunity to be harsh where people praise them for it.

Then there's the sort of user who may overlap with the previous set. The sort of user who not only enjoys the opportunity to be harsh, but who is also perhaps a bit racist, or sexist, or homophobic...

You may see where I'm going with this, but the encouraged harshness has brought more than few people to the Stack Exchange Network who are probably here for the wrong reasons, and the encouraged harshness has allowed them to take root here, **and at times be defended by good faith users.**

You're pissed off about low quality content and you're pissed off about being painted with a broad brush. That's understandable. But be very careful about what you do with that anger. Don't end up defending the indefensible, don't inadvertently give people who are here for the wrong reasons your support.

I don't like it any more than anyone else, but we have some problems to deal with on the network. We can admit that the network isn't perfect and people who enjoy being harsh for the sake of it are making us all look bad, or we can defend ourselves and inadvertently defend these problem users. **And worse, let problem users drive us all apart, and drive honestly well meaning users away from the network.**

Comment: I can agree with a good portion of this, but the blog post doesn't actually seem to focus on users who are harsh because they enjoy it.

Comment: I can definitely get everything you're saying in this answer, but I think it bears mentioning that *lousy, but not provably lousy* folks have a very long history of being deliberately defended by the best elements of society's justice. That's where we get concepts like the right to a jury trial, innocence until proven guilt, protection against illicit search/seizure, and so forth: all protections that, in normal circumstances, mostly protect those who probably did do something at least rather nasty. So for SE to inadvertently shelter a few sneaky louses is far from the worst possible thing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy those protections are there for a reason. If you never found yourself in the need of those protections because you are innocent, good. I wish that you never will be in a situation like that.

Comment: @Rhayene: Perhaps I wasn't clear; my point was that in order to protect innocent people and good things, it's been found necessary for centuries to *also* protect some guilty people and bad things. (As few as possible, certainly, but it's never been anywhere near none.)

Comment: If you want to stay with the law analogy: It is perfectly fine for a policeman to arrest a thief (aka close a off-topic question). It is not ok for a police man to punch the thief in the face while arresting them (aka leave a "This is soooo basic, if you're to stupid to understand even that you're shouldn't be here" style comment). I read the blog as a statement against the second part, not about the closing itself.

Comment: @NathanTuggy it seems I misunderstood. I am sorry for this.

Comment: @BDL: The blog is partly against comments (which is not necessarily that big a deal, although coming down harder on comments on answers to terrible questions is not something I agree with), but also partly and explicitly against downvotes. ("It makes me *sad* when someone get downvoted for posting a duplicate.") Downclosevoting isn't police brutality (unlike rude comment pileups); it's using a fairly reasonable amount of force to ensure the job does get done.

Comment: @NathanTuggy This sentence has been discussed in several meta posts now. I still think it says "Don't downvote duplicates because they are duplicates" with which I agree. It doesn't say, imho, that one shouldn't downvote duplicates if they don't meet the quality standard. I'v seen a large number of duplicates that were downvoted although they were actually well written (and sometimes even better written then the dupe target).

Comment: Not finding a duplicate is (imho) not a lack of research that warrants down-voting (with some exceptions like duplicates that can be found by pasting the question title into google). The whole blog post doesn't say anything about downvoting other things than duplicates like off-topic or unclear questions.

Comment: @BDL: Dupe voting is a bit fuzzy anyway, but the post does nothing to clarify things. My own guidelines would be something like this: if the post is clearly a solid, well-researched, clearly-phrased question that adds a new dimension to searchability of the dupe target, I'll cheerfully upvote. If it's lacking a bit of that, I'll be more hesitant, or will just leave it unvoted. If it took an unusually short amount of time to find the dupe, or if it took longer than normal to figure out what the question was saying in order to find it, I'll downvote.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I totally agree with that and this is also how I handle duplicates. But there are other opinions which say that duplicates should be downvoted no matter of their quality because not finding the duplicate target is inherently a lack of research. Seeing good questions downvoted due to this also makes me sad (to stay with the words of the blog). I think we all should see the blog way more relaxed and not interpret the worst in it. And I for sure do not agree with everything said in the blog. We all should wait which proposals will be made to improve the situation and than judge that

Comment: So your theory is that a bunch of racist, or sexist, or homophobic people who also love programming and spent quite a lot of time getting good at it came here not because they love programming but because they were looking for a place where they can be racist, right... their plan was also not to do it on SO(because we can't see it here) but wait for some years until other sites will be opened were they can manifest their racism... yeah... makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Oleg: ... huh? Where are you getting that from? The post isn't saying anything of the kind. What it's saying is that unpleasant people came to answer questions along with perfectly reasonable people. But now that we're trying to do something about the unpleasant ones, some of the reasonable ones are defending them without realizing how unpleasant they are. I'm not sure I agree with that, but it's certainly not some conspiracy theory that the sexist/racists/etc somehow *planned* all of this.

Comment: @NicolBolas "who is also perhaps a bit racist, or sexist, or homophobic..." followed by "brought more than few people to the Stack Exchange Network who are probably here for the wrong reasons" means apaul thinks some people came here specifically with the goal of being racist, or sexist, or homophobic

Comment: @Oleg: Ehhh I'd suggest "wrong reasons" is just a slightly clunky way of saying something more along the lines of "impure motives" (that they aren't here *to make a programming library that is better for everyone in the best possible way*, but something a little short of that, like a programming library that's better for white Java programmers or something).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I know I'm reaching but apaul is talking about 3 distinct groups one of those groups is racists,sexist.... And because I also know that he wants to expel all racists from SO even if their racism doesn't manifest in any way I think that's what he really means.

Comment: @Oleg: Perhaps a better way of understanding what Apaul is talking about can be found in this page on the [Five Geek Social Fallacies.](http://www.plausiblydeniable.com/opinion/gsf.html) It's an old document, but I think GSF's 1-3 are at least somewhat relevant to what Apaul is saying. It's not *exactly* the same thing, but it's similar.

Comment: @NathanTuggy to keep with your law analogy, some cops like being cops because they want to serve and protect the community they love. On the other hand, some cops, even those who started out with good intentions, sometimes get mad and go too far. And sometimes, some cops actually are just corrupt and abusive and got into it for the wrong reasons. Now should we say all cops are awful and should be denounced, or do we take a nuanced and realistic look at the complaints a department is receiving? I think we're finally beginning to take a nuanced and realistic look.

Comment: @NicolBolas Possible and I can see why you think so based on the post, but I would be surprised if this is the case. I have no idea who those "problem users who drive us all apart" are, we are driven apart by SO employees. SO was fine before that blog post.

Comment: @apaul: "*I think we're finally beginning to take a nuanced and realistic look.*" OK, so... where is it? Because that blog post is *sorely* lacking in nuance (and other things). It's so poorly written that it's basically a Rorschach test: everyone sees what they bring to it. One person sees that it clearly denounces unexplained downvotes; another person disagrees. If we want to have a "nuanced and realistic look" at any problem, we need to actually have that, not a single, poorly written blog followed by chirping crickets.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not trying to defend the blog post. Ya, it wasn't as well put together and articulated as it could have been, or should have been, but it did mention a few things worth taking a look at. The part that I was most concerned with was the bit about how minorities are treated on the network, because that's the part that's most affected me personally.

Answer (score 17):

There have been so many times in the last few years since I've been a member that I've tried to help someone who tried, but simply didn't understand what he needed to do.

So I spent half an hour typing an answer explaining every step on the level I perceive the OP being able to interpret the answer, to follow it and to gain knowledge.

Equally as many times I receive a comment among the lines of "You should have closed this answer as a dupe -1", however a lot of times I also receive a thank you from the op, stating it was insightful with some follow up questions to clarify stuff.

The people who forget that this is a site to help people, to give answers to questions to people can understand, that future visitors can understand on a level that they can understand, to build a knowledge base that's interpretable by advanced coders, and the novices. I also think that a lot of people simply stop discerning, who is a person who needs clarification what all the stufzz means and who is someone that says, gimme the codez.

With every answer I try to give the OP, and future readers that might also have the OP's question, insight into what he/she needs to know to understand his/her problem, how to find a solution and what steps to take.

Then in the years following I find the upvotes on those questions slowly trickling in, meaning I helped some people provide what they needed on those simple questions that others just want to close as a dupe.

So when that blogpost came, I truly agreed. There are too many users too quick with the close as dupe, close as too broad, within minute of a question being up sometimes. And the OP commenting under it that he doesn't understand how the other scenario applies to his issue. Mostly because the OP lacks the experience.
So that user probably then leaves disillusioned and toils on with his problem.

When I started people used to ask a few questions via the comments, to find out the problem, to ask for more code, giving the OP some time to update, people who saw the comment then left the answer alone until it was at least a day passed.

Today however, I find no comments, just closed as dupe almost instantly, even on the question where the OP clearly states his lack of knowing where to start looking where it's a clear X/Y problem, without a single comment asking deeper, or a snarky comment referencing a dupe and that the OP should do research before posting.

So yeah, Stack Overflow has a lot of dupes, and most questions already have answers. I find myself unable to ask a good question, because they usually already have all good answers I can use. But I have 17 years of experience on my side. I can make a Java answer work for PHP because the Java answer pointed me to the fundamentals I needed to know. A new user most likely doesn't have that experience.

So I agree with that part of the blogpost, and I think Stack Overflow should basically start being a bit more forgiving for people who lack experience and are not "gimme the codez" people. Burn those. But people who are curious, lack the experience and gathered the courage to post here with their problem, we should be welcoming them, encouraging their curiosity, and help them on their way.

Note, this is just my reflection and observation of how Stack Overflow went in the last 6 years from harsh welcome to slightly unfriendly. Experiences may vary by person or tags.

Comment: You can welcome and encourage someone while still recognizing that their question is a duplicate and has an answer elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Does anyone really close Java questions as dupes of PHP questions? Seriously?

Comment: "The people who forget that this is a site to help people, to give answers to questions to people can understand, that future visitors can understand on a level that they can understand, to build a knowledge base that's interpretable by advanced coders, and the novices." wow we strongly disagree about that.

Comment: I agree with much of what you're saying (so I upvoted), apart from what you're saying about dupes. OTOH, I certainly agree that much can be done to make dupe closure seem less harsh / hostile to new OPs, and largely that can be done with the existing interface.

Comment: Usually a comment under the question explaining WHY it's a dupe goes a long way, pointing to a certain answer in the dupe target helps too with some guidelines as to how OP can translate it to his problem. Sometimes that helps OP to reword his question to make his problem more specific. But a lot of dupe closes just lack that extra touch.

Comment: Then invite them to chat instead of having an edit/comment/answer war trying to figure out what the OP was actually asking for.  Those kinds of questions, typically, aren't useful.  I downvote answers that are trying to guess at what the OP wanted because they aren't answers, they are guesses.  That's the whole point of the comments: get clarity on the question.  Once you have the question actually nailed down, go nuts with answers.

Comment: If only inviting to chat was easy. Oh, and you might have forgotten the purpose of comments. Asking clarification, providing suggestions and answering on those.

Comment: When closing as a dupe, you _can_ still leave a comment explaining why. "On line 99 you do x. Don't do that. See the linked duplicate for details."

Comment: "The people who forget that this is a site to help people, to give answers to questions to people can understand" - the purpose of the site **is not** to, in some nebulous way, "help people"; it is specifically to *maintain a repository of high-quality answers to questions*. Answer quality entails that answers are accessible to (understandable by) the people that would most likely have the question. It also entails that questions are **not duplicated** and that answers are **centralized**. If the best existing version of the question has unsatisfactory answers, **add your answer there**.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I hope Stack Overflow stops demonizing them extremely soon, because **the entire site is becoming such a horrible mess!**

**It's the first time I've seen so many low quality questions (and low quality answers too) on SO. They are growing like weeds.**

I ended up here from Google searching for stuff like "is stackoverflow dying" because I had the feeling something wrong was happening to the community.

IMHO they should forbid for a while to any newbies the ability to ask a first question unless they reach a certain reputation.

---

And about your quote:

> Stack Overflow the site, and programming in general, is a meritocracy.

It sounds harsh, but it's true!

Coding is a discipline someway like math and science, it's not something that is "opinion based", it's not politics, it's not a democratic process, it's a meritocratic one.

**If a newby doesn't even respect a code of conduct, and the site guidelines**, and for these reasons he/she/it feels discriminated by age, skin colour, gender, accent...
...well he/she can go and ask his/her questions on a site that migh suits him/her better like Facebook or at the nearby local pub.

Comment: @Jean it seems it just came all of a sudden (maybe in few quarters), last year I did not notice SO was getting messy. Maybe it's something that can still be fixed, unless I didn't notice it only because the chaos had already grown but was still not exceeding the order.

Comment: "they should forbid for a while to any newbies the ability to ask a first question unless they reach a certain reputation" note here that without the ability to ask questions you are denying the opportunity of earning reputation. The system is designed that you earn reputation by participation, without it venues of earning non-trivial reputation are non-existent.

Comment: @Braiam can't they grow reputation by answering first to some questions, instead of asking ridiculous questions without even searching on Google for 5 seconds. Anyway it was an idea just to fix the mess for a while, not meant to be forever.

Comment: @Moritz: I agree the entire site is marching down into hell! Such a pity!

Comment: @MarcoDemaio I prefer the run of the mill asker not answering questions... usually their knowledge isn't enough to actually answer a question (blind guiding the blind situation). Remember, everyone can ask a question, but not anyone is able to answer. That's why answering yields more reputation than asking.

Comment: @Braiam `everyone can ask a question` Unfortunately, judging from the thousands of flags and close votes I had to put on "questions" these last months, I don't believe this anymore. Some people are just incapable of even this basic task. It's very sad but it's where we are.

Comment: @Moritz when I said "everyone can ask a question" I was actually comparing the intrinsic value of an answer vs a question, not implying the capacity that anyone has to produce quality content.

Comment: I agree with you. I think SO is getting worse every day. SO should be more strict and even newbies should respect the rules that made this site the greatest programming site.

Comment: This is all very one-sided.  Low-quality questioners are incentivised by by the fact that there are a lot of contributors willing to answer their questions.  It's not all about newbies, and generalising like this about newbies is, to say the least, unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer, I concentrated on the post controversy. In this one, I'll concentrate on the underlying matter.

1. There's definitely a fine line to walk between caring about quality and being petty while doing that.
2. There should be a barrier to entry, but there's always a trapping of it becoming too high to maintain a stable community (roughly, the ratio of "requests per time period/active members" should be kept low enough to get a decent processed rate, and there's always an inevitable churn which the inflow of new members must compensate).

*The blog post basically says that they* feel *the community has deviated to the pettiness side, and the balance needs to be restored.* The problem with the post essentially is that they formulated this badly.

Leaving aside the validity of this observation, here are some thoughts on how  to keep the balance:

- Programmers are expected to know to, and to be able to learn the essentials when delving into unfamiliar areas. This is one of the critical skills in the trade.

  - But to RTFM, you need to know where exactly to find what you need (because [learning anything that you don't need is not an effective time investment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338492/should-we-be-teaching-people-to-think-for-themselves/338500#338500)), [which is not always immediately apparent](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8934/what-to-do-with-questions-when-the-answer-is-in-a-man-page/8936#8936)
  - Besides, you need to know that you *do* need this and absolutely cannot do without it to warrant investing time
- So, **when rejecting a question, give (links to) useful hints (this includes casting close votes if the resulting boilerplate message would contain a useful hint)**

  - [It's permissible to give external links if the existing help system articles are not good enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended/356058#356058)
  - If a message is presented to new users, it needs to say right away, in an overt manner, that not looking through a few select help pages first would most likely lead to their question being rejected (maybe give a percentage with a link to statistics to show we're not joking).
- To avoid delving into pettiness, **concentrate on information, not attitude**

  - In particular: **do not comment if a vote would say just as much**
  - [Give the right message, **which includes the message given by votes**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366352/what-is-the-ground-of-earning-reputation-with-overall-negative-scored-vote-quest) (i.e. account for the fact how votes are interpreted when giving them)

    - In particular, if a question is bad, perhaps only drive its score as low as hideous the question is (voters already seem to be applying this subconsciously)
- [Online communities, especially tech ones, are "direct" cultures](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html#believe2) because time is more precious here than in live communication

  - [This can be especially jarring and come across as rudeness to people who hail from "polite" cultures](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/how-do-you-know-if-americans-genuinely-literally-mean-what-they-say/38192#38192) because it's vastly different to what they're accustomed with.
  - Users need to be able to learn this somehow other than by trial and error
- SO is mature now, and most common problems have already been asked and answered.

  - So, it's only natural that more questions are being closed as duplicates and downvoted for lack of search effort
  - But duplicates are not deleted specifically because you need to know the right keywords to find an answer
- So, **when deciding whether to downvote a duplicate, see if the existing answer can be found by the keywords that the OP has used**
- Likewise, it's becoming ever more important to systemically encourage locating related questions/possible duplicates -- at the very least, to reduce time wasted and anxiety built up on duplicate questions

  - E.g. there's already a panel that suggests these when typing a new question (I wonder if there are numbers how many duplicate questions it has prevented from appearing).
  - [Maybe the same tool for answerers that appears automatically?](https://stackapps.com/questions/2253/duplicate-question-suggestion-boxes) (The app on the link is dead.) Improving search? (E.g. I often see that Google finds more relevant questions than the internal search)

Comment: `Give the right message, which includes the message given by votes.` This is like trying to swim against a tsunami. Culture has ingrained in us the attitude that negative marks are *personal*. I'm resigned to the fact that *no amount* of education will resolve this for new users (and, indeed, many experienced users). Giving the right message is pointless when it's not being received. Votes do have a purpose, it's to filter content for the rest of the community. Using votes to give OP "the right message" is a fool's errand.

Comment: @jpp No, I mean exactly this: give the right message with the votes, _accounting for the fact how the votes are received_. That's exactly why I argued that [downvoting to oblivion is not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366406/how-to-deal-with-answers-to-unanswerable-questions/366427#366427) (others seemed to disagree with that though so I hesitated to include this point here).

Answer (score -13):

This unfortunately all comes down to the reader... What some see as a perfectly fine answer others see as condescending. There are a number of things that can be done to reduce bad questions and bad answers. Sadly you can't make all users read your post with the actual inflection you intended, we have all gotten a text we thought was rude, only to learn we just took it the wrong way.

I just saw a comment on one of my posts I thought was snarky... Then I clicked the user profile and he is the nicest guy you could imagine... Yes sometimes stackers are judgemental, but this is not usually the case. It's usually the reader taking it the wrong way. If something offensive is said we have flags and moderators. Just keep trucking guys, you are all legends.

Comment: IMHO mem "SO is toxed"  is not about "somebody said something" - it is normal - we all are human after all - but about the fact that during review "sloppy" questions are judged the same way as "nice but offtopic" (downvoted and closed) what could be really offensive. IMHO nice offtopics should be closed without downvoting and with attempt to show more respect to the authors.

Answer (score -15):

When more people like you speak up.

It stings at first to come up against the high standards that people have for the site and failing to meet those standards. One can complain, or one can remember that they're still a worthwhile person and that they are fully capable of meeting these high standards. The second path is one of maturity and ego strength.

People who lack a strong sense of self (i.e. can't handle criticism) are wont to lash out at people who remind them of their own insecurities, and they complain.

People in management tend to grease the squeakiest wheel. The people who are most invested should get squeakier like you are, and they will inevitably relent. That is unless the company culture has been taken over by the same sort of person who makes their insecurities other people's problems. If so, it will only ever get worse.

Comment: Did you mean "want" instead of "wont" in your 2nd paragraph? Anyways, I have trouble understanding your point here?

Comment: Nope. "Wont" as in accustomed to, or used to.

Comment: ["Wont" is indeed a word.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wont)

Comment: The edit now makes your use of "wont" make more sense to me. Although for the benefit of non-English speakers, perhaps changing it to say "likely" instead of "wont" will convey the same meaning and have less chance of confusion?

Comment: Anybody is more than welcome to edit my post

Comment: ...or to simply look up an unfamiliar word in a dictionary and thus learn something!

Comment: The argument here seems rather self-serving and thus unconvincing: if others complain, it's because they're insecure and don't want to measure up against standards; if we complain, it's because we're right and we just have to convince management of that too, by being the loudest. Regardless of who you label "we" and "others", it seems like it could effortlessly swing either way by just reversing the labels.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's fair. The answer is incomplete in that respect. Thank you for holding me to a high standard. It's a sign of respect. :)

Comment: @mason: That's something else I've seriously contemplated for a while. What if the words we use are too big and convoluted for non-native speakers to understand? Should we accept edits that might otherwise be perceived as "dumbing down" the language of a post in an attempt to make it easier for non-native speakers to understand? Or should we do like LRiO suggested and have readers look up the words themselves (like we have askers do their own research)? I could totally envision a separate meta thread for this. And now that I've mentioned it, I bet someone's going to post one.

Answer (score -15):

The [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)
 post by [Jay Hanlon](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jhanlon/) is not discussing sexism or racism, and it's not suggesting being lax with moderation.

The premise of the post is:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place

And the reason given for that premise is:

> We trained users to tell other users what they’re doing wrong, but we didn’t provide new folks with the necessary guidance to do it right.

And we are given the criteria that defines the behaviour that is felt as hostile and elitist:

> Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong. They get snarky or condescending comments for not explaining what they’ve tried (that didn’t work). They get an answer… but the answerer gets scolded for “encouraging ‘low-quality’ questions.” They get downvoted, but don’t know why, or called lazy for not speaking English fluently. Or sometimes, everything actually goes well, and they get an answer! So they thank the poster… only to be told that on Stack Overflow, “please” and “thank you” are considered noise. All these experiences add up to making Stack Overflow a very unwelcoming place for far too many.

And there are a hell of a lot of examples of this out there.  Everyone on SO would have either seen or contributed to this behaviour.  It's undeniable that it exists.  It's accepted behaviour.  Users defend this behaviour.  It's not racists. It's not sexist. But it is hostile and it is elitist.  And this is exactly what the blog post is trying to address and to stop.  And I happen to wholeheartedly agree with it.

Comment: This is a great answer, I DON'T see why this get down vote so much.

Comment: @Eric because it is just as disingenuous as the original article. People who are acting in good faith, who don't intend to "discuss sexism or racism", *don't bring up* groups who are marginalized on the basis of sex or race in the same breath that they discuss concepts like "hostility" or "elitism". And, for that matter, it is not good faith to argue that it's "hostile" or "elitist" to point out that "please", "thank you" etc. are considered noise here [when that is clearly established policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950).

Comment: @karl hostility and elitism and racism and sexism can exist together but they are not tied together; they can exist independently. People who aren’t elitist can be racist/sexist and people who are friendly can be racist/sexist. Also, someone receiving racism and sexism can at the same time be giving racism and sexism to others. The hostility that I’ve seen on SO isn’t from sexism or racism, but from people being frustrated with repetitive and poor quality questions. It’s like a call center operator getting frustrated with customer calls. So no, I’m not being disingenuous. Stop conflating ideas

Comment: ... Did you forget about the context of the discussion? (Admittedly it has been five years, but the rest of the page is still here.) **The blog post** brings up sexism/racism in the same breath as hostility/elitism, and *that is why OP was upset*. For reference: "Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups." To say "especially", i.e., to allege disproportionate impact, is a technique people use to imply bigotry without having to actually provide evidence.

Comment: Anyway, my best guess is that you got downvotes for asserting that the blog post "is not discussing sexism or racism", when we've all been through this countless times before. That's the part I personally find disingenuous. Again, the context of OP makes it clear why the blog post registers that way. In your quote here, you simply *discard the part of the sentence that OP found antagonistic*, in order to assert that the antagonism didn't occur.

Comment: I think I left that part out because of my interpretation of that blog post, but maybe for the same reasons the OP used "especially ...".  Also, I don't really care about the downvotes as everyone has different opinions.  I also never said that racism/sexism doesn't occur.  I just haven't seen it, but I have very clearly seen the elitism and hostility, but that doesn't mean the sexism/racism/ageism doesn't happen. Most of the hostility I've seen has been due to poor quality questions.  I'm just one guy though... so its anecdotal.

Comment: Part of that may be people struggling with English, and the responses could be interpreted as racism, but I think its more in response to general communication issue rather than coming from racial hatred.  Again, I think its about conflating separate things... they may overlap but that doesn't mean they are causally linked.

Answer (score -16):

> I have discriminated against those who show no desire to make an
>   effort to think, or read basic "how to ask" pages, or who just don't
>   care. And I will continue to discriminate against those people.

I'm sure if you think about it for a moment you'll agree that the best you can have hoped to accomplish is to discriminate against those who *you believe* to have the motivations you describe.

Unquestionably, there are people who cut-and-paste a question from their homework without even having made an attempt to solve the problem. Most of those questions should receive a (polite) response of "please post your effort so far".

But there are also plenty of people who post a code snippet with a fairly obvious flaw, or who post an incomplete example, not out of laziness but simply because they are so early in the learning process that they *do not know* and *can reasonably be excused for not knowing* exactly what is needed to construct a complete, reproducible example of their problem. They may even have misidentified the problem entirely (for example, "Cannot Read From File" when the real problem is "Cannot Iterate a List"). It is really sad to see those questions "attacked" by drive-by downvotes when what the person actually needs is guidance in understanding where to find the information they need and then how to interpret that information.

It's my opinion that many people (maybe not you, but lots of people on Stack Overflow) are unable or uninterested in discerning the difference between the first and second type of person. No one has a responsibility to answer the second person's question (or anyone's question), but it's in the spirit of Stack Overflow (in my opinion, anyway) that second person should be allowed to ask their question, and someone who's interested in helping rank beginners to answer it, without receiving negative feedback.

And even in the case of the first person -- who posts no effort at all -- it's ultimately impossible to discern whether they're simply lazy or just so new that they don't even know where to look. So, ideally, rather than making the person feel bad with downvotes there would be a way to direct them to the correct beginners resource in the form of "read this, then post a specific question if there's something you don't understand".  If it continues to happen with multiple questions from the same person then, perhaps, some negative feedback is needed to encourage them to follow the advice they were given or to leave the site.

Comment: Thing is, there shouldn't *be* a discernment between the two groups.  Both show no effort.  One because they won't, the other because they can't.  While I feel for those who don't understand, learning how to debug and program isn't something that SO was ever meant for.  And downvoting is required to signal that it's not a good question.  Whether they're just lazy, won't follow the rules, or can't follow them, doesn't matter.  Voting is blind to the user.

Comment: There is a fourth option -- would follow the rules with sufficient education, but don't know how yet.  I see a lot of questions from people who I believe to fall into that category.  I think the original post that triggered this one is a clear indication that S/O *is* meant for those people.

Comment: From what I see, there are plenty of comments being made to help guide new users to the resources needed to help them learn.  Those are the users that do well, I find.  That doesn't really have any bearing on what voting is for, though.

Answer (score -18):

It is apparent that Stack Overflow has problems. I usually only look at the [C++] questions. The large majority are from new students who have not, and often will not, read the Asking and MCVE pages. They interpret succinct suggestions that they do so as affronts. Their questions receive downvotes. The newbies understandably become bothered and defensive.

Motivation is best done through positive reinforcement, not through negative punishment. As anyone who has managed a programming team, or even trained a pet, can attest, the major hurdle is "getting the behavior." One cannot reward or praise behavior that has not been presented. The solution is usually to substitute an easier assignment which can be achieved and praised.

The situation is not great for would-be helpers either. They are not presented with enough information to help. It is frustrating. The more experienced helpers often come from industry, where excuses are irrelevant, and a description of why, for example, a code-submission is erroneous or inadequate stands on its own. No apologies from the code-reviewers are required or expected. I cannot recall a single unpleasant exchange on Stack Overflow in which the original provocation from an old hand could not be charitably regarded as helpful, but terse. Using Meta to label such responses as mean or unwelcoming is counter-productive. Again, strive for the desired behavior, and reward it when it is presented.

Often good suggestions go unrewarded, perhaps because the newbie is unable to understand, or unwilling to do the necessary work.

I think the whole system needs a major re-factoring. I have a few suggestions for temporary stopgaps.

1. Disable downvotes and votes to close on new users' questions for an hour or two.
2. Provide an encouraging and helpful standardized response about Asking and MCVE.
3. Give rewards for responsiveness from the newbie. If they respond to a comment or answer at all, they get some cyber-praise.
4. This one I am not too sure about. Post newbie questions in a separate arena. No downvotes in that arena. When the question passes muster, it gets promoted to the main arena. Then there is a big reward and celebration. Maybe this suggestion could be folded into the others.

Comment: "*Disable down-votes and votes to close on new users' questions for an hour or two.*" So gaining reputation gives you the anti-privelege of your posts being able to be downvoted earlier? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas It makes sense to me. I already have a down-vote on this response, and hey, I can live with it.  The measure, which I propose as a "stop-gap" is only to prevent newbies from receiving the immediate negative feedback that they presently are subject to. I stopped down-voting newbie questions a while back, and my life is none the worse for it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I do respect your opinions. When I see your moniker on an SO response, I know it will be a good one.  How can we mitigate the perceived "unwelcoming" attitude to newbie questions? The down-vote delay was only an idea to consider.

Comment: "*How can we mitigate the perceived "unwelcoming" attitude to newbie questions?*" ["Unwelcomingness" always stems from bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366774#366774). So we have to stop users from asking bad questions. Either by encouraging them to ask good ones up-front, or by preventing bad questions from being asked at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas - That would be ideal. The present efforts toward that goal are obviously inadequate. It is apparent on [C++] that few first-time questioners have read the Asking and MCVE documents, and fewer yet have understood and acted on them.  All too often I suspect that the newbie simply _cannot_ understand, due to bad instruction and unrealistic expectations.

Comment: I would be willing to extend the one-hour moratorium on down-votes and votes-to-close to all users, new and old - again as a stop-gap.

Comment: Question closure exists to prevent people from answering inappropriate questions. By delaying closure, you're effectively removing the ability to do *any kind* of quality control. Closure is the only tool we have to actually stop broad, opinionated, etc questions: by denying them answers. Without that, the site is dead.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree on that point. I do vote to close broad questions, requests for software, opinions, discussion,  and so forth.  I might even both up-vote a question and vote to close it, with an explanation in the comments. So amend my suggestions.

Comment: I'd be on board with *hiding* downvotes/closevotes for a couple hours. Don't think disregarding them completely would work. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88440/introduce-timed-downvotes

Comment: @Pekka - I could get behind that.

Comment: Related: [Replace a negative score or highly downvoted post with a big !](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366916/9209546)

Answer (score -21):

I think if you clearly state that you have a zero-tolerance policy towards rudeness, you are perfectly entitled to enforce it. Just do that, and immediately stop wasting your time with those which are not worth it.

Comment: We already have such a policy since day one, so what's your point here?

Comment: Then you agree that throwing trash in some strangers yard and then complaining that they were unwelcoming because they asked you to not do it again and pointed you to the sign politely saying as much that you saw and ignored is rude and should not be tolerated!

Answer (score -22):

> ... the endless hordes that only care about "gimme teh codez" ...

I may be wrong, but I think this is an unfair portrayal of the majority of the users of the site.

When I type a programming question in Google, very often Stack Overflow comes up first in the search results.

So I can well imagine that the majority of consumers are engineers who already know the theory of programming, but just have a question about a technical detail, and just want the answer quickly, as they don't have the time to stay and chat about the best programming practices in the context.

SO has proven to be (for me at least) a very powerful tool in that respect. It is a great store of the grains of sand around which, like the clams, we can form our engineering pearls.

And so in the end, when we have the time, we will come back to contribute our own grains of sand too.

Edit: ok maybe I am still somewhat new here, I haven't ploughed through the droves of 0-point questions like others may have, but focused on those which had already gotten upvoted. Still I think if someone starts behaving bratty to your answers you are perfectly entitled to just leave, no need to expose yourself to more of it.

Comment: *I may be wrong, but I think this is an unfair portrayal of the majority of the users of the site.* From my experience it is an accurate portrayal. I'd say about 80% of the question I visit I do some combination of: asking the OP clarify/add more information, down vote, vote to close, link to the documentation.  This happens every day I'm on the site.

Comment: Not to say that these mindless coders don't exist, of course. They're just the loudest.

Comment: @NathanOlivier: can you give me examples of these actions? Also, "link to the documentation": is it that bad? If it so hard to find, maybe SO is the best place to help people do so. Then eventually Google should pick up on it and make it first in search results.

Comment: The documentation isn't hard to find.  For C++ if you google it generally cppreference is in the first 5 websites and it is an awesome site.  Here is an example I pulled right from the C++ tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118825/how-can-i-extract-the-first-sub-string-enclosed-in-double-quotes-within-a-string

Comment: C++ is not the only language used here. Also, documentation is often poorly written, and then SO is the perfect place for filling in the blanks.

Comment: @NathanOlivier: why is that in the first 5 search results? Is it maybe because many other sites link to it, such as SO? ;)

Comment: @NathanOlivier: as I commented in my other answer, stop wasting your time down-voting, focus instead on up-voting, should result in the same with much less frustration.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  I've seen plenty of questions/answers that need to go and they get up votes.  Those up votes stop deletion which means our overall quality trends down.

Comment: @NathanOliver: that's where your down-voting should come in play.

Comment: By the way, @Protean, how many answers do you need to post to get your point across?

Comment: Downvoting is a primary quality metric.  Not using it means there's less signal to be able to pick out the truly valuable content.

Comment: @Mr Lister: these are two different points. The comments above about voting got poured over from the other answer.

Comment: C++ is probably one of the languages worst hit by homework dumps, but I'd say 80% of questions are very low quality is pretty accurate. Spend some time on the site and it's not that hard to see.

Answer (score -24):

*What* you all do is great.  You help enforce quality. I don't think this is questioned.  You are all great at this.  Those of us who ask more than answer are very grateful!

*How* you do it, while not inherently wrong, could use some reflection.  I think this is what the blog post was trying to say.  It's how I feel.

Comment: That's the problem with the blog post: Nobody seems to understand what Jay is really saying (I don't). What does SO (the company) plan *in detail*? Jay talks about feelings and priorities, maybe even goals, but he does not say anything about *how* these goals shall be achieved.

Comment: @Scott: "What" we do is a function of "How" we do it. If people are perceiving downvotes and close votes as inherently hostile (and the blog *specifically* calls those out), then that "How" is a direct function of "What".

Answer (score -26):

### "and programming in general, is a meritocracy."

I absolutely believe you when you say you have never, knowingly, discriminated against anyone on SO "based on their age, skin colour, gender, accent, or whatever".

The problem is your belief that (a) programming is actually a meritocracy in some pure and perfect sense and (b) so-called "merit" is a perfect blind evaluator that doesn't just serve as an excuse to engage in what often ends up being behavior with heavy bias correlation outcomes.

People like to complain that the diversity problem in tech is a "pipeline issue" and therefore *not their problem*. Well here **is** the problem: when you have a pipeline fractured by systemic social issues and discrimination, it means that you are going to see people rising to certain levels with less exposure to certain forms of investigation, and therefor certain groupings will receive disparate impacts of behavior that has been systematized to favor certain other, principally in-group behavior.

### You don't have to want to engage in bias behavior to still be effectively causing disparate outcomes along bias lines.

It would be easy to lay the blame on the situation regarding SO on "people like you", the true believers in "the meritocracy" as a blind, non discriminatory arbiter of who rises to the top, as if skill wins everything when skill is largely cut off by a combination of various bias encounters and *unbiased behavior* that largely aligns with particular groups—with excuses lain at the feet of the pillars of merit—along the way.

Ultimately, the real problem with the altar of merit is that it is all about one thing: claiming that certain people got where they are by being somehow intrinsically better, so as to *deserve* it. This belief is then used to spurn everyone who does not happen to master the secret merit handshake.

But this shouldn't be about where certain problems are stemming from. This should be about solutions.

### If Stack Overflow has a problem, it's because Stack Overflow incentivizes certain patterns of behavior, while leaving no space for others

Stack Overflow treats only certain types of learning as valid. If you don't read this and you ask a "bad question", you are punished. By your post, you even claim that people who ask these "bad questions" **deserve** to be punished because they aren't high enough in the "meritocracy" to be worth a response.

In this sense, while I want to re-iterate *you* are not the problem, your post *does* do a good job of showing off some of the hostility and patterns of behavior which underlie the problems: this concept that some **people** don't deserve to be treated like people, with the excuse being how they ask or answer questions, or other ritualistic behavior that they are expected to either already be familiar with or will want to spend the time to learn just to have a "merited" place on this site.

And I think a lot of that comes down to an issue that the site is set up to point all things in that general direction.

Different people learn in different ways. Different questions and answers expose different things, depending on both their wording and whether or not they deal with the same either core topics or nuanced aspects. Programming and Software Engineering are tough, often unforgiving, and sometimes what someone experienced sees as obvious is anything but that to someone who is struggling to learn basic concepts.

We should always be striving for **everyone**, regardless of who they are, to feel like they have friends in this struggle, that they have a place in this struggle if they want it, and they aren't going to be turned away simply because they didn't know the right secret handshake.

### "all in the name of keeping the site's quality up"

Here, I think, is the fundamental issue that I personally believe you have missed: Jay's post is just as easily about the quality of the site as yours.

The question is a matter of perspective, and also defining objectives: what makes Stack Overflow a quality site. As someone who almost never needs to ask questions, because she can pull together an answer faster on her own than trying to explain what she needs to ask when hitting a wall, I know what **qualities** make Stack Overflow valuable *to me*. But I'm not everyone.

Pretty much none of my coworkers participate on Stack Overflow except to mine it for solutions. Particularly the junior developers are afraid of asking anything at all. And that's a loss. Because in the nuance of the questions they would have asked, from the directions they were approaching problems, there would have been something helpful for other junior developers.

### Quality is a matter decided by perspective and related subjectivity

Stack Overflow tries to wrap questions and answers up into certain formulaic points of what will make them a good question or answer "in general". And in many regards, that's fantastic. But it also falls down a hole of ascribing a certain sense of this being a perfectly objective measure of quality, which is how we arrive at posts talking about quality and merit as gatekeepers.

The real issue, to me, is that if you fall outside certain lines in asking or answering a question, there is quickly the impression given that there is little room for you on Stack Overflow, that you are to be knocked down and away as harshly as possible simply for what quickly can feel like it was simply for daring to open your mouth at all. You didn't RTFM hard enough, and you didn't Google it good enough. And in the end the message is that: it's you, so just shut up, give up, and walk away.

And that's a pity. Because rather than slowly teaching people to do better, there's a definite degree of telling everyone who doesn't immediately jump off the deep end with a perfect barely-rippling-the-water dive that they don't belong. So people stop taking the plunge unless they're already at a certain level of their game, and in turn people who aren't at that level are faced with questions and answers that they don't understand how to translate into applying to their own problems.

### What's quality for me is not necessarily quality for my teammates

There are plenty of times where I've sat down with someone with a Stack Overflow page open and worked through how to suss out the information they needed from what was there in terms of what's in front of them and not working correctly right now. Everyone here likes to claim "it's obvious" and therefor "that's a quality question/answer". Well, the problem is that no matter how many Manuals you can tell someone they "didn't fucking read", at the end of the day if it's not obvious to them, it wasn't "quality" **for** them.

### So how can one engineer a Q&A site that doesn't become a horrific mess of hidden needles for you in a ton of everyone else's hay

To me, the problem that Stack Overflow really faces is one of community and behavior, and how certain forms of behavior the site incentivizes through various structuring is resulting in outcomes that fall along bias lines.

This doesn't require bias to be at the forefront of that behavior to still be a fundamental truth at the macro level.

So how do you engineer something better? I think you have to start by creating more space that can self organize around different needs, while providing streamlined access for those arriving there with to different approaches to related information, and then contextualizing it all together.

I think you also have to look at the related gamification, and providing incentives for creating that quality information contextualization, because even if it's not the same type of work, it definitely ends up being work.

And I think you have to provide incentives for simply being kind about opening doors for people rather than shutting them, where simply throwing more answers into the equation might not be the outcome desired, but rather finding ways to gamify other interactions that lead to **making those answers intelligible in the context of a different approach or different nuanced question,** and in turn **still recording that result when it's the desired outcome**

### So you don't want to feel demonized for pursuing what you feel is excellence

That's great. **People shouldn't be demonized for trying,** in the many forms thereof. Personally I don't think the blog post in question, fumbling as it may have been in points, was intent on demonizing anyone.

But I'll admit it was possible to read a lot of things into it. If that's how it impacted and felt to you, then there you go: those are your feelings. I'm sorry that post impacted you like that.

At the same time, I think denying that the specific system of how Q&A is implemented and "judged" on Stack Overflow doesn't create an structure which leads to the outcome showing the demographics seen would be an exact opposite of the objective behavior supposedly enshrined in "meritocracy".

And I think that if you feel demonized due to the outcomes being called out, you need to take a long hard look at yourself, and maybe develop a little empathy for the other people who are on the receiving end of certain behavior and interactions related to the underlying structures of Stack Overflow and the particular form of community/"community" that is grown around them.

There is a lot of behavior encoded in certain aspects of Stack Overflow that are meant to help people find good answers, but when removed from a broader view is easy to internalize as basically being shot down without any actually constructive feedback, but at most, often, just derision.

I think a lot of people come to Stack Overflow, make what to them was a well meaning attempt, and leave feeling demonized. They're looked down upon in so many ways, with their intent read in to, judged, and summarily dismissed as, among other things, "not quality". And often, it's made to feel either personal, as if they aren't good enough, or so dismissively impersonal and disconnected as to be degrading. Somewhere between these two points there has to be room for some empathy and mutual sympathy.

### No one *merits* being derided for trying

### No one merits being derided for caring

You don't like feeling "demonized" "for caring about quality," but in effect you're also making the claim that there's a polarizing line here set by those who care about quality and are on the right side of "merit" and those who don't and thus aren't.

I personally don't see anyone being demonized for caring about quality. What I do see are questions about whether the systematized influences at work are, under a guise of upholding certain forms of quality, creating an environment that drives away people, and in doing so is perhaps impacting some groups of people more so than others.

It's not about "identity" politics. If anything, this identification (which easily comes across as snide, and yet I'm sure it was meant entirely with all the best intentions) with "merit" and "quality" seems to be more on that side to me than anything else. It's about a reality of a disparate outcome being created and a question of what is leading to it and how to help overcome it.

There's a lot of concern over "diversity" as if it's somehow the opposite of "meritocracy", and to me that says a lot about that particular vision of merit. Instead what I see is a concern about making a site better, but for everyone. It's not about putting down the few who are already in and doing well with how it currently works, but making room for more and an overall improvement in the process. This doesn't need to be a zero-sum game, and it's interesting but saddening to me that some people are latching on to it in this way, and immediately placing it in that framing.

A lack of diversity isn't a call for initiatives to "fix diversity" as if that means forcing an outcome with equalized representation, but rather points to something being broken if the goal is to provide a quality experience for everyone rather than just certain people who find they arrived early enough or fit in just right.

As I see it, there is a core answer that needs to be formed, and that's what the actual end goal of the site is. If it's merely meant to be another Q&A site with a "crowd sourced" aspect, then it's there, because it's certainly able to meet such a standard in this incarnation. If it's meant to be more, for instance if there's meant to be a more pedagogical side that's intent on generally lifting people up while still providing an easy road to relevant answers both for searchers **and** "askers"... then I think it needs more work. Which isn't a bad thing.

And it doesn't preclude quality.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts that you've laid out here. There are three different emphases that can be given to the blog post, and the angriest voices are choosing one: that SO is regarding users as explicitly discriminatory. The second interpretation is that established users are subconsciously biased, but they don't mean to be, and they are just reflecting the discriminatory memes of their wider societies. That has been mentioned on Meta several times too. ...

Comment: The third one does not seem to have been mentioned so much, and I wonder if it is worth raising. I wonder if the blog post was aiming for this: some people feel excluded as a result of marginalisation/discrimination they have received elsewhere, and they feel less welcome as a result. Thus, perhaps it is not so much a problem of the implicit biases of readers - who often cannot see the identity of the question author - just that we need to improve our welcome mat?

Comment: Honestly, while I realize this kind of meandered more than I meant it to when I had the idea of writing out the related thoughts, that third point is where I'm *hoping* the aim will be, because I see it as the most crucial, and also the one that is most easily overlooked on the hill of "but I'm not biased and don't even look at the race/gender/etc of the people I reply to/moderate, so HOW DARE YOU!!" There's a lot of room for problematic impact *outcomes* outside of any desire to harm people. And there's a lot of room for very angry defensive posture in response to saying "let's do better".

Comment: Indeed, yes. I wouldn't worry about the length here - I suspect it could be used as a canonical response to link to every time I see a new instance of misreading inclusion strategies.

Comment: I remain unconvinced of the "problematic impact" of SO because 1.) it still fulfills its primary mission, to be a library of useful information for people to find with 0 barriers of entry except for a PC and Internet, anywhere in the world, and 2.) the grumpiness around here is usually very equal opportunity, and my view is the divide of people who can put up with it vs. those who can't is decided by personality type more than by anything else. (Yes I agree the place needs to become more friendly and hostility sucks, been saying that for years. But it's not an easy thing to pull off.)

Comment: I completely agree there's loads and loads of people who leave SO every day feeling awful, and that's not right. But - SO is, as you correctly note, a highly specific, highly competitive system that is optimized for a certain outcome and for a certain type of skill/knowledge - but that's not inherently a bad thing. Every institution of higher education works the same way, and SO is producing improbably good results even a decade in. Honestly, I was sure it wasn't going to last more than five years! So while as said I agree SO needs to improve in terms of tone and athmosphere, I'm wondering...

Comment: ... whether what some people are asking SO to become isn't something that should be implemented in the form of a distinctly different platform instead. A sister site to SO, perhaps, or a partner site if SO, Inc. can't do it. A place that focuses much more on community, empathy, mentorship, helping people where they are at rather than judging them for not yet being there, etc. etc. There's certainly room for improvement on SO but I don't see it turning into a place I would feel ok to send a complete beginner to, ever. Not without taking away the very attributes that made it work so well.

Comment: @Pekka웃 *personally*, from a UX standpoint crossed to an IA one, I think there's room to implement both a better funnel for asking/finding questions/answers, & a better way of handling questions w/ commonalities. I think "duplicate" often loses information as it is now. Would require some definite work, so really up to whether SO has a vision of that nature in mind & wants to put in that effort for those reasons. To me, this is much like accessibility at the core: result = making things better **for everyone** in the process of solving for factors more strongly affecting marginalized groups

Comment: @Pekka웃 in terms of "problematic impact", my concern is more whether there are non obvious elements creating bias outcomes in marginalized groups, possibly at a greater ratio despite no intentional targeting. The demographics are pretty clear: the question is what's driving the disparities. Everyone wants to point elsewhere on diversity issues (pipeline/etc): but rather than worry over "blame"/shifting blame, I prefer approaches that try to fairly elevate all as they can. Being generally more welcoming, to me, is a UX improvement *for everyone* that might also help with diversity issues.

Comment: Yeah, handling duplicates is definitely one of the areas that could use some work. There's several promising (and btw *much* more friendly!) suggestions how to do that on Meta; e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958) from Shog that I fleshed into a feature request. So far there's been no interest from above though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 to me, to fundamentally do it "right" would require re-architecting relationships between questions on the backend, &then how relationships between similar questions present on the front end. Ideally you'd arrive at something like micro-topical question/answer clouds, with particular questions & answers being promoted and even cross promoted above others via the voting & other structures; possibly even allowing for answers to *other questions* to be chosen as correct for a given question. At stake would be the fine line between just a mess vs organized information. Will read your link!

Comment: I would love to see a system that connects similar q's better than the current one. Btw, on the broader topic, here is a FAQ entry/philosophical treatise on why one frequent suggestion to make things more humane - requiring that negative feedback be accompanied by a comment - just isn't feasible  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s

Comment: @Pekka I agree that mandatory comments on downvotes are infeasible, and would cause systematic behavioral pressure issues counter to the point of using them, and honestly might make things worse rather than better in terms of people "feeling welcome", given the comments likely to occur. I think a better way of integrating downvotes in terms of how they display might help soften their emotional impact while preserving their ranking utility. Or deciding on a different structure that fits their imagined/intended role & eliminating them (I only downvote for objectively *wrong* things, for instance

Comment: @taswyn yeah, that's probably the way to go. I suggested [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88440/introduce-timed-downvotes) once...

Comment: "The problem is your belief that (a) programming is actually a meritocracy in some pure and perfect sense and (b) so-called "merit" is a perfect blind evaluator that doesn't just serve as an excuse to engage in what often ends up being behavior with heavy bias correlation outcomes." I don't understand how people can make statements like this in good faith and without self-doubt. Like, you *are* aware that there is such a thing as a compiler, and it processes *your code* without taking your race, gender or anything else into account? What else could "blind" or "perfect" mean here?

Answer (score -29):

From the sole perspective of the OP, it is still an [**unwelcoming behavior**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366818/681929).

That blog post, [that particular blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), I have waited for this for years. Though it is not to the point, but still...

And when it comes, I see the precious people from the community justifying why they were like that.

I completely agree with all of them, the dedication with which they work. Putting up there time in solving someone's issue. They want that that user must have to put a clear, justified question so that they can help the user.

But please go through this small story back in 201*:

> John: Hey Mike! I joined Facebook today, it's a pretty cool site. You
>   can post statuses (Mike doesn't know what posting a status means),
>   upload photos, videos and cool stuff.
>
> Mike: Oh wow! I will try that

Mike went home, signed up (hasn't read any T&C) and started posting.

Mike went to college or a new company, and had a programming issue. He didn't know it was some code issue, or a logical issue, or something. He just started coding. On the Internet or from some friend, he came to know about this holy site 'Stack Overflow'.

> John told him: Stack Overflow is place for enthusiasts, a site where
>   people solve issues, help to learn better.

But from the above sentence he just heard this thing, a site where

> people solve issues

He went to the site and saw the **'Ask a Question'** button. The page asked to go through a tour. But he came from a number of social media, open platforms, to a more formal platform where people dedicate their knowledge to help others.

**But he skipped the tour** (Why? Because he never ever had gone through any before these on any other site. He didn't know that it is also very important to post questions according to the guidelines of Stack Overflow.)

He posted an unclear question, no logs, no RnD (may be), may be a duplicate.

He is expecting an answer, he is waiting for an answer, and suddenly a downvote, and a comment, and some close votes, and more downvotes.

'Please take a tour' one of the comments suggests.

He becomes furious. Why are people judging him? What do they want? Am I unclear (new users will never ask this of themselves).

So now, either he will

1. Go to the tour
2. Throw a rant
3. Or I don't know

But all the parties involved here seem so honest and up to the point. Nobody is wrong. But yeah, from the sole perspective of the OP, it is still an **unwelcoming behavior**.

[See this question as reference: New users never take the tour everytime.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376898/detect-thanks-wow-fantastic-that-worked-comments?cb=1)

[image]

Comment: Most (all?) would agree that we need better ways of easing new users in. I agree that their experience with other media like Facebook and Twitter, may give them expectations that don't apply to Stack Overflow. But the pushback against The Infamous Blog is that it makes an implicit accusation of racism and sexism; I'm sure that without that, the whole thing would have gone over a lot better.

Comment: The "all the other platforms do it in one way, SO should adapt to them" argument is getting old. All platforms are unwelcoming for users at times.

Comment: One don't go to Linkdin and start posting memes. Having a *minimal* understanding of *where* you're posting stuff is a sign of respect for your audience...

Comment: @brasofilo  Believe me, [it is worse than that](https://www.glamour.com/story/people-are-using-linkedin-as-a-dating-site), however I am emphasizing over (1.) The **inability** of the user to know the depth of the policies and regulations of the platform, which they have taken forgranted unconsciously while following other platforms, and  (2.) the rude behavior(from the POV of OP) of SO community. However I am having a diplomatic view for both parties, as none of them seems wrong to me.

Comment: no what you are describing is not *unwelcoming behavior* on the part of the community, that is *entitled self-absorbed narcissistic behavior* on part of the person internalizing a completely neutral comment and clicks on an arrow, that is what you are describing.

Comment: I like the sentiment of this post, even if I don't completely agree.

Comment: Since you are quoting me with the screenshot, notice how the author of the post I commented under "_became furious_" or anything like that. They thanked me and went on their way to read the tour. Isn't that **just great**?

Answer (score -32):

I can't see that you would be demonized. I see that you are ruling the site.

Unfortunately, I've seen

- too many good questions in the vote-to-close (VtC) queue,
- too many good questions closed with some trumped up reason
- and too many falsely closed questions dupe-hammered by "someone" without a single remark,

to fully agree your view.

BTW, the VtC queue on the main site is still at 8,700. I think if you feel yourself demonized, then go there and review 40 questions. Until the VtC queue isn't below 1,000 again, there isn't too much to talk about.

P.s. the "discrimination" based on gender and similars are obviously laughing on a mainly anonymous site. In my opinion, simply the voting customs are somehow too antagonistic. (While the site is too tolerant against people who clearly show that they doesn't even try to post high-quality content.)

Comment: I agree that there are too many questions in the close vote queue that dont deserve to be there, and too many questions that are closed which shouldn't be, but I disagree with your assertion that curators are not being demonized.

Comment: Fortunately, "good" is subjective and we have this queue to give more people the ability to present their opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant Cooperative arguments! :-) You are like an oasis in the desert. I edit the post.

Comment: The only ways it's going to get below 1000 would be if more people use their votes, or if we strongly restrict asking. Or, i guess, if we bump the threshold back to 3.

Comment: @KevinB What about a decrease of the 3k limit? I think a flexible limit would be the best: if the queue is low, only higher rep users could review, while with high queue, also the low-rep ones could.

Comment: I think a lot of the problem comes from close flags bybusers with less than 3k combined with robo-close-reviewers personally, but I have no data to back that up.

Comment: yeah, allowing more users to cast votes *might* help.. but then you have to start thinking about the quality of those votes. I would expect users who have been here longer to be more likely to use their votes anyway.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but now a large part of the close votes is lost due to the queue expirations. A similar negative effect exists in the current system, too.

Comment: @KevinB SEDE could be used to calculate a function, how the "correctness" of a close vote depends on the voter reputation. This could be extrapolated below 3k. This info could be used to calculate, how would the increased count of the bad votes affect the quality. It could be compared with the effect of the expired VtC reviews. It wouldn't be an easy query, but you gave me an idea! :-)

Comment: My point being that if we disabled flagging for closure (or possibly directed those flags to a separate queue where it would be clear to reviewers that they are evaluating the flags of users that are still learning what is on-topic here), the size of the close vote queue would likely be much smaller, wouldn't be filled with as many questions that don't need to be there, and close votes would be less likely to age away.

Comment: @TinyGiant How do you know that most VtC review is initiated by a flag? As I can remember, in the VtC review queue it doesn't happen too often that I would be the first reviewer.

Comment: I see it fairly regularly when I do review. At one point i just skipped all close vote reviews that didnt already have a close vote and it was quite a lot of skipping. As i said I don't have any data on it, but that's what I think.

Answer (score -40):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is written from the perspective of a 'newbie'.

You state

> I have discriminated against those who show no desire to make an effort to think, or read basic "how to ask" pages, or who just don't care.

This sounds very arrogant to me. What makes you think you can distinguish in an instant, whether someone posted crap on purpose not willing to read any advice on asking? Maybe these people don't know it better. Many people can't read/speak/write English fluently. Those people tend to read only text that seems important for them. Unintentionally. They have a question and want an answer for that as fast and as profound as possible. This is why they're on Stack Exchange after all. If they wanted a dumb answer or they wanted to wait for few weeks for an answer, they would visit any forum or [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) or such.

Let's take your 'question': *When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?* (Caution: personal statements without confirming arguments ahead.)

The question title alone makes me think, you see yourself as a kind of elitist who stands alone (or with a few others) against a neverending flood of newbies who actively and repeatedly try to decrease the overall quality of Stack Overflow by asking dumb questions on purpose.

Tell you what: that's not the case. It's not **you** against **them**. At least it shouldn't be from your point of view.

What may seem like a dumb question to you (as an expert on your field) may be the exact the question another (or 100 other) newbie(s) has/have too. With no clue how to solve the issue. For whatever reasons. So they ask, maybe making mistakes while doing so. No reason to assume they are evil and still no reason to be hostile.

Also Jay wrote:

> But our active users regularly express their frustration that we haven’t done more to make outsiders feel more welcome. The real problem isn’t the community — it’s us [...]

On many occasions newbies get told that **not they personally get downvoted, but rather their questions and answers** and they should keep this in mind when feeling offended. This applies here, too. Jay doesn't demonize the community as a whole, every single responsible user in it or even you in personal, but some users who are not able to express themselves in certain situations without seeming hostile to the recipients of their message. You should not take it personal.

---

From a newbie's perspective, here come two examples:

After using Stack Exchange as a trustable source of answers to any kinds of questions for years, I finally asked a question. In the comments of the question I was told, what I want to achieve is not possible. Then the question was marked as a duplicate of another question, which I strongly disagreed with. I made my point clear and requested for removing the duplicate 'stigma' and reopening the question. I got the following rude comment (I don't know the exact wording anymore):

> So that someone else can tell you this is not possible? Definitely no.

Crushing. I felt treated unfairly. Also this comment led me to believe, the commenter indeed was aware that the question is not a duplicate, but refused to reopen the question because he/she didn't felt to. It would've been more valuable to me (as in learning to ask 'better' questions) and to others having the same question, if an actual answer would have been posted. Even if it stated, what I try to achieve is not possible (+ reasons). I think behaviour like this is what Jay meant in his blog post. Unfortunately this question seems to be deleted by now and I don't even know the question title anymore.

Then, a few weeks later, I asked a question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) about enterprise architect & code generation just to receive a bunch of downvotes with none of the downvoters seeming to care leaving a comment on why they downvoted. After writing a comment asking for reasons, I finally received a friendly comment stating that *"This is off-topic for Software Engineering, questions about help getting specific code working should be posted on Stack Overflow."*

I didn't know that. Not because I'm lazy and didn't read the tour or the asking advice, but because it is stated nowhere on the site when compiling a question. Not even on the landing page of a Stack Exchange site there is an explanation of what the scope of this specific page is - in detail. *

This is not newbie-friendly. This discourages from asking more questions as a beginner. I don't say that every user (or even a big portion) trying to keep up the quality of the site is an evil monster (and as stated above, Jay didn't either), but there are times when those 'power users' may behave in a hostile (read non-friendly) way. Not necessarily on purpose. But the reason for the hostility doesn't matter for the newbies. It is not important what the (hidden) intention of the sender was (e.g. writing the same advice for the 10000th time). It is important how the information is perceived by the recipient.

To use an analogy of "If you don't have anything nice to say, just don't say anything": If you can't express what you want to say in a friendly manner, leave it to the next one.

IMHO this is what Jay's blog post was about.

---

*: I think I've seen that it's possible to move questions between sites to a Stack Exchange site that it fits in. This would have been a much better approach to me than just downvoting the question without leaving any comment on the reasons.

---

**TLDR:** The blog post does not seem demonizing to me. Don't take it personally. Two examples of what can go wrong when dealing with newbies.

---

Three things I have to add:

1. The whole discussion may be heavily biased due to the nature of humans. We like to criticize fast and often if something doesn't meet our expectation (like I did here). Rarely we praise something that works as expected. So Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general receive more criticism by newbies than praisings.
2. I don't know why Jay mixes up newbies to the site with minorities implying that every user already active on the page must be a middle-aged white Caucasian man and every newbie must be a member of any minority. IMHO this is a statement leading to many acts of justification and self-defense.
3. Please do not see my answer as an universal condemnation of Stack Exchange and its very experienced and valuable users. Stack Exchange is an awesome platform. My answer is also not meant as a rant on you in personal.

Thank you all for contributing to this platform, making the Internet more a source of valuable information bit by bit, day by day. Love you all <3

Comment: @Tim: I read enough to know where you were going with your post. And by the end, I saw nothing to make me change my vote.

Comment: "Many people can't read/speak/write English fluently" This probably isn't the place for them. This is an English language Q&A site. If a person can't understand the answers given, it likely won't help enough that they can apply the answer given to their specific situation.

Comment: @Tim 1 minute is long enough to read your __tl;dr__.

Comment: "Caucasian" may not be understood outside of a US context.

Comment: "So that someone else can tell you this is not possible? Definitely no." is a prime example of really unnecessary snark.

Comment: FYI https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367092/changing-new-users-expectations-of-this-site-before-they-ask-their-question

Comment: @D_N - that is their internalized *paraphrasing* of what it actually said, they say this as much *"I don't know the exact wording anymore"*, so there is no way to judge what the actual comment might have been or where it  falls on the *snark* meter. So their characterization of the interaction is just that, **their characterization**, not fact and should not be used as the truth in anyway.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome sure thing

Comment: I see your point but I definitely agree with OP's arguments. It's not fair to demonize old contributors to make SO more beginner-friendly.

Comment: "What makes you think you can distinguish in an instant, whether someone posted crap on purpose not willing to read any advice on asking?" Typically, because they have done something that they would know not to do had they read the advice, and persist in doing that thing after being pointed at the advice repeatedly. Or because they have obviously copied and pasted a homework assignment, with no attempt to even ask a question (only posting the problem statement).

Comment: "They have a question and want an answer for that as fast and as profound as possible." It is [*explicitly not*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) part of Stack Overflow's purpose to answer questions *promptly*.