# When do we stop blaming the community?

Tags: discussion, new-users, welcoming

After a contribution hiatus from SO for reasons of time, meta drama, and general lack of quality, I have "come back" during my downtime. And basically, nothing has changed. All these welcoming posts, all these promises, all the SE turnover hasn't changed anything.

Since I've been back, I think I've upvoted 1 or 2 questions simply because the author wrote them well, not for content reasons. Downvotes and close votes galore. The new questions page is flooded with single sentence questions, homework (I literally reported a post to a university in Sweden because it left the class's professor on it saying "do this for me ASAP"), and worst of all:

I'm the unwelcoming one. Saying please, respectfully disagreeing, downvoting, closing, following the posting rules, etc.

It makes me want to leave SO for good. When are we going to stop caring about the new user statistics when a fraction of new users actually read the FAQs, and half of them post a good question? When did I become the bad guy over and over again for taking time out of my day to help people, only to get sucked into a vacuum of quality control that is spiraling because people are too worried new users will be upset over a downvote or being told they need to read the site rules?

> Visited 2003 days

This is a LOT of time invested in SO, and being told I'm the problem is a major slap in my face (indirectly being told, via blog posts, comments, etc, we all know what I mean here).

This is very ranty but at this point... what the hell am I doing here when the community puts the majority of the blame on me?

Comment: Good phrasing for the questions a lot of us still have :/. Thx for managing to explain this succinctly, yet powerfully

Comment: Asking and Answering is a privilege, and *most* of us that have posted enough know that. New users, on the other hand, see SO as a "free answer service" and it's our "duty" to answer their (homework) questions. Some users, however, that do answer questions don't help the volume of low quality (homework) questions by [answering]https://stackoverflow.com/q/60411720/2029983) them. In my view, the community of answerers need to be on board and stop answering awful questions (before they are closed). Without the answering community being "on board" with not answering, the bad questions won't stop.

Comment: [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/839601)

Comment: @gnat it's depressing that a year later I feel the exact same as that user.

Comment: I'm tempted to close-vote this as a dupe, but since that'd mean I'd single-handedly dupe-hammer it, I won't.

Comment: I would close it myself as a dupe, but I think then it would just brush my feelings aside. If something isn't fixed, bring it up again, and again, until something proper is done about it. However, if the community closes it as a dupe, that is ok with me.

Comment: Who is actually blaming you? The new users you just downvoted? Of course they will, no matter if your intentions are good, anonymous criticism is hard to take for some people. Afaik the company hasn't made any recent moves to criticize curators, and from recent moves I think the realization that we aren't the problem is very slowly sinking in, but that might be wishful thinking

Comment: @ErikA it's something the community has to stop doing to itself as well, not just SE. An example is an answer I disagreed with a couple days ago, and the user said to the question OP don't worry SO isn't welcoming. Heck, there is a comment on a meta post from 16 hours ago that starts with "SO isn't very welcoming" (it wasn't even OP that said this) on a meta question about a closed question that was closed because it was looking for a 3rd party source. It's not just SE that did it to us. We did it to us as well.

Comment: @Sterling to be fair, the author of that meta comment has been inherently negative about SO and its community for years. From that specific user, it's more 'business as usual' than anything else

Comment: That sounds like the traditional _Curator_ - _Rep-Who-must-not-be named_ - _Help vampire_ dynamic. The curator always catches the flack, it's been described often, but the only real thing we can do is ignore it. Unless you got a good proposal on how to combat it, though.

Comment: @ErikA if that's the only real thing we can do, something has to be done. You can only ignore something for so long (in my case, about 7 years). It would really be nice to know that some higher power supports what we do, and how we do it. I don't think I've seen SE do much but condone, instead of praise in these aspects (but I may be ignorant, as I can't read *all* of meta or the blog posts or podcasts)

Comment: FWIW I see it pretty much the way ErikA commented: In recent months SEI (the company) has backed off pointing to curators as "culprits". Unfortunately what was voiced in public-facing media (tweets, blogs, etc) early last year has made its way into the jargon complainers use: "toxic", "unwelcominng", etc. They probably hope/expect that pounding on these terms will change policy. Indications I've been seeing recently say otherwise. I've been participated in a number of on-line interviews about UI changes and they've all been pro-quality / pro-curation...

Comment: ...So flag those comments on Main for removal and VTC on Meta when you run into that kind of thing and watch how it gets removed. And people suspended.

Comment: @CindyMeister we all know the content can be removed and it is removed. Sexist comments are removed, so why is the community called sexist? The stigma remains.

Comment: @CindyMeister: so I wasn't imagining a strong reek of self-confirmation and leading questions in the recent surveys? (Takes off tin foil hat.)

Comment: Some of us still remember why SO was created in the first place.  It was because all the alternatives were absolute junk. Filled with unanswerable, unintelligible garbage questions, lots of "I have that problem too", lots of "Never mind I solved it" (but not telling you how).  SO is now full of the exact same junk questions.  Or in other words "Four legs good, two legs better".

Comment: I could not have said it any better, @Cindy. Can you say it in an answer, please? I totally agree that this vernacular of “welcoming” has been picked up by everybody whose question got closed without getting an answer. Recently, I’m even seeing known trolls using this sort of language in complaints that their trolling content got removed. It’s beginning to become very irritating. On the other hand, the quality of content on SO has not measurably declined as of late, and there are no restrictions on the community or moderators’ ability to clean it up as we always have. Let’s keep doing it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Not sure what I should reply to that... How do you fight preconceptions ("stigma") with no basis in reality (my opinion - I've *never* encountered what *I* consider sexism on SO Main)? Do you feel the situation is hopeless and you can't deal with it any longer? My reaction is to stand up proud and say, "No, that's not the case. My colleagues are decent human beings or I wouldn't be here. *Show me* the proof." And they'd better not come with that tired "the assumption is that everyone is male"!

Comment: @usr2564301 The surveys... Yeah, the people who write those have an agenda. But so have I when I answer <evil-g> I wonder how many of those are to make people think one cares about personal orientations vs. How much weight that will actually be given...

Comment: This question could be improved by adding details about exactly who is calling you unwelcoming. Aside from that, what you do expect, exactly, to change immediately upon your return? Change is a process, not an event.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a comment ErikA writes

> Afaik the company hasn't made any recent moves to criticize curators,
>   and from recent moves I think the realization that we aren't the
>   problem is very slowly sinking in, but that might be wishful thinking

I see it pretty much the same way: In recent months SEI (the company) has backed off pointing to curators as "culprits".

Indications I've been seeing recently say those currently running the show no longer believe that we who enforce site quality are "bad guys". I've participated in a number of on-line interviews about UI changes over the past months and the topics have all been pro-quality / pro-curation.

Unfortunately what was voiced in public-facing media (tweets, blogs, etc) early last year has made its way into the jargon complainers use: "toxic", "unwelcominng", etc. And as we know, what's on the Internet remains public "for eternity" - it can't be recalled...

Complainers who spout such accusations at the drop of a hat probably hope/expect that pounding on these terms will change site policy.

And let's not forget the trolls who will pick up on something like SE saying the site is unwelcoming and use it just to create chaos and hurt feelings! Or those who've made it their passion to kill off the site by any means at their disposal.

...So flag those kinds of comments on Main for removal and vote-to-close on Meta when you run into that kind of thing - and watch how it gets removed. And people suspended.

Just like there needed to be a crackdown on "snarkiness", now it's necessary to stop the trolling and entitlement of complainers. It seems the pendulum is starting to swing in the direction that will support the community to stop attacks undermining the site's integrity. Let's maintain that momentum until a good balance is attained.

Comment: Gonna be honest here - I'm not even paying attention to how the company views us right now.  Frankly, it's not about how they *view* us; it's about how they *shield* us.  Sure, they're not joining in the chorus of us being seen as the "bad guys".  But I don't see them going out of their way to shield us from the criticism, either. They're taking a neutral stance, which may be OK, but I personally want something more.

Comment: From [personal experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336516/223370) ([screenshot](https://www.planetcobalt.net/_img/q336516.png)) I can assure you that hostile behavior of SEI towards curators continued at least until December 2019. That might not have continued into 2020 (maybe they start feeling the impact of people like us not putting in the (free) work anymore), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Makoto With all the discussion around the Roadmap concerning the topic of engaging more people, I have to wonder that no one has questioned whether this is because the exodus of experienced community members is being noticed. IOW they're hurting (even without a strike)? If yes, your point (which comes down to "trust") would be one worth making in that discussion. That said...

Comment: ...The fact that we're now advised to DV and VTC *without leaving comments* - despite the regular demands and complaints that DV-ters should be forced to do so - is an acknowledgement that people involved with site curation do need "shielding". You comment at your own risk, so to speak, but aren't even *expected or requested* to do so. DV, VTC and move on - don't engage, don't try to lead people to a good question. *That*, for me, says a lot. With all the push to raise the number of people, that's something notable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I may be missing something, here, but the screenshot (I can't view deleted messages on SE Meta - to little rep) dates from October, not December. And the topic has nothing to do with curator duties, per se, or "blaming the community" (topic of the Q)? It appears to be about your personal coming to terms (or not) with the CoC and pronouns?

Comment: The question is from October, the ban happened in November, and the deletion in December. You're right that it's not about curator duties per se, but I believe it's related insofar that it demonstrates the attitude towards people who helped curating the site: removing dissenting opinions without explanation, stonewalling when being asked for an explanation, then banning the user when the opinion is voiced again. And with a ridiculous excuse no less. Saying "how anyone can look at <long list of made-up pronouns> and not see the lunacy in it is beyond me" is rude? Give me a break!

Comment: @CindyMeister *"The fact that we're now advised to DV and VTC without leaving comments"* eh, the annoying popup suggesting i leave a comment every time i downvote is still there.

Comment: @KevinB I never see it - I don't hover over the buttons, I just click :-)

Comment: No, not that one. When you have less than 2k rep, every downvote is met with a pop up notification at the top

Comment: @KevinB Ah. It's been years since I've passed that rep threshhold. In the tags I work in, it's *hard* to earn rep; took me four or five years to pass 20k. My memory isn't so good anymore that I'd remember that :-) But, on the assumption that *most* people who engage actively in curation would have passed 2k, in that case the message doesn't target "curators"?

Comment: It’s clearly targeting users who are newer to stack, IMO instilling the idea that downvotes should be accompanied by comments.

Answer (score 31):

I've been tempted to let this reset after I crossed the 3K threshold.

[image]

The main issue is that everyone seems to have pigeonholed "community" to be exactly *one* group - users of Stack Overflow.

In reality, there's at least three separate communities:

- The group of users who find answers on Stack Overflow through Google searches and have no real intention of creating accounts.  By far, the largest group of people out there; not a lot of people *have* to ask questions or *have* to answer questions or any of that nonsense to get value out of the site.
- The group of users who ask questions on Stack Overflow, or answer questions on Stack Overflow.  These are the ones who are probably going to be the most vocal about just how toxic we are when their off-topic question gets closed.
- The janitors of Stack Overflow, who actually take the time to close questions, upvote and downvote content, and keep the place nice and neat.

To to answer your question, blame will always exist because there are some behaviors that people just don't like coming from janitors.  You only have two options - tune them out or run away.  In the end, the only real arbiter of whether or not we have an actual *problem* is if leadership fails to truly take Meta's position into account when deciding that blame needs to be attributed.

Comment: It sort of falls into the real life scenario where a janitorial position is often criticized by those that don't realize society would literally crumble without them.

Comment: But I have to add that there is a significant overlap/intersection of your second and third groups - as there should be.

Comment: @SterlingArcher [A policeman's lot is not a happy one](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=gaBWXpPEO8GdkgWwyZbADA&q=a+policeman%27s+lot&oq=a+policema&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1907.4714..7472...0.0..0.78.624.10......0....1..g)

Comment: My numbers: `Visited 2534 days, 3 consecutive` - I don't bother with keeping up the consecutive count, you gotta have some days away from the madness.

Comment: I finally did it on meta ... `Visited 1887 days, 1 consecutive`.

Answer (score 11):

For the most part, the issue of low quality questions and homework posts have been present for many years.

As far as being the unwelcoming one, I disagree.

> Saying please, respectfully disagreeing, downvoting, closing, following the posting rules, etc.

These should not be called "unwelcoming", and you shouldn't have to shoulder the burden of being accused for simply providing full range to the signal.

Recently, it should be noted that the tone has been much more level, although, that could just be the result of a lull in messaging than the result of a change in messaging.

The fundamental design of the site is to have high quality content bubble to the top, and that cannot happen with only positive signal. Downvotes were deemed a critical part of of communicating the quality rating of a post.

> "In building Stack Overflow, we realized the intrinsic informational value of full range post scores. Downvotes give you the critically important ability to distinguish between the good, the bad, and the ugly. Without downvotes, how can you possibly tell the difference between a post that is harmless but uninteresting, and one that is actually wrong or harmful? Sure, it stings a bit to get downvoted. I’ve been downvoted myself on Stack Overflow. And each time, it makes me pause. But that’s good! That’s necessary! You have to believe there are potential consequences for every post you make — both good and bad. This is how things work on real playgrounds; why would we expect our web playgrounds to be any different?" -[Jeff Atwood (Stack Overflow Co-Founder)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/)

In addition, the system was acknowledged overall as containing some level of anxiety to use.

> "I've heard people describe the process of asking a question on Stack Overflow as anxiety inducing. To me, posting on Stack Overflow is supposed to involve a healthy kind of minor "let me be sure to show off my best work" anxiety:
>
> - the anxiety of giving a presentation to your fellow peers
> - the anxiety of doing well on a test
> - the anxiety of showing up to a new job with talented coworkers you admire
> - the anxiety of attending your first day at school with other students at your level
>
> I imagine systems where there is zero anxiety involved and I can only think of jobs where I had long since stopped caring about the work and thus had no anxiety about whether I even showed for work on any given day. How can that be good? Let's just say I'm not a fan of zero-anxiety systems."
>   -[Jeff Atwood (Stack Overflow Co-Founder)](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)

If you see someone demeaning others for actioning posts, then that should be flagged, and appropriate action can occur. Frustration is common though, in situations where there is anxiety, so it is important to consider that there is another person on the other side of the content when it comes to actioning it.

It has also become very cliche for a certain group of users to blame the site, and the community, for their lack of research or ability. This group is actively harmful. While some of it can be attributed to cruft from recent events, there is a very large external dynamic that plays into this as well which I will avoid pointing fingers at.

Going forward, as overall messaging improves, this should tame down a little; it is impossible to remove altogether though, as false positives are detrimental to those who are well-intentioned. In the long term, as the external contributing factors even out, the field overall should become less tumultuous... the downside is we will probably all be retired by then.