# Are users being disincentivized to care about posting good questions?

Tags: discussion

Some seem to think this is a rant about downvotes. It is not. In fact, I got positive points overall on the question... in question. The title describes the central point of the discussion, and it's not primarily about downvotes but about the entire experience... including people trying to close your question while others with the information you need are actively saying the question is fine and are in the process of answering the question. Yes, I get that when argue it brings more downvotes... and I don't care. And this actually goes to my point: this environment encourages people to not care.

For me, the answer is yes. After my experience yesterday and over various other questions in the past, I have come to the conclusion that it is no longer worth trying to form a good question (it hasn't always been this way).

On the one hand I get multiple downvotes and votes to close within seconds of posting with no indication as to why. On the other hand I still get the information I need, even if the question is closed because someone will come along and help in the comments.

So if I ultimately get what I need, but I get punished even though I actually did try to follow the guidelines, then what incentive is there for trying to follow the guidelines?

Moderators may think they don't have time to tell all the people they need to downvote why they got downvoted. But you might just be creating more work for yourselves as people like me will care less and less about even trying to worry about whether a question is appropriate.

And lest you think I'm being unreasonable, understand that my most recent question was closed, then reopened by the people who were actually helping, then closed again. And the reason it was closed was literally *already* addressed by someone who helpfully edited my post to make it more clear. Before that happened, someone also marked the question as a possible duplicate even though I had *already* made it clear to others why the duplicate did not answer the question. And I'm not 100% certain, but I think I had even marked an answer before it got closed the second time.

I don't care whether you agree with me or whether you think I'm the one being unreasonable here. Just ask whether I have any incentive to care about the quality of questions I ask in the future, and what does that mean for moderators workloads? Most people aren't like me... they won't argue or complain; they'll just silently stop caring about what the guidelines say if they know they'll get harassed half the time even when they do try to write a good question.

Comment: You may have a point. Hopefully the upcoming [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info) will help (is it really only for new users???)

Comment: i mean.. at the end of the day, if your posts aren't a positive contribution to the network, you'll eventually lose your ability to contribute in that way... regardless of whether or not you or anyone else cares about whether or not you post good questions. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ranting about downvotes in a question body on the mainsite is a surefire way to rack up more.

Comment: @KevinB Circular logic. You are assuming the moderators were right and I did not post positive content. You are also missing the point. Do you want to incentivize people to post good questions, or do you want an environment that often discourages them from doing so?

Comment: I want to incentivize people posting *useful* questions. casting downvotes on things that aren't that are a way of preventing not useful from taking up the time of people actually willing to post great answers.

Comment: By "moderators", I'd assume *any* users moderating someone's posts, not the community/elected moderators with the diamond on their username?

Comment: @Warcupine That's irrelevant, and I'm happy to take the extra fire if a few people can read this post for what it's meant to be... which is that an environment is often created that produces the opposite effect of what you're intending to do... which is to encourage better content. Right? I understand if you can only see this is a rant though; others like Peter Mortensen seem to get the point.

Comment: @AndrewT I suppose so? I don't know the rating system and privileges and all that well enough to say but that's probably true.

Comment: I'm referring to your [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73684412/1) on the mainsite, not this question.

Comment: @Warcupine Ah, I see. What do you suppose my purpose is? Do you suppose I'm trying to get more points; or do you suppose I'm trying to get someone to engage with me and tell me what they think is the matter with my question so I can get it answered?

Comment: Regardless of your intent, hostile language in edits and comments can attract more downvotes. It's quite counter-productive.

Comment: Your point is irrelevant, it isn't the place for it and will be removed every time and likely to generate a more negative response. Why would anyone see that all-caps exclamation point riddled edit and think gee this person will surely respond positively to my feedback.

Comment: @KevinB You're assuming my post isn't useful. That's subjective, and there are others in my post who clearly thought (and said so) that my question was perfectly fine. Are you even considering what I'm saying, or does it just annoy you when someone writes about getting downvotes so you automatically take a stance against them? I don't feel you're understanding the point of this post and can't get past that.

Comment: @BVernon i haven't expressed an opinion either way on your post. You asked a question and i gave an honest answer. It's certainly possible that i disagree with the votes on your post,

Comment: @KevinB Okay, perhaps I'm misreading your point about wanting to incentivize useful answers. Then consider that there is more to it than simply casting positive/negative votes. What about the other issues I cited such as closing a question for a reason that was already fixed, and marking it a duplicate of something that was already said not to be so? Are we going to ignore this part of the experience?

Comment: *"closing a question for a reason that was already fixed"* is often a side effect of our closure system being too slow or too overloaded. It unfortunately happens occationally and can be fixed through the reopen queue. The duplicate side though... it's relatively common for an OP to claim something isn't a duplicate, without providing any evidence to confirm that it isn't a duplicate. In these cases, it more often than not remains closed as a duplicate... and when evidence is provided, it's often still a duplicate, just there was some *other* issue that caused the code on the dupe to not work.

Comment: 2/ The op claiming it isn't a duplicate or that the dupe doesn't work only works when enough information is provided so that future visitors can see *why* it isn't a duplicate. We aren't going to just take the word of the person who hasn't figured out how to debug/solve their problem yet.

Comment: Please do not start your questions with "Edit:"

Comment: Maybe users should be _even_ more disincentivized towards making a fuss whenever they receive a downvote or a close vote. Those commonly get toxic really fast.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who)

Comment: @gnat That suggestion comes often, but I'd say we should refrain from using that question as a duplicate target for _users_ demonizing the quality-concerned users. That question was originally directed towards the _company_ and mentions past context which may be confusing for users such as this OP to read.

Comment: disincentivized (good Scrabble word...) no. If people are properly incentivised to do so... that I would gladly argue and bicker about. It could be made a little more clear just how important it is in this day and age that the first version of a question requires sunglasses before it is safe to read it.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger these are two sides of the same coin if you think of it - both aiming at site curators. When company did their [meta-tag:welcoming] stuff, they didn't say "Joel ordered this" - instead they referred to "ordinary users" at twitter or reddit complaining about cruelty. Complaining users on their side play the same smokescreen game. They know full well that votes down and close come from their peers not from the company...

Comment: ...but they pretent to critisize the company because this makes them look more respectable. Quite likely they even silently hope that naming the company will somehow trigger management to invent next summer of love hunting the snark

Answer (score 23):

Generally no. Users are not penalized or discouraged from asking good questions. On the contrary, well-asked questions received upvotes which incentivises asking more good questions.

Questions that deserve to be closed shouldn't be answered nor should they receive solutions via comments. There are some exceptions to this though, e.g. pointing out a typo and closing a question as off-topic. However, one user may think a question deserves an answer and another may think that it cannot be reliably answered in its current state. Regardless of differing opinions, we don't care if the question's author receives an answer they were looking for, we only care if that question can receive answers that will be helpful to future researchers. Questions that received answers and still got closed may be deleted by the community too.

---

In your case, you have posted a rant about downvotes and insulted your audience. That's not a good question. That's the opposite of a good question. You literally shot yourself in the leg by your whining which should not be part of the content in the first place. Someone decided to help you by removing the rant, but you insisted on keeping it, so the question got closed and locked. It later got reopened and reclosed again but with a different reason... I am not sure I agree it should be closed with that reason but I also don't think it's a very useful question.

Comment: I assume it would change something. The question might have gotten closed too, but with less downvotes. At the end of the day, it just isn't that useful considering that we already have similar questions available with better answers.

Comment: Is this post really about downvotes? You all seem to be coming back to this topic as if it's the central part of the conversation when it's not. If you think it is, then please read my post again. I get it, you guys are all like "oh  here we go, another rant by someone offended by downvotes". No... actually read my post please.

Comment: @BVernon I amended the answer. Hopefully now it addresses the topic more clearly

Comment: @BVernon If you want to have a constructive conversation, stop knee-jerking hostile terms like "gestapo."

Comment: @Dharman You have generally explained the why behind the closing. And you point out that good questions are encouraged. So I have to say this also misses the mark, but it could just be that you feel my concern is of no importance. First let me draw attention to my entire experience (reread post if you need to) and not just the down/close votes because if you ignore that then you really aren't addressing the issue. My problem is actually less with the downvotes and more with the rest of the experience. Then let me exaggerate to get the point across in the next comment...

Comment: Suppose thousands of people had similar experiences (whether deserved or not) and as a result they continued to keep coming to the site and posting questions because ultimately they were getting answers, but they stopped caring about posting good questions and the site was filled with a lot of poor content that had to be improved upon. And specifically, the amount of poor content this produced was much greater than the amount of poor content that was dealt with in such a way that it caused this problem. Is that of little or no concern?

Comment: Users posting bad content is a huge concern for the site. That's why we have automatic account bans. The more downvoted and closed questions an account has, the quicker it will get banned. This is also why we encourage downvoting and closing as much as possible. If a user has a history of posting bad questions, others can flag their account and mods can deal with such a user. But that's also the reason why I said that we don't want to answer questions that should be closed. At best it's a waste of time and at worst it is lowering overall quality of posts on the site.

Comment: "Suppose thousands of people had similar experiences (whether deserved or not) and as a result they continued to keep coming to the site" - This already happens.  Stack Overflow receives thousands of questions daily, majority of those users, return and ask additional questions that are well received by the community and in general helpful to other users.