# Evaluating answer by Accepted and Downvote

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I had change to help a new-comer to stack overflow in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906000/php-rename-duplicates-result-from-an-array-without-remove-entire-keys) question.

Some users mark this question as duplicate but looking into the question and the recommended as duplicate show me this is actually different one.

My answer seems to help the OP but some user downvoted it. The only reason someone wrote was: "this is so inefficient .. plus there are tones of dupes. Just flag and close".

I believe this is actually efficient (`O(n)` - but lets not discuss it) and this is not duplicate - or at least no one flag it with good duplicate so the OP can use it (and this defiantly not qualified for "The answer is not useful").

Having 2 downvote make me feel I want to erase this post despite the fact if is good answer and helped the OP (I know this ok to downvote as you want as in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions/255466)).

My question: should we consider mechanism to avoid this kind of situation? should I flag it for moderator? should accepted answer with negative score need to have special case?

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/1233251

Comment: I saw that - the answer there said it is not appropriate - should we do something about it? (in particular in case when accepted?)

Comment: @dWinder: You'll also see that the answers say that there's nothing to be done for it.

Comment: Nope, everyone is free to use their votes as they see fit. Note that a question being "legitimate" doesn't bring much weight here. Being legitimate is not a reason to upvote nor a reason not to warrant a downvote. By the looks of it, the question was considered a fairly common duplicate.

Comment: You admit yourself people can vote however they please. How does 'avoid this kind of situation' works, when it's how some users want to vote?

Comment: @dWinder could you please clarify what you tried to ask/suggest? Title and question seem to imply that you want some mechanism to avoid "Downvote answer for legitimate question"... (I bet you can get a lot of support for such FR as users generally only see value when others low quality answers are downvoted… but not their own... But I think you mean something else in the question)

Comment: I hope now it is better - I tried to express my frustration for this downvote as all I wanted to help the OP - and even the example for duplicate given in one of the post here is not actually a duplicated - which mean pepole are rush to press the duplicate. Is the OP could solve his issue by the dup - maybe - but he clearly not in the level to do so - so I tried help him.
As the reaction I get here - I afraid a again post something I shouldn't...

Comment: One thing to remember: we're here to create a repository of knowledge.  The user being unable to understand the answer isn't a valid reason not to close a question as a duplicate.  We're here to help more than the asker.  We expect askers to be able to put in the effort to properly ask a question, and, if closed, to fix their question to resolve the close reason.  For duplicates, that requires them to read it, *understand* it, and then edit their question to show why it's not.  "I can't understand it" isn't a valid reason.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> should we consider mechanism to avoid this kind of situation?

No. You received feedback on your post, which is more than many other posts that get downvotes receive. You may not agree with it, but there is not a special situation here. If you feel your answer can be improved, do so. Explain why you believe it's efficient and address the comments you've been given.

> should I flag it for moderator?

No. Moderators don't have any say over how a user votes, as long as it doesn't become a "voting fraud" problem (this doesn't sound close that at all). Again, you've been provided feedback. Utilize that. Moderators can't judge a post based on technical accuracy. We aren't all experienced in all the topics Stack Overflow covers.

> should accepted answer with negative score need to have special case?

Again, no. There are accepted answers with negative scores all over the site. Some due to a similar situation you are describing here. Others where an answer contains incorrect data but was still accepted by the original user. Even others due to being incorrect much later in the answer's life cycle. It was accurate at the time of the post, but over the years it no longer works that way.

Answer (score 23):

There's two things at play here

## You admit it's a duplicate but you answered anyways

You made this comment under your answer (emphasis mine)

> this is pretty easy issue and **there is already several questions about it**. You can still mark this question as accepted (the grey "v" mark at the left of the answer) so other know it helped you

You have enough reputation to vote to close this as a duplicate and yet chose not to and announced that fact. Right or wrong, there are voters who don't like that (I did not downvote, FYI). In the future, point people to existing answers, as they have likely covered the subject in better detail.

## Your answer was poor

You used a clunky loop when [better alternatives exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10408526/2370483). At least one comment noted that. That's certainly a reason to downvote