# Does Stack Overflow track the effect of moderator policing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just got done reading this:

[What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

And I thought.  Wow - right on!  For example in the past this type of question would have been OK:

[What is the difference between :focus and :active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active)

But this is no longer acceptable.  You have to show work.  In the above case, that would have diluted the question, thus wasting the time of all the readers who find the question and answer useful.  That is not a concern for the moderators who are now cracking down on these types of questions.

For example here is [a question I recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-dropdown-thats-clickable) that the moderators have taken a sledge hammer too:

[image]

Long term I think this "Users who don't show work are a bunch of lazy losers" attitude and "Why does everything have to exist on Stack Overflow?" judgement call by moderators is going to be detrimental to Stack Overflow's business model. Everything does not have to exist on SO but why when a person is willing to ask and others are happy to answer -  almost always within a five minute time frame - does a moderator get to crack down on the question?.

So I'm requesting that Stack Overflow create a replay feature.  We have it in soccer nets, hockey nets, the NFL has the ability to review plays.  Here's how it should work.

> "This post has been closed by BillTheLizard for this reason". If you feel this is unfair please follow these steps to build a case for it. That includes reviewing all the closings and other activity by BillTheLizard to see how good a referee BillTheLizard is. This can then be submitted to metareviews.stackoverflow.com. And you can let a user have like 3 chances to do this. Same protocol we use in the NHL or NFL or any other sport where a coach can ask for a play review

Some are saying this will make no difference from a purely logical point of view.  It will.  And the reason is simple.  Stack Overflow is trying something that addresses the needs of all of us, and that's enough.  For more info read up on the Hawthorne studies:

[Hawthorne Studies](https://www.boundless.com/management/textbooks/boundless-management-textbook/organizational-theory-3/behavioral-perspectives-30/the-human-side-hawthorne-170-8381/)

### References

If you look at the comments there are a lot of people that think that there is no need for this type of feature because moderators are only contributing positively to stackoverflow.  These articles all say otherwise:

- [The decline of stackoverflow](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d)
- [Why is stackoverflow so negative as of late](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)
- [My love hate relationship with stackoverflow](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php)
- [stackoverflow and discouraging beginners](https://www.sonyaellenmann.com/2016/06/failures-learning-failures-teaching.html)
- [Why is Stack Overflow - and Stack Exchange in general - so scary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/why-is-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-so-scary)
- [Beware of the stackoverflow overlords](http://timschreiber.com/2013/10/30/beware-the-stackoverlords/)
- [Why stackoverflow sucks](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/)

Comment: You obviously have no idea.  First of all its not moderators that close questions, its any 5 normal users that can close a question.  And secondly if you allow a free for all on questions the you end up with a cesspit like yahoo answers or expertsexchange (thats in theory - in practice it is however too late, the flood of rubbish questions like this one of yours has already long since ruined the quality of stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-dropdown-thats-clickable).

Comment: Let's take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600338/does-json-parse-work-for-deep-nested-objects) for example - Yes, it was closed by a moderator as unclear, and yes - It's unclear why you don't read the [docomentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before posting a question, then you would understand that passing an object to `JSON.parse` just doesn't make sense

Comment: Are you *still* salty about that one time Ryan closed your question?

Comment: Never mind, there's [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-dropdown-thats-clickable).

Comment: Hehe - BoltClock - you are super awesome - and I truly mean that - you have helped me out big time - I would have spun my wheels for a long time if it was not for you...so maybe a little :) - But overall there's seems to be a trend here otherwise I don't think the link on what the purpose of stackoverflow is would exist.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal

Comment: And by the way the people that voted that question into the grave (Initially there were just 2 minuses) did it because of this question did it because of this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352081/asking-questions-without-showing-work

Comment: So it does seem like there are a lot of people who don't want their super powers questioned.  I'm fine with the community as a whole voting things up or down.  When moderators start jumping in and policing questions that have already been answered ... that's when there's a problem.

Comment: @Ole There's not policy (that I know of) saying that moderators can't VTC or up/downvote questions

Comment: There's also this argument about ending up with a cesspit like yahoo answers ... what the heck is that  ... everytime I google something it takes me to stackoverflow - and the answer and question are usually fantastic - so how is this even a concern?  If it's a cesspit question it probably will not receive and answer right - but who are you to decide for everyone else that the question and answer does not belong on SO?

Comment: @Alton Eitan what I'm asking SO to do is track the timing of when and how tools that moderate a question are being used.  If everyone is acting in SOs best interest then there's no problem.

Comment: SO then should correlate the metrics on those tools with the traffic and activity on the tagged channel and decide for itself whether the management of the channel is in line with SOs business goals.  I say business goals because I think what is good for users is good for SOs business.

Comment: But until we can agree on what's good for users, that still won't help. You appear to think that a far more permissive policy would be good for users, whereas many of us disagree - hence the reaction to any Meta question suggesting that SO *should* be more lax on its quality standards. Note that your final sentence sounds like you think a question being closed is equivalent to being deleted - it's not. The point of closing a question is to *encourage* the original poster to respond by improving the question so it can be reopened.

Comment: Why do we have to agree on what's good for users?  There's up voting and down voting.  The users have the power to take care of that themselves.  My view is that there are moderators who are doing the equivalent of spitting in the sandwich and serving it to the customers.  If you are the owner of the restaurant - you should keep an eye on that.

Comment: 1200 upvotes and then closed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Comment: Yes, SO was more tolerant in the past. It was also a lot smaller then, and didn't have tons of already answered questions. I'm not saying that how it is to day is optimal, but it is quite natural that SO needs to adapt to changing circumstances.

Comment: And viewed 93,355 times ... so there's something going on.

Comment: And as you say, when you google a computer problem you very often get a link to SO with a good and relevant answer. Maybe that's a consequence of how SO works?

Comment: "Why do we have to agree on what's good for users?" because by your reasoning, if we can't agree on what's good for users, we can't agree what's good for SO's business, so we can't agree whether the management of the channel is in line with SO's business goals. If you're saying that SO itself is responsible for those choices, then how do you know SO isn't already monitoring this and making appropriate decisions?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - We are going around in circles here.  If SO gets back to use and says that that is precisely what they are doing then the question is answered.  I think the feature request is a good tool for SO to have and I don't see why anyone would have an issue with it?

Comment: @klutt maybe it's a consequence of allowing people to ask questions and receive answers - simple as that.

Comment: Perhaps if your question had been phrased in a neutral way, "Measure and publish timings for moderator actions, and the state of the question at the time" rather than linking it to "I think questions get closed too quickly" it would have received a warmer reception.

Comment: @Ole: no, it is a consequence of [optimising for pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/); we keep a tight focus on questions that are likely to help future visitors.

Comment: It's hard to know what the pearl is if the sand never gets a chance to enter the oyster.

Comment: So in other words SO has instilled the moderators with a crystal ball that allows them within a 5 minute time frame to make a decision on what will be useful to future visitors ... I NEED THIS!  Then I'm going to play the stock market - and we can have a party on my yacht.

Comment: @Ole: the oyster is the site, we receive plenty of questions. Loads of them get rejected because they turn out not to be pearl material. **Nothing of this is new**, we have been doing this for years now, and the success of the site has only grown. It turns out the strategy has been working.

Comment: Great - then why not have a page that allows everyone to drill into those metrics and help ensure that SO stays on track?

Comment: @Ole: knock yourself out: http://data.stackexchange.com/, closure events are included.

Comment: That's impressive - do you have a link to the query I'm looking for?

Comment: `maybe it's a consequence of allowing people to ask questions and receive answers` if that were true, Yahoo Answers and Amazon's Askville would have been resounding successes.

Comment: `So in other words SO has instilled the moderators with a crystal ball that allows them within a 5 minute time frame to make a decision on what will be useful to future visitors` yes - a set of rules. Imperfect, as we all know, and no crystal ball, but a workable toolbox. Just like in any community, there's rules that govern what people can do and how they can interact with each other. You don't have a vote every time a house party on your block goes past midnight; the community has created a rule deciding to what extent it'll allow nighttime parties, and that rule is then enforced.

Comment: That's great - We all like to throw parties and we like it when they are not busted by the Gestapo, because the Gestapo feels like it.  If you recall 10 years ago Monster was the biggest job site.  Do you ever hear about monster anymore?  If you make enough developers angry (Especially the total loosers that are not worthy of the site) it will come back to haunt SO, because someone at some point will create take advantage of this.  What I'm asking SO to do is put in place tools that ensure that the instruments are rules used by moderators are used properly.  Police have bodycams for a reason.

Comment: You don't have to look that far to see the frustration that is being built up: https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/

Comment: @Ole If you feel that a particular policy is harmful, then write up a post that explains what policy you think is harmful, why, and what it should be changed to.  Keep in mind that most all policies have been discussed at length on meta, so you should do your research into past discussions of the policy, and explain why the conclusions arrived at in previous discussions were wrong, or no longer apply, or how your proposed change addresses those concerns.

Comment: It's really not about policy.  Read the article I linked.  People are getting frustrated because they think they are within the community rules for throwing the party, yet their party is busted.  Then they look around and see 100 other parties that were not busted and go WAIT!  WHAT????  So I'm not saying that a particular policy is harmful.  As a matter of fact I think everything has been written up rather well.  I think the moderators interpretation of the policy can be harmful.

Comment: `Then they look around and see 100 other parties that were not busted and go WAIT! WHAT????` they're usually looking at Facebook and Instagram posts of parties that were had a year ago, and forgetting to look at the date.

Comment: We can talk in circles about that - but it's really not necessary.  If we can all click on a moderator and see for example the number of questions they have closed and review the quality of those questions for ourselves then it quickly becomes obvious whether there is overreach or not.  This would relieve frustration for users, because they can easily look and see when the moderator is throwing the flag.  People are going to be people and what brings the best out of all of us is transparency.

Comment: @Ole The information is all public, you can see it, you've been linked to the data sources.  As to the enforcement, yes, you're right that not all of the content that violates site policies gets cleaned up (or gets cleaned up promptly). It's an unfortunate reality that there are more people interested in providing bad content than there are people willing and able to clean it up, so as a result, not all of the trash ends up being thrown out.  We do the best we can.  If you have ideas of ways of more efficiently cleaning up the trash, by all means, propose them.

Comment: Perversely, SO gets a lot of accusations and hate for closing questions *because it is so transparent about its actions*. I know no other major site that is even remotely this transparent. On normal megasites like Facebook or Twitter, there's an army of censors that do nothing but delete stuff 24/7, with zero community oversight, but because the activity is invisible, it's much harder to get worked up about it. On SO, real people do the moderating. It's easy to hate on real people and call them Gestapo or whatnot. On FB and elsewhere, nobody gives a shit about what you think.

Comment: Can't help but think there's a valuable lesson for anyone interested in building a community-based site here. And it's not a good lesson.

Comment: @Pekka where is the link to all the posts that you have closed or moderated along with the timing information for how that was executed?

Comment: The resource where you can find this was pointed out to you twice now. I'm not going to continue this conversation; everything's been said.

Comment: You can, if you want, do your own research [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Right I've looked at that link and I don't see where and how I generate a query that shows the numbers of posts closed or moderated by @Pekka, the timing of the intervention, etc.

Comment: I'm not a moderator; not sure whether normal users' close votes are included in the data dump. If they aren't, then maybe they should be. That would be an actual constructive feature request to make.

Comment: I'm asking SO to create a tool that users can go to if they feel that they are being unfairly targeted ... so not sure why that's causing so much controversy.

Comment: @Ole It's not controversial at all.  You've been linked to such a tool. You're just refusing to use it.  You have the exact information that you're asking for, right at your fingertips.

Comment: No I'm not.  Show me one example of how I find the number of posts closed by a moderator and the timing of that intervention and everyone is happy.

Comment: @Ole Go to data.SE, write a query to find that exact information (all of the raw data is there for you to compute it from), and then execute the query.

Comment: @Ole Why is it *our* fault that you don't actually care enough to get the information you're looking for, when given the tools to do so?  If you actually want to see the info, and consider it worth the few minutes of your time it would take to write the query, then write the query.  If you don't actually care, then that's *your decision*.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not even completely sure what information are you after: a list of delete votes for a particular user? of close votes? What would expect to get from that, exactly?

Comment: Simple - if a moderator closes a question for a user just put a link to the number of other questions closed by the moderator along with the timing so that the user can see what other flags the moderator has thrown.  99% of users are not going to go to http://data.stackexchange.com/ and start looking through 50K fields on how to query the moderator.  It needs to be a simple url.

Comment: Why does the user need info about *other* flags by any other user to know if one particular raised flag is fair or not? How does that make any sense?

Comment: I really can't understand what you're after here. Are you under the impression that moderators get some kind of "kick back" for closing questions, and that visibility into their actions would help keep them honest? If that's the case, you should know that neither elected moderators or regular users get any kind of rep or compensation for closing questions, as duplicates or otherwise.

Comment: Read this: https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/  If a user feels that BillTheLizard is just Gestapoing their posts because he feels like it then it's nice for that user to be able to click on a link and review what BillTheLizard polices in general.

Comment: @ole Then I strongly disagree, and this tool will not likely exist. We don't need you stalking a moderator and second-guessing each of their actions or otherwise harassing them.

Comment: Simple  - If I click this moderator link on a closed question I get complete picture on everything else that was closed by the moderator and I can see for my self whether there is overreach or not.  Is that big deal?

Comment: @Ole If the user cares enough to create their own webpage just to rant about a moderator doing their job and removing low quality content, then I think that user can take the few minutes of their time it would take to actually look at their history.  They seem rather motivated.  If you're sufficiently motivated on their behalf, you could look it up yourself, I'm sure they'll be more than grateful to find evidence that Bill doesn't care about them in the slightest, but rather about closing any bad question.

Comment: I think it is. And I think you are trying to use the wrong tool to fix a non-existing problem. And I think you don't understand how closures and deletions work in SO. Moderators are only the last resource. Most content is closed/deleted by regular users.

Comment: No one is saying anything about harassing a moderator.  If they are doing a great job then they are.  But if a user is feeling targeted then at least they have a tool where they can say to SO / Fellow community members "Look - here are 20 other posts closed by this moderator".  Do you guys agree that all of these fall outside of the rules for SO conduct.

Comment: @Ole And they *can* do that, already, using existing tools.  [meta-tag:status-complete].

Comment: @Servy do you have an example of that somewhere?

Comment: @Ole No, a moderator (or regular user with sufficient rep) will *often* close a run of bad questions by one person. That's totally normal. If you want to complain about it, flag it and *another mod* will investigate. If you don't think you're getting fair treatment from mods, contact SO and *they* will investigate it. There is absolutely no reason why *you* should be the person performing your own investigations when you're the subject of moderator action.

Comment: @Ole It's been provided to you repeatedly.  The information is there to see what that mod has closed, if you care to look, and you can post about it on meta, with links, if you have evidence that a moderator has acted inappropriately.  It happens all the time.

Comment: @meager I have never seen an example of that process on any post I have looked at.  Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: I'm not asking for it for me personally.  It think there are 10 million users on SO.  I'm asking for it to be easily accessible to all of them.

Comment: Here's a simple scenario.  "This post has been closed by BillTheLizard for this reason".  If you feel this is unfair please follow these steps to build a case for it.  That includes reviewing all the closings and other activity by BillTheLizard to see how good a referee BillTheLizard is.  This can then be submitted to metareviews.stackoverflow.com.  And you can let a user have like 3 chances to do this.  Same protocol we use in the NHL or NFL or any other sport where a coach can ask for a play review.

Comment: The community can then perform the review.

Comment: @Ole That's making an assumption that mods are inherently prone to abuse, and that most users should be searching for a pattern of abuse every time that they have a question closed.  That's wrong, and not a constructive message to send.  When a user has their question closed, they need to figure out what they did wrong, and how they can improve their question to make it no longer merit closure.  That's what the close reason, correctly focuses on.  The tools are in place to find and prevent the abuse in the extreme cases, for those that feel they are actually needed.

Comment: @Ole, considering the overwhelming response you've gotten so far to this and your othe "let's lower SO standards" meta post... you should realize by now that even if you _are_ actually right; you are facing unsurmountable disagreement here. Why persist? If you feel SO is failing you so much, you might be better served by taking a short break from the site.

Comment: @Servy you are right in all the cases that you are right - which is probably 70-80% of cases.  I'm asking for a process that can handle the other 20%-30%.

Comment: @yivi based on some of the other links I have seen here - I'm not going to be the least bit surprised if this starts getting a lot of upvotes in the long run - unless you figure out a way to cap that.

Comment: Or 99% - 1%. Before asking for the tool, you could do your research and see if your numbers actually make sense. Otherwise, you are making an expensive and possibly problematic proposition without any reseach to back you up.

Comment: @Ole If you're going to assert that moderators are abusively closing questions they know don't merit closure because of personal vendettas *20 to 30 percent of the time* then you're going to need to back that up.  I've *never* seen a case of it *ever*.  There are plenty of places where people disagree over whether a particular question crosses the line, or where the line is, or even where someone simply makes a mistake and misunderstands a question (or misclicks), but the abuse you're asserting is extremely common is something I haven't even seen *once*, and it's a *very* serious accusation.

Comment: Look we are talking about a tool that probably takes a SO dev 2 days to complete.  After that we can see what pops up.  If you are right, then that's a great thing, but the fact that 93000 people reviewed this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late suggest that maybe you are one of the people with a lot to hide.

Comment: @Ole You have the data.  Go look.  I don't have anything to hide.  Go find the evidence to back up your assertions, rather than just claiming them without basis, despite having the means at your disposal to verify them.  Yes, lots of people don't like to be told when they do something wrong.  Lots of people want to be able to do things that help them, at the expense of everyone around them, by being able to post low quality content without consequences.  While understandable desires, they're clearly not beneficial for the site.

Comment: In a play review it's very easy to get a picture of moderator and user actions.  If the user has a lot of poor quality posts and still complains about being moderated, then obviously that user has a problem, but if the moderator is taking a sledgehammer to SO questions blindfolded then that would be a play by play review that all would like to see.  I'm asking for that play by play tool to be put in place.  If it's never used, as you are saying it won't be, then that's great.

Comment: "if the moderator is taking a sledgehammer to SO questions blindfolded" Absolutely no need for a replay tool to tell if a specific question is unfairly closed. Flag it and move on.

Comment: Please stop spamming your question with edits and comments. You're continually bumping it without adding anything *new* to the question. You've made your case, the community will vote (or not) to reopen your question over time. Nobody is taking any action against your question to keep it closed, I'm not sure what you think is happening there but edits don't reopen your question if that's your thinking.

Comment: sounds like you want an appeals.stackoverflow.com

Comment: ' I'm asking for that play by play tool to be put in place' well, since you have presented no evidence of ' moderators taking a sledgehammer to SO questions blindfolded', but are convinced that it happens, would you be willing to pay for the development of such a tool?

Comment: Nobody comes here for the reasons you list in your latest update. They come here because there are probably already good answers to their questions, and the reason they can *find* those answers it that we're careful to maintain our content, and reject the noise that pollutes other Q&A sites.

Comment: All else aside, why do you think we need an extra tool to dispute closures? People already come on Meta to ask why their question got put on hold *all the time*.

Comment: *This question received 2 runnable answers in five minutes.* That doesn't make the question on topic. Why not just put a small, functioning example of that drop down menu in the question itself instead of pointing to a tutorial?

Comment: If you want to dispute the closure of your CSS dropdown question, ask a meta question about that. Please stop editing irrelevant information into your **feature request**. You've stated the case for your feature and described its use, the "references" you've been adding are not relevant and the continued editing needs to stop. The links you've uncovered are many years old and have been referenced and discussed on meta time and time again. They have nothing to do with your proposed feature request.

Comment: I've asked you repeatedly to stop bumping your post with spammy edits. If you want to include **relevant** supporting information then do so, but collecting random anti-Stack Overflow links from around the Internet is *not* relevant here. These pages are *years old* and have been discussed ad nauseum. Please limit yourself to **substantial** edits and stop making small irrelevant changes.

Comment: @meagar at this point one has to wonder.... does this question even appears in the home page?

Comment: @Braiam: -8 is the limit for when questions stop appearing on the home page listing, if I recall.

Comment: @NicolBolas yet for some reason keeps appearing on mine... every time is edited.

Comment: @NicolBolas OP just bumped it with another edit so I'm also seeing it in the 'Home' tab. It also shows a couple of other highly down voted questions. I'm guessing the limit only applies to the Main site, not Meta.

Comment: @BSMP: That's strange; I don't see it on the [main MSO page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). I only see it on [the questions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: @NicolBolas maybe the new-old nav vs the old nav differences?

Comment: @Braiam : In an attempt to be actually helpful, [*I fixed Ole's question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-clickable-dropdown). Now, if more people would do just that instead of telling people to bugger off *when they make an effort to come to "meta" and raise an issue* (→ no, I'm not saying we should improve ALL questions of questionable quality ourselves), SO would be having the bad rap it has today. Yes, I'm all in favor of strict rules, but (1) the rules do need to make sense (which they often don't) & (2) strictness is no excuse for being unhelpful or plain rude!

Comment: @JohnSlegers thank you.  SIDE NOTE - Just about every single post I see has a lot of comments on them, and some of them have 0 additional information.  Thank you has been  social norm for a while now, especially when someone is being really helpful, and to act as if that is a bad thing is ... It would be nice if SO implemented some emoji like mechanism to communicate this stuff without adding too much noise ... for example github allows you to add thumbs up, etc. emojis to the comment posts.

Comment: I also understand that some of the people making comments on this post wanted me to provide the type of context that @JonSlegers has now provided, however I have done that in the past, and the person answering will use their own context for something they have been working on to provide the runnable code, so now their is a context mismatch with the question and the answer.  My experience is that the answers trickle in within 5 minutes, so I try to keep the question as succint and minimal as possible allowing the person providing the answer freedom to structure the context.

Comment: So essentially you are at the restaurant, you ordered your food by simply saying "I would like the calamari".  You don't provide a picture of the calamari because the server knows what it is.  It's served.  You eat and you are ready to order dessert, but first one of the servers wants to show you how to properly hold your fork and cut the calamari, since you were eating it with your fingers like a savage.  So you decline the instructions at which point they throw you out of the restaurant.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the above analogy is that it sounds snobby, and does not include the fact that all the people helping on SO are incredibly bright and talented people.  Most of the time it's like going to visit the Oracle.

Comment: These moderators are Nazi's. I can never actually ask a question. It's way to toxic and forget about having a discussion with another member. "Off topic" deleted... SMH

Answer (score -27, accepted):

> And I thought. Wow - right on! For example in the past this type of
> question would have been OK:
>
> [**What is the difference between :focus and :active?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active)
>
> But this is no longer acceptable. You have to show work. In the above
> case, that would have diluted the question, thus wasting the time of
> all the readers who find the question and answer useful. That is not a
> concern for the moderators who are now cracking down on these types of
> questions.

Personally, I believe that question is a perfectly reasonable question that totally belongs here on SO. And I don't see why [**Pure CSS Dropdown That's Clickable?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-dropdown-thats-clickable) should be any different.

Yes, these illustrate a total lack of experience in frontend web development, but that doesn't mean they aren't valid programming questions. Just because any experienced frontend developer would consider those pretty silly / ignorant question, that doesn't mean they're off topic.

Nor do they prove lack of effort on the side of the person raising the question. Some information is just hard to find, especially if the person looking is a n00b or the answer to be found is complicated. Heck, I don't think anyone would ask a question on SO if they would know a better place to get their answer. You can't just assume laziness just because YOU happen to know resources that can answer most n00b questions in less than 5 minutes and people somehow ended up not reading those first before they raised their question at SO.

If people have a programming issue that other people are likely to encounter as well, I don't see why a question addressing that issue should be closed just because it doesn't contain an arbitrarily determined amount of code. Nor do I see why questions of the time "is X possible" should illustrate coding effort.

Why should anyone have to waste hours trying to achieve something so he can somehow prove he's done enough effort before I can spend 30 seconds of my time to tell him that what he wants is impossible?! How helpful is that? How does that increase people's productivity? Because, really, isn't increasing either our own productivity or the productivity of others the very reason why people are supposed to be active on SO? Isn't this what SO is supposed to be all about?

To quote Niels Bohr : "An expert is a man who has made all the mistakes which can be made, in a narrow field." Many people on SO seem to have forgotten that they all were n00bs some time ago. We all made mistakes that we now consider utterly stupid & ignorant. And we all would have appreciated it a few senior programmers would have spent a few minutes of their precious time to educate us on some basic fundamentals of programming instead of letting us figure out everything on our own and waste hours - if not days or weeks - on dead ends.

Heck, it is my experience that the most useful questions tend to be questions that end up getting closed before anyone gets the chance to post an anwser. I mean... sometimes all you need is a direction to look at to help you get started, but you cannot ask that here because you must prove in some way that you've already started.

Or sometimes all you need is a framework or library to take care of the heavy lifting, but asking for external resources is not allowed here as well. And God forbid you ask a question similar to one already asked, but with only outdated or otherwise useless answers... God forbid!

> So I'm requesting that Stackoverflow create a replay feature. We have
> it in soccer nets, hockey nets, the NFL has the ability to review
> plays. Here's how it should work.
>
> > "This post has been closed by BillTheLizard for this reason". If you
> > feel this is unfair please follow these steps to build a case for it.
> > That includes reviewing all the closings and other activity by
> > BillTheLizard to see how good a referee BillTheLizard is. This can
> > then be submitted to metareviews.stackoverflow.com. And you can let a
> > user have like 3 chances to do this. Same protocol we use in the NHL
> > or NFL or any other sport where a coach can ask for a play review

I'm not convinced that an [**"appeal system"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal) like the one you're proposing can or will make difference. SO already has several ways to appeal against decisions made by other users :

- people can raise an issue in the comments of a post
- people can raise an issue on chat
- people can flag a closed question to nominate it for re-opening
- people can flag a deleted question to nominate it for undeletion
- people can flag a question to call for moderator assistance
- people can raise a question here on "meta" to discuss actions of other users
- ...

Yet I'd agree it can be damn near impossible to get question re-opened or undeleted, even when they've been closed for the most questionable of reasons. But I don't think the problem is that there is no practical way to appeal the decisions of other users. I don't think the solution is to implement newer or better ways to appeal against the decisions made by other users. Personally, I think problem lays with the actual users making the decisions. I'd say it kinda boils down to [**"Who watches the Watchmen"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F)...

In the long run, any set of rules and standards will only be as good as the people applying them. And during my time here on SO, I've come to the conclusion that...

1. many of the rules on SO simply don't make sense and are counter-productive
2. many of the rules that do make sense are too vague and open for interpretation
3. many of the users policing SO apply the rules in ways that are totally unproductive
4. many of those same users behave in a way that is elitist/arrogant, hostile or otherwise unpleasant for people who trying to engage with SO in a productive way, chasing them away
5. the gamification mechanism that gives us our privileges often favors the wrong behavior, rewarding the wrong people and making aforementioned problems worse
6. all of the above makes it nearly impossible for many real world programming questions to get answered on SO

People like myself and many others [**have been complaining about one or more of these issues**](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) over and over, ad nauseam. The moderators simply don't care, either because they see SO as [**"the worst form of Q&A system except all others"**](https://richardlangworth.com/worst-form-of-government) or because they simply don't see the problem from their ivory towers where everyone is congratulating each other on how great they're doing...

Eiher way, I can only see things getting worse and worse until the owners & administrators of SO acknowledge the aforementioned issues and address their root causes...

> please create a set of key performance indicators that monitor the
> question, how fast a moderator cancels it or closes it, and whether
> anyone was allowed to respond before the moderator intervened. An
> aggregate public summary view of questions that moderators are closing
> would be great.

Anyone can create their own queries on [**Data.SE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Here's some queries I created two years ago :

- [**Questions closed by closing time for users with reputation < 100, per month since 2011**](http://Questions%20closed%20by%20closing%20time%20for%20users%20with%20reputation%20%3C%20100,%20per%20month%20since%202011)
- [**Questions closed by closing time for users with reputation < 1000, per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334203/questions-closed-by-closing-time-for-users-with-reputation-1000-per-month-sinc)
- [**Questions closed by closing time, per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333590/questions-closed-by-closing-time-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Questions closed within 24 hours, per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333581/questions-closed-within-24-hours-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Upvotes per month, since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334150/upvotes-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvotes per month, since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334141/downvotes-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvotes within first minute, per tag, per month, since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334157/downvotes-within-first-minute-per-tag-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvotes per month for user accounts < 7 days old, since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334183/downvotes-per-month-for-user-accounts-7-days-old-since-2011)
- [**Votes by voting time, per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334118/votes-by-voting-time-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvote / Upvote ratio per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334105/downvote-upvote-ratio-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvote / Upvote ratio within 1 minute, per month since 2011**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334106/downvote-upvote-ratio-within-1-minute-per-month-since-2011)
- [**Downvote / upvote ratio for all answers since 2009**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333919/downvote-upvote-ratio-for-all-answers-since-2009)
- [**Lowest rate of Down-Votes for questions with more Down-Votes than Up-Votes**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333699/lowest-rate-of-down-votes-for-questions-with-more-down-votes-than-up-votes)
- [**Highest rate of Down-Votes for questions with more Up-Votes than Down-Votes**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333687/highest-rate-of-down-votes-for-questions-with-more-up-votes-than-down-votes)
- [**View rate, answer rate, vote rate and close rate for all questions since 2009**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333734/view-rate-answer-rate-vote-rate-and-close-rate-for-all-questions-since-2009)
- [**Vote rate for all answers since 2009**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333931/vote-rate-for-all-answers-since-2009)
- [**Votes cast per day for the most popular tags**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/333528/votes-cast-per-day-for-the-most-popular-tags#resultSets)
- [**Posts per month since 2011 for users with reputation > 2K**](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/334019/posts-per-month-since-2011-for-users-with-reputation-2k)
- ...

Feel free to use these queries (or [**any of my queries**](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18811/john-slegers)) as a starting point for pulling your own metrics!

Comment: `And we all would have appreciated it a few senior programmers would have spent a few minutes of their precious time to educate us on some basic fundamentals of programming instead of letting us figure out everything on our own and waste hours - if not days or weeks - on dead ends.` sure - but a million new programmers asking a couple thousand senior programmers simply isn't a sustainable model. I'm currently learning a couple new technologies and am making loads of mistakes. Part of them are because I've opted to just get started, rather than sit through....

Comment: ...a systematic fundamental education on the languages I need to learn; it's more economical for me this way because I can learn in bite-sized units during a busy work day. It would, however, never occur to me to offset the cost of that decision to someone else and start asking questions I can answer myself by Googling - or working through the fundamental basics after all.

Comment: Incidentally though, I do find the question mentioned by the OP fairly reasonable - *in its final edited form.* It was not a good question in its original form and I would have downvoted it, too.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - `but a million new programmers asking a couple thousand senior programmers simply isn't a sustainable model` - Maybe... maybe not... but it is how I would define the purpose of StackOverflow? *** `it would never occur to me to offset the cost of that decision to someone else` - In several years, I've raised only about 10 questions on SO and answered +500 questions. So, like you, I prefer to figure things out on my own - and I usually do - before I ask a question on SO.

Comment: `but it is how I would define the purpose of StackOverflow?` Well, many here wouldn't, at least not for every type of question a new programmer might have. And it's a sentiment that goes far beyond some perceived elite group - just watch what happens to candidates in moderator elections who promise to be super duper lenient. Like it or not, our continuously increasing strictness and narrowness is a product of the community, arguably not in sync with the wishes of even the people running the site - even Jeff was surprised by the direction the place's rules have taken since the site's inception.

Comment: `So, like you, I prefer to figure things out on my own - and I usually do - before I ask a question on SO` yup, didn't mean you personally, but some of the askers of the type of question we're talking about here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I'm all in favor of strict rules. I guess I just have an issue with (1) the choice of rules, (2) the vague way many are formulated (leaving too much room for interpretation) & (3) the unhelpful mentality of many of the people doing the moderation. One of the other reasons I raised so few questions, is that most of the questions I would like to ask are questions that aren't allowed on SO (eg. "what library could I use to do X") or that I rarely got any useful answer during those few times I did ask a question. When I ask a question, I pretty much expect not to get an answer...

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*Why should anyone have to waste hours trying to achieve something so he can somehow prove he's done enough effort before I can spend 30 seconds of my time to tell him that what he wants is impossible?! How helpful is that?*" Because it teaches them to be programmers. A programmer is someone who can solve problems. Copying a solution and pasting it into their program is not solving a problem. You're basically saying that, rather than disseminating knowledge, we should just be doing work for other people. That's teaching them to be bad programmers.

Comment: @JohnSlegers don't entirely disagree with your description of the problem. I see too many (often new) people ask questions in very good faith and fail, too. It's not moderators's fault, though. There is a strong community consensus behind these things. Moderators just execute the policy with some, but definitely not unlimited, leeway. I don't like the extreme narrowness that we have, but am not sure what can be done about it. Overall, I lean very much towards the "worst form except all others" view. SO *still* manages to deliver quality content in many many cases.

Comment: @NicolBolas : There's three ways I learn how to write decent code : (1) reading material on coding, (2) tinkering with code myself and (3) getting advice from senior programmers. The effectiveness of each of these strategy depends on your personality, where you are in your career and other context-related aspects. How can judge people and argue they haven't spent enough time reading or tinkering with code before they can ask a certain question on SO so people like me can give them advice when you know little to nothing about their background?

Comment: (continued) : Whenever have to learn some new tech, I find that sitting together with a senior dev who has experience with that particular tech is still the best way to get started, followed by watching a lecture by senior devs... and reading articles... written by senior devs. Tinkering with code is something I usually only start with after I feel confident enough because of the advice I got from other people. And for me, that's the reason why I'd like to share my own experience with other devs here on SO.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*I find that sitting together with a senior dev*" That's great; that's a wonderful way to get started with some new tech. SO is *not the place* for that sort of thing. It's not for interacting with a senior dev who slowly guides you through the new tech. You drop a question in a box, and some time later, an answer pops out. It's supposed to be completely impersonal.

Comment: @NicolBolas : It's those rare moments when someone explicitly thanks me for helping them with their problem and keeping them from wasting any more hours on their problem that gives me that fuzzy feeling that the many hours I spent on SO are not entirely wasted... far more than any badges or up-votes could do. This may not be a place for cozy chats, but it's still a place for people asking questions & people answering questions. And people on both sides still expect to be treated with respect... or get frustrated when someone prevents others from helping them or vice versa...

Comment: (continued) For me, posting a long answer on SO that has the potential of helping countless people feels a lot like sitting together with a junior dev... or giving a lecture on a stage... or talking your customer through how to get something done. It all boils down to me sharing me personal experience as a programmer to someone else who hopefully can increase his/her productivity because of it. And in a way, SO can be more gratifying than any of the more personal equivalents, because you know you may be able to help up to millions of people with just a single answer.

Comment: @JohnSlegers If you're here for the "thanks", you're here for the wrong reason. That's not what this site is for. We're a **work of reference** not an interactive tutorial site.

Comment: *Why should anyone have to waste hours...*  Would it have really taken hours to produce a minimal version of the result of following the tutorial? Why is it so unreasonable to ask that people posting questions not force people trying to answer to start completely from scratch?

Comment: @john Slegers greatly appreciate your well written and eloquent input.  I think if SO has a tool that users can use to appeal what they see as "A poor judgement call" and build a review case that at least makes them feel better about SO as a whole.  If you can make them feel better then that should drive a decrease in moderator flag alarms going off, and that should be really good for all of us.

Comment: @meagar : This is a Q&A site, where both questions, answers and comments are added 24/7. No matter how much you're prefer to see it otherwise, that does make it kind of a tutorial site with some degree of interactivity.

Comment: @BSMP : `Would it have really taken hours to produce a minimal version of the result of following the tutorial?` - It can take a person who is new to a particular kind of tech hours or days (maybe even weeks?) just to figure out how to get started! That's something someone with even a limited amount of understanding of that same tech can explain in just a few minutes of time. This, I believe, is what StackOverflow COULD and SHOULD offer, but which elitist attitudes and nonsensical arbitrary rules often prevent from happening!

Comment: (continued) l: It is **totally unreasonable** to ask that people post a minimal version of something if the problem they're facing is so elementary that they don't know how to get started. Getting started is often the hardest part. Even with 15 years of experience in many different programming environments, it is getting started with a new language, a new framework or a new paradigm that I find most challenging. It is that moment **before** I write my first letter of code that I find most challenging and where I find the assistance of another dev most useful!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: sure, but that **doesn't mean Stack Overflow is the place for that**. Stop assuming that it is and you'll have a much better time here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Stop preventing people from helping others with their problems with the most nonsensical and arbitrary rules, and **everyone** would have a much better time here!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: stop painting the rules as arbitrary; they are pretty clear. We have a small number of closing reasons, and a narrow definition of what is on-topic. Stop assuming that when people disagree with you they are being elitist, arrogant or hostile (it is you that is coming over as hostile by using terminology like that). Not that I think you'll listen to me, I'm already part of the elite in your view anyway, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : That small number of vaguely defined closing reasons is interpreted so loosely and so irrationally that I find it impossible to raise a question that is considered on-topic for the vast majority of programming issues I actually could use some help for. And those few times I can come up with a question that is considered on topic (about 10 times, in all the years I've been here), I rarely ever get an answer that is helpful at all. Basically, I've come to a point where I no longer expect SO to be helpful at all when facing with a programming problem.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: I'm sorry that you have found SO to be unhelpful for your questions. You appear to have plenty of well-received questions on your account. I don't see how the rules were hard to figure out for those that were closed; is it clear to you taht https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803420/using-svg-and-or-html-to-visualize-a-family-tree-where-nodes-can-have-multiple-p is really too broad?

Comment: @JohnSlegers: thanks for calling me an arrogant jerk. This is why people are not willing to help you or listen to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149365/discussion-between-john-slegers-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 31):

> please create a set of key performance indicators that monitor the question, how fast a moderator cancels it or closes it, and whether anyone was allowed to respond before the moderator intervened. An aggregate public summary view of questions that moderators are closing would be great.

OK, let's say we do that. So you can look at a user's closing history to see how fast they close questions on average. You can see how many questions they voted to close which had answers on it. And so forth.

What exactly will that accomplish?

If a question deserves to be closed, then *it deserves to be closed*. Whether that happens 1 second after its posted, or 50 years later after dozens of people have answered it, it still deserves to be closed. Consequently, if a question doesn't deserve to be closed, if it's closed after being answered, then it still *doesn't deserve to be closed*.

Time to closure is therefore completely irrelevant as a useful statistic. A user who frequently votes to close questions quickly after they are answered is objectively no worse at the task of closing questions properly than those who vote months later.

If you find a user who VTCs questions soon after they're asked, can you use that fact to decide how good they are at judging which questions should be closed? No. The only way you can judge that is by actually *looking* at which questions they vote to close and which ones they don't.

So this will not actually accomplish anything towards your presumed goal of improving the site.

Now, your real problem is right here:

> why when a person is willing to ask and others are happy to answer - almost always within a five minute time frame - does a moderator get to crack down on the question?

Because that's not how the site works. We have minimum standards for questions. And if an asker and answerer happen to disagree about that standard... *tough*.

We, as the community most experienced with SO, came to an agreement about what that standard will be based on *experience* with what happens when you *don't* have that standard. We have a really good idea about what kinds of questions provoke good, useful answers and which kinds of questions are useless filler that helps nobody but the original answerer.

You say:

> There's also this argument about ending up with a cesspit like yahoo answers ... what the heck is that ... everytime I google something it takes me to stackoverflow - and the answer and question are usually fantastic - so how is this even a concern?

The *reason* Google sends you to SO instead of Yahoo Answers is ***BECAUSE OF OUR STANDARDS***. The reason "the answer and question are usually fantastic" is *because* of our standards. We try our best to reject crap, and in so doing use the time of people who give fantastic answers more efficiently.

> My view is that there are moderators who are doing the equivalent of spitting in the sandwich and serving it to the customers.

My view is that "moderators" (AKA: users with close voting powers) are keeping the site afloat. They're the ones keeping the crap questions at bay, maintaining the question quality of the site, and thus making it attractive to people who actually know things.

The "customers" are the people who find good answers. They are not served by crap questions that don't help them.

---

> we now have a lot of people who think SO is great because of **STANDARDS**, and they are out their cracking down on whoever misses a comma in their code, did not dilute their question thoroughly enough, and so on.

This is hyperbolic nonsense. Nobody votes to close questions over a comma. And I don't know what you're talking about with "diluting" of questions.

But yes, this is what makes SO what it is. Having a bunch of garbage questions that help nobody but the OP is not what we want. The reason why "people that like to share knowledge" are on this site is because they find that there are good questions here that allow them to do so.

Other sites have all of those things you mention. SO was not the first Q&A site. It was not the first site to have voting on posts or even on questions/answers. And yet, SO is the one that is most famous and most well-regarded. Why?

Because we developed standards for the questions we allow. We explicitly do not allow whatever crap a user wants to throw onto the site. We try not to waste the time of experienced users by having them wade through uninteresting garbage.

Comment: Reminds me a lot of this Jimmy Kimmel Episode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4muxxItbGvo

Comment: While many standards on SO simply don't make sense, even those that do are commonly abused by privileged trolls. [**StackOverflow is literally full of "soup Nazis"**](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) who apply the most irrational arguments for closing questions, downvoting posts or otherwise engaging with other users in a way that makes those users lose any interest in actively engaging in a meaningful manner with SO. Any standard is only as good as the people enforcing it. Ignoring the problem or pretending it doesn't exist doesn't make it any less a problem!

Comment: @John So, your position is, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44832572/1) was totally fine and should not have been closed, and all the people who voted to close it are just "soup Nazis"? You don't think the requirement that the relevant portions of the code need to be in the question itself "make sense"? Or are you talking about *other* types of abuse?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's a perfectly reasonable question. Yes, it illustrates a total lack of experience in frontend web development, but that doesn't mean it's not a valid programming question. If people have a programming issue that other people are likely to encounter as well, I don't see why a question addressing that issue should be closed just because it doesn't contain an arbitrarily determined amount of code. And I don't see why questions of the time "is X possible" should illustrate coding effort. Why waste hours trying to achieve something I can tell you in 30 seconds is impossible?!

Comment: (continued) To quote Niels Bohr : "An expert is a man who has made all the mistakes which can be made, in a narrow field." Many people on SO seem to have forgotten that they all were n00bs some time ago. We all made mistakes that we now consider utterly stupid & ignorant. And we all would have appreciated it a few senior programmers would have spent a few minutes of their precious time to educate us on some basic fundamentals of programming instead of letting us figure out everything on our own and waste hours - if not days or weeks -
 on dead ends.

Comment: (continued) Heck, it is my experience that the most useful questions tend to be questions that end up getting closed or get no answer at all. I mean... sometimes all you need is a direction to look at to help you get started, but you cannot ask that here because you must prove in some way that you've already started. Or sometimes all you need is a framework or library to take care of the heavy lifting, but asking for external resources is not allowed here as well. And god forbid you ask a question similar to one already asked, but with only outdated or otherwise useless answers... God forbid!

Comment: --> I added these comments to my answer

Comment: The "soup nazi" is an overloaded simile. The soup nazi has his business, and the moment you enter, you accept his terms of service. He doesn't take your money (or whatever you gave) if he doesn't give you soup. As long as he's not discriminating social classes, he can do as he please with his private business, and will get clients as long as his soup is as godly as it is and the price is reasonable. Our price is equally reasonable, since at the end of the day, we are providing several times more value than what the asker provides (an answer instead of a question).

Comment: @Braiam : As you said, it is the "soup Nazi"'s right to deny anyone service. Much so is the elite here at SO entirely in their right to deny anyone service for any reason they consider valid. I'm not arguing against that. What I'm arguing against, is that putting the wrong people in charge and using the wrong reasons for denying people service makes it increasingly difficult for anyone to get helpful answers on SO, no matter how well-meaning people are or how much effort was spent on a question  and the research leading up to it.

Comment: @JohnSlegers so, what do you believe are the wrong reasons? Having interesting questions (or at least not dead beat questions) to answer isn't fair? Because as far as I'm aware, the people that provide value are answerers, and if you don't keep them happy they are not going to answer anything at all. It's completely fair that they have that power. They've earned it. Oh, btw, there are at least 10 million answers on the site, do you really believe that those answers aren't the most common?

Comment: @Braiam : `what do you believe are the wrong reasons?`- For example, closing questions that ask for advice on which framework or library to use is pretty stupid, since that's often the best way to solve a problem. ***  -  `It's completely fair that they have that power. They've earned it` - How exactly did people who (through sheer luck) got the vast majority of their upvotes from raising a handful of popular n00b questions with +500 upvotes "earn" their rep? In my experience, post quantity & luck play a far greater role than post quality in getting a decent rep here at StackOverflow!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: It has been proven from the early days of SO that "advice" questions degenerate into discussion. SO exists to *prevent* discussion. "*In my experience, post quantity & luck play a far greater role than post quality in getting a decent rep here at StackOverflow!*" Your experience does not seem to correlate with the facts on this site. Most people with 20+k rep did not get it from a few highly-upvoted answers to "n00b questions". For example, I did a quick test where I computed the rep from answers I've given with 50+ upvotes. It's still less than one fifth of my total rep.

Comment: @NicolBolas : `"advice" questions degenerate into discussion` - ANY technical question can result in discussion. Yes, I understand that the choice of framework or library may be more prone to personal taste than certain issues other issue, but doesn't apply in every case (sometimes it's hard to find just a single library with all necessary features). Nor is that that's no reason to throw away the baby with the bath water. You shouldn't prevent people from finding the help they need when finding the directions to the right library for their problem is really all they need...

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*I understand that the choice of framework or library may be more prone to personal taste than certain issues other issue*" No, that's the end of it. We want to minimize discussion as much as possible, so we excise the things that cause the *most* discussion. And subjective questions cause the most discussion. "*You shouldn't prevent people from finding the help they need when finding the directions to the right library for their problem is really all they need.*" We're not preventing anything; we're simply not providing that service *on this site*.

Comment: (continued) `Your experience does not seem to correlate with the facts on this site` - Are you're saying you know how to measure quality now? Or luck? Which metrics do you use exactly to measure the impact of quality and luck?

Comment: @JohnSlegers: You're the one making the claim. So you're the one who has to provide evidence for it. What metrics do *you* use?

Comment: Ok, @john, lets try it easy: how can you be convinced that we are better than what you pictures us to be?

Comment: @NicolBolas : `We want to minimize discussion as much as possible, so we excise the things that cause the most discussion. And subjective questions cause the most discussion.` - Not all questions that involve the choice of a framework involve a high degree of subjectivity. Nor is subjectivity a bad thing per se. Not allowing topics that are more prone to subjectivity is just a pretty bad idea if it prevents people from getting the help they need on technical issues. It makes SO pretty useless for many -
 if not most - issues I experience as a programmer and would really like some help for!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: If most issues you experience as a programmer are things that can be solved by "use this framework/library", then I humbly submit that what you do and what I do are very different things.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*Nor is subjectivity a bad thing per se.*" Yes, it is. It's been proven to be a bad thing. *Twice*. First, in SO's early days when subjectivity ran wild and quality was terrible. Second, in the "Not Programming Related" days, when subjectivity ran wild on Programmers.SE and quality was terrible. What you're talking about is not new to SO. It has been tried, and it has *consistently* been shown to produce bad questions, bad answers, and general crap. Experience has taught us what questions produce good answers and what questions do not.

Comment: @JohnSlegers appreciate your eloquent and well thought out response.  I think if every single user has the ability to review the "calls" made by their peers / moderator via a simple tool that allows them to aggregate calls they consider damaging, then they will at a minimum feel better about SO as a whole, which should lead to less articles like the ones we have linked and less moderator flags going due to comments lists overheating.

Comment: @Ole: "*calls they consider damaging*" But they're not damaging, no matter how much they consider them so. As I pointed out, the "damage" of a closure can only be judged by actually looking at the question being closed. Which no aggregator can do. And therefore their ability to aggregate based on some terrible/meaningless criteria and complain about them is unproductive and unhelpful to achieving the site's goals.

Comment: @NicolBolas we have 2 sides with differing opinions.  If you have a tool that acts as a mediator then there's a good chance that those 2 sides will feel better about each other.  Nobody is perfect.  Some refs are better than others and no ref has the ability to be right 100% of the time.  If you have one ref that's handing out 2 red cards every 4 games, that's a nice thing to be aware of.  Just because we think it does not happen does not mean it's not happening.

Comment: @Ole: "*If you have a tool that acts as a mediator then there's a good chance that those 2 sides will feel better about each other.*" Nonsense. That will only happen if both sides *respect* the mediator. And thus far, the mediator you have proposed is respected by pretty much nobody who isn't on your side. I do not recognize that someone who closes questions within 5 minutes of them being posted is doing anything wrong. And the ability to detect such persons will in no way make me feel any different about that.

Comment: If you and I are having a beer and discussing programming and someone jumps in and says "Um no talking about C++ here", the other guests don't like it.  We are going to be like WUUT?  And who are you?  And that's how some people feel.  It's not damaging, but it is alienating ...

Comment: @Ole: You seem to be missing my point. I had two of them, yet you seem to have missed both. The most important is that ***the change you have proposed will in no way fix the problem you claim exists.*** Arbitrary metrics and automated tools cannot reliably detect when someone is closing questions improperly.

Comment: There is not the slightest indication that nuclear energy will ever be obtainable.  It would mean that the atom would have to be shattered at will - Albert Einstein.

Comment: @Ole: Hurray, you can use WikiQuote. Was there a purpose to that statement, or did you just want to show off your ability to quote mine? Because it in no way invalidates anything I have said, nor does it show any errors in the reasoning I have provided.

Comment: I know - you are the genius who has everything figured already.

Comment: @Ole: I'm not a genius. I'm simply having a debate. A debate in which I've put forth reasoning why your idea won't help, even to solve the problem you say exists. While you've put forth zero reasoning as to how it would help solve the problem of inappropriate closures. Unless you define "inappropriate" to mean "fast", in which case your OP is inaccurate, since the problem you cite is one of questions being closed that should remain open, rather than how fast questions are closed whether they should be or not.

Comment: See the link I put in the question on the Hawthorne studies.  Researchers increased the lighting in the factory - productivity increased.  They decreased the lighting - productivity increased.  Why?  Because the workers felt like someone cared.  So it could be a purely symbolic feature, but it shows that SO actually cares to address the growing chorus of people who feel that SO is hostile, and that matters.

Comment: @Ole: They've already done that. They gave people who think SO is hostile [a place to play](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation). So go play and leave the rest of us alone. But making it easy for people like you to target contributors to this site for harassment and questioning will do nothing but drive useful contributors away.

Comment: @Ole: The other thing you don't understand is that there are plenty of long-time contributors who believe that the rules are currently *too lenient*. That we're allowing way too much crap in. People who want to allow experienced users to have faster close-voting powers, or to punish people who answer bad questions by deducting rep from them, or whatever. These people have provided significant and useful contributions to this site. Why should SO consider your feelings over people like them?

Comment: @Ole: Why not have a way to track users who ask bad questions? Let's have statistics on users whose questions are closed as duplicates within 10 minutes. Users whose questions get downvoted within 10 minutes. Or so forth. I'm sure some people would very much like to be able to name-and-shame such users.

Comment: Because there are a lot of people on SO that are really fantastic when it comes to being helpful.  They actually don't mind helping.  On the contrary they enjoy it and it makes their life more meaningful.  Then a moderator comes along and smashes that butterfly....and those people are now disillusioned, offended, etc. and that dynamic is not good.  Now if someone is asking a bad question after receiving guidance and help 15 -20 times in a row, then maybe a summary page of this activity that could be exclusive to that person and a few of the people providing assistance would be helpful.

Comment: @Ole: You keep talking about "a moderator" as if they're some rare, precious species of user. You get close-voting powers at 3,000 rep. That's not a lot. You also keep talking about "a moderator" as though they're people who don't want to be helpful. Getting 3,000 rep generally requires "being helpful". Nothing you've said here makes sense once taken out of your deluded world of "moderators vs. non-moderators".

Comment: @Ole: You also seem to not be willing to acknowledge that the fact that someone might be able to post something in response to a question that the OP consideres an answer does not mean the question deserves to be answered. You do not consider the consequences of encouraging the asking of low-quality questions. To you, if a question could possibly be answered, then it ought to be here. Again, this model has been ***proven to fail***. Stop suggesting things that we already know don't work.

Comment: You are purposely ignoring the comments made in "The decline of stackoverflow", etc.  Some of our peers feel like they are being handled by a bunch of soup Nazis and there is something SO can do to address that.  It does not necessarily have to be open to the global public, but could be open to a select group of our peers, just like moderation is in general.

Comment: @Ole: "*You are purposely ignoring the comments made in "The decline of stackoverflow", etc.*" Let me make this perfectly clear: ***I don't care.*** I don't care how many off-site rants there are about how difficult it is to get a question answered on SO. I care about what is good for SO. And if catering to the people making those rants is not good for SO, then we should not cater to them.

Comment: Failing who?  Take the CSS question I asked.  I had a question - two people answered - done.  We are all happy.  Who is that failing?

Comment: I know you don't care and that is exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Ole: "*Failing who?*" It's failing Stack Overflow's purpose. The purpose of SO is not to make the person who asked a question happy. It's not to make the person who answered the question happy. It's to create good and useful content for people who are *neither* the asker nor the answerer. Crap questions and answers that are useless to everyone except the people who posted them is not what this site is for.

Comment: @Ole: "*I know you don't care and that is exactly what is causing the problem.*" But... because I don't care, I also don't believe that what such people talk about represents a problem that needs solving.

Comment: That's great dude.

Comment: This was a good experiment.  I now know exactly how to fix this.

Comment: @NicolBolas : `It's been proven to be a bad thing. Twice. First, in SO's early days when subjectivity ran wild and quality was terrible` - It's a bad thing to have people discuss which is the best framework or library to do X. It's a good thing to have people suggest one or more frameworks that match a certain list of requirements. What SO SHOULD do, IMO, is prevent the former without restricting the latter. And yes, I know that's hard, bit preventing people from getting the help they NEED should not even be on the table IMO!

Comment: (continued) `Experience has taught us what questions produce good answers and what questions do not.` - Experience has taught me that many of SO's attempt to filter out the bad questions have unintended side-effects that make SO less effective as a Q&A website... which is the point I'm trying to make. I understand the reasoning behind those rules. I really do. However, I also notice how those same rules prevent people with urgent real world programming problems from getting the help they need... which should NOT be the case!

Comment: @Ole : In the comments of the other answer, someone said `we're a work of reference not an interactive tutorial site`. I think that sums up the problem quite well : this is a Q&A site that's being treated by those running it like a "work of reference". Even though this site relies heavily on the people doing the Q and the A, their interaction and experience as users is considered irrelevant. People come here to find help or they give help, but the owners treat it like it's something similar to Wikipedia. Basically, the goals of the users and those running the site don't match!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*Experience has taught me that many of SO's attempt to filter out the bad questions have unintended side-effects that make SO less effective as a Q&A website...*" You act like these rules are something new; they've been around for upwards of 7 years now. If getting rid of such questions were going to be a problem, you think we'd have seen the effects of it by now.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: "*Basically, the goals of the users and those running the site don't match!*" Nonsense. I am a user; I do not "run the site" in any way, shape, or form. But the community of users have come up with standards, and when I see questions that violate those standards, I use my abilities to enforce them. That doesn't mean I'm "running" anything. SO is community-policed, and the community that has created this site decided on these rules. The site's goals do not align with users seeking "help". SO is not a help desk, so people who want to treat it as such are frustrated. Tough luck.

Comment: @NicolBolas : `The site's goals do not align with users seeking "help"` - Exactly my point!! People come to this side to find help for a problem they're facing... or to help others with their problem. For some reason unclear to me, the SO elite likes to pretend that's not what this site is being used for... and that - IMO - is the main problem!

Comment: @JohnSlegers: People seeking help are a means to an end here; helping them is not the end unto itself. We only want people seeking help in such a way that it allows us to fulfill our goal of creating a knowledgebase. If you seek help in such a way that this won't happen, then helping you is not conducive to our goals. We seem to agree in principle, but disagree in effect. Help Vampires are a real problem, and we must do everything we can to keep them to an absolute minimum.

Comment: @JohnSlegers you split the arrow sitting in the bullseye.  `Even though this site relies heavily on the people doing the Q and the A, their interaction and experience as users is considered irrelevant. People come here to find help or they give help, but the owners treat it like it's something similar to Wikipedia. Basically, the goals of the users and those running the site don't match! `

Comment: So essentially it's like going to a restaurant, ordering the king crab, and asking if you can a little extra cajun on the side for your butter.  However the Chef is a purist and does not believe in Cajun in the butter, so Bon Appetite!

Comment: What makes it so fun is that that Chef is only there 1/10 of the time.  Most of the time you meet really great people with really amazing almost mindblowing amazing insight, like for example @BoltClock.

Comment: @Ole: You're seriously tilting at windmills here. The people you castigate for over moderation are the *same people* who provide good answers. They are the people who have made this site successful. The standards they promote are what has made this site great, and however much you believe that this is new, ***it isn't***. Why do you spend so much time arguing for allowing (more) bad questions, and so little time actually answering good ones?

Comment: Because all the articles you see are not about the good people providing the good answers.  The reason for the 1200+ upvotes (Before the post was locked - presumably to prevent more upvotes) on "Why is SO so negative as of late" is not because of good people providing good answers.  What you are doing is creating the business opportunity for someone to fill this void, and if you look at where monster is now, it's very clear that someone will fill the void.

Comment: The top 6 (Not top 6% - top 6) guy did not leave because everything was blue sky: http://smellsblue.blogspot.be/2008/10/why-reddit-is-better-than-stack.html

Comment: @Ole: "*'s very clear that someone will fill the void.*" Good luck to them. Go fill that void. SO has tried to handle such questions twice, and it *does not work*. I don't know why you keep ignoring that crucial fact, but there it is. I've seen Reddit, and it is filled with *trash*, just like OpenGL.org's forums, and many others. Help Vampires run rampant, and skilled professionals are quickly used up and flee. Just like the forum lifecycle.

Comment: No one is arguing for allowing bad questions.  There is already a voting system in place to take care of that.  What we are arguing against is the Watchmen who shut down and place on hold questions that the community has not even had a chance to evaluate yet, and even questions with 1200+ votes that are shut down for no reason.

Comment: Reddit is irrelevant because Google takes care of that.

Comment: @Ole: "*No one is arguing for allowing bad questions.*" The fact that you do not recognize that this is what you're doing is the problem. "*What we are arguing against is the Watchmen who shut down and place on hold questions that the community has not even had a chance to evaluate yet*" The "watchmen" you refer to ***ARE MEMBERS OF THE COMMUNITY!*** By closing such questions, they are "evaluating" them.

Comment: And we are not even arguing that there should not be a mechanism for improving the quality of posts.  What we are arguing for is a mechanism for user recourse when the improvement mechanism is abused.

Comment: @Ole: "*What we are arguing for is a mechanism for user recourse when the improvement mechanism is abused.*" And now we're back to arguing in circles. None of the stats you've proposed detects abuse. "Abuse" of VTC is *not* closing a question quickly; therefore, seeing who closes questions quickly tells you *nothing* about whether they are abusing their powers. Therefore, your proposal is pointless at solving the problem you believe exists.

Comment: Read "The Goal" or the "Haystack Syndrome" by Eliyahu Goldratt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_M._Goldratt).  Policies are tricky things and what you are doing is running the factory straight into the ground.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149428/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-ole).

Comment: Pretty good video for all the people that think they know what they are doing (Bret Victor - The Future of Programming): https://vimeo.com/71278954

Comment: I like his core summary argument:
"The most dangerous thought you can have as a creative person is to think that you know what you are doing.  Because once you think you know what you are doing you stop looking around for other ways of doing things and you stop being able to see other ways of doing things.  You become blind.  You become like these guys over here ..."