# Can I improve the low-quality question by changing all the text to a new question?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, post-ban, bad-questions

I read this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.

If I have a low-quality question, and there is a well-accepted answer, such as *[What's the difference between the `tree -L 1 /` with `tree -L 1`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365769)*, how do I improve it? Can I change all of the contents to a new question?

If not, then I can not think out of any idea to improve my question.

Comment: Edjting your question this way means invalidating the amswer you got. That is a big no-no.

Comment: _can I change all of the contents to a new question?_ **No.**

Comment: So, you mean this type question( base knowledge question ) can not be improved, right?

Comment: Why isn't this on https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Pang The link just a example, locate where do not matter to the question.

Comment: This is the meta for [so], **not** a generic place for meta questions for all [se] sites.

Answer (score 1):

### If your changes do not change the original intent of the question

As long as the original intent of the question still corresponds completely with your modified question, I don't see the problem. Or to put it differently: if all good answers to the original question would still be good answers you the improved one and vice versa, I don't see the problem.

Consider [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832572/pure-css-clickable-dropdown) (currently deleted):

> #### Pure CSS Dropdown That's Clickable?
>
> Anyone know if it's possible to implement a pure css dropdown that
>   does not use the hover event, but is instead clickable? Here's an
>   example from [w3c schools using the hover event](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp). I'd like the same
>   effect with pure css, however I'd also like it to be clickable in
>   order for the menu to come down. It has to be pure css though.

I changed it to the following, [after the author discussed his question getting deleted here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352225/does-stack-overflow-track-the-effect-of-moderator-policing/352325#352325):

> #### Pure CSS clickable dropdown?
>
> I learnt from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp) how to use the `:hover` pseudo-class
>   to style my HTML elements on hover and to how create a dropdown when I
>   hover over a particular element in pure CSS (= without using any
>   JavaScript).
>
> Is it possible to create the same dropdown as the one in the example
>   below, in pure CSS, but when clicking an element instead of when
>   hovering over it?
>
> I would prefer to use no JavaScript at all, or - if not possible
>   without JavaScript - as little JavaScript as possible. The items of
>   the drowndown should be clickable themselves.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```css
>  .dropbtn {
>      background-color: #4CAF50;
>      color: white;
>      padding: 16px;
>      font-size: 16px;
>      border: none;
>      cursor: pointer;
>  }
>
>  .dropdown {
>      position: relative;
>      display: inline-block;
>  }
>
>  .dropdown-content {
>      display: none;
>      position: absolute;
>      right: 0;
>      background-color: #f9f9f9;
>      min-width: 160px;
>      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
>      z-index: 1;
>  }
>
>  .dropdown-content a {
>      color: black;
>      padding: 12px 16px;
>      text-decoration: none;
>      display: block;
>  }
>
>  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
>
>  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
>      display: block;
>  }
>
>  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
>      background-color: #3e8e41;
>  }
> ```
>
> ```html
>  <div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
>    <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
>    <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
>      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
>      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
>      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
>    </div>
>  </div>
> ```

Now, I'm not saying we should do this with every question of questionable quality. After all, we don't want to encourage / reward laziness, do we?

However, if you think you have a valid reason for cleaning up a question and you can do so in a way that it doesn't invalidate good answers on the original question or change the actual intent of the question in any other way, I don't see a reason you shouldn't do it!

---

### If your changes do change the original intent of the question

Now, if you want to change the actual intent of the question, I do NOT think that's a good idea. This is especially the case if it's not your own question and/or there's already answers to that question that would be invalidated after your changes.

If this is not your own question, I would leave it as it is. If this *is* your own question - as in the case of the example you're giving - I would recommend just deleting your question if you feel uncomfortable with it, or adding an *update* section at the bottom of that question to clarify your position, but without changing the original content!