# Ephemeral questions

Tags: feature-request

To me, a very large percentage of (new?) questions seems to be of the kind where even if the question is legit, there's no way an answer will ever be helpful to anyone else except for the poster, and even to him for a very short while.

So, I'm thinking it'd be nice if it was possible to mark a question as ephemeral, meaning it would disappear/auto-delete after some time (1 week of no new upvotes on either the question or the answer? disable after 15 upvotes?).

It'd also be useful for all the beginner posts asking for help, where instead of shooting them down, people could help them (if they wanted, knowing there's no long-term rep to be gained), without invoking all the "questions like these will ruin/kill SO" feelings many seem to have?

What do you think?

Comment: That runs counter to the basic philosophy of the site, though: to build an (imperfect) archive of (more or less) unique questions, each of which, over time, (hopefully,) amasses the best possible answers and comments, serving as the best possible resource for that specific question, thus adding a small piece of real value in the sea of useless garbage that the Internet often is. I'm sure many of the experts donating their time here wouldn't be willing to do so in a forum where the only beneficiary is the asker - more often than not just a bozo too lazy to read the docs. I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: ["You have it backwards, I think..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601)

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, I realize that people have different priorities, but there seems to be an awful lot of activity where neither of the two is an expert you describe. I'm thinking this would be a much better way to moderate that activity than to basically insult people for daring to ask a question, which I see happen all the time.

Comment: @xs0 Care to provide an example of someone being "insulted" for daring to ask a question?  I'll call that bluff.

Comment: @Servy Well, not easily, because bad questions tend to get deleted very quickly. Will update next time I notice it.

Comment: @xs0 Sadly, bad questions *don't* get deleted all that quickly, at least often enough.  That's precisely the problem. (One that you're trying to make worse.)

Comment: @xs0 `but there seems to be an awful lot of activity where neither of the two is an expert you describe` I see your point, but I'm not sure it's enough of an argument to make SO something it's not trying to be. It could easily suck the lifeblood out of the place (because the worst question askers would start making ample use of the feature, and because reputation from content posted on an ephemeral question would have to be retained it would become a super duper rep mine for lazy answerers, actively discouraging the harder work of answering non-ephemeral stuff.)

Comment: I think this is counter-productive. What is not extremely relevant today may be the new "best practice" tomorrow.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I explicitly suggested no rep should be gainable by these questions (and their answers).. Or maybe implicitly :) But it's definitely there, in parentheses..

Comment: @xs0 that sounds like it would be more trouble than it's worth. Consider someone gaining rep for answering before the question is flagged as ephemeral. Not to mention people would start whining when they gain rep and it goes away 5 minutes later, once it has been flagged.

Comment: We already basically have this feature. Vote to close and/or downvote said question. If it doesn't fit a close reason, or isn't bad enough to downvote, it likely isn't ephemeral.

Comment: Not necessarily a bad idea... but why does it have to be on StackOverflow?

Comment: Well, with "opposition winning" by 15:1, it's probably not worth the time to continue arguing, I just thought it'd be useful to have something of a middle option between "excellent question" and "terrible question".. So what is the etiquette? Should I delete this or leave it?

Answer (score 8):

While you may have it backwards, I can see the frustration. But first, a bit of a disambiguation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6163683/1079354) at first blush looks like a beginner question, but it has proven to be valuable to me time and time again as I develop software:  **never assume.**

There are [lots of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877086/why-do-comparisons-with-integer-valueofstring-give-different-results-for-12/20877115#20877115) [other useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23852556/1079354) [examples out there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27598164/1079354) which aren't *as* silly, but are still just as valuable.  Any one of those questions could have been closed as "too beginner" or closed as a dupe (and in fact, the first one [actually *was* for a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20877086/timeline#history_2bc850a1-31fd-49d3-a020-6191b0c6df22) - genuinely in error).  The fact that they're still around means that people *have* found value in them and that they're *not* temporal.

I'd like to call this partial statement out:

> ...where instead of shooting [beginners] down, people could help them...

At *no point* do beginners get shot down.  What we shoot down are ***terrible*** questions.
Questions which don't show any research effort.
Questions which are just a code dump.
Questions which you wouldn't articulate someone in a hallway without getting puzzled looks.
Questions which are just too broad or too vast for us to even tackle.
Questions which aren't even questions at all.

It's no surprise that there is overlap between a beginner and a bad question, but not all beginners ask bad questions.  We only want to foster and nurture *good* questions here.  Making questions suddenly disappear seems incredibly counter to this.

Comment: Questions of value suddenly disappearing would indeed be bad. That's why the proposal includes an automatic disable, should the question actually see upvotes, contrary to expectations of those that thought it was ephemeral (including the OP).

Out of time for today, will say more tomorrow..

Comment: @xs0:  I fail to see what's wrong with the current system.  We have a system which automatically deletes old and uncared for questions.  We have users who have the power to vote to delete questions which really need it.  It's uncommon that anything of value is lost *today*.  Additionally, it's also uncommon that even the temporal questions which only really affect one individual are kept around for very long at all.  I'm not sure what your system is going to accomplish on top of what we've already got.

Comment: in 1 week it happened 3 times (to me) that a question was deleted while I was writing an answer and 2 times that a question was deleted beacuse it was "unclear what you're asking" even though it was clear (at least) to me, and I tried to help via comments.. But maybe my sample was just randomly really bad.. Anyhow, it'd be nice if the bad-question-haters instead tried to flesh out the OP's underlying confusion and turned the question into a good one, instead of just saying "terrible" and then leaving.. If a question goes away in as little as a few minutes, there's no chance to do so..

Comment: @xs0 _it'd be nice if the bad-question-haters instead tried to flesh out the OP's underlying confusion and turned the question into a good one_ Do you have any idea how much time that takes? Time that could be spent answering good questions? And I sometimes try to do that, but a lot of users don't _want_ any help formulating their question, but want it answered _right now_. (And questions going away a few minutes after they were asked - those must be exceptionally rare. Maybe they were deleted by the OP?)

Comment: @ModusTollens:  They're almost *always* deleted by the OP if it's that quick.  Basically it means that those questions weren't worth the time to answer.

Comment: @ModusTollens I'm totally not saying every question deserves that treatment, but some do have "goodness potential". E.g. the other day one was like "My library stopped working, I'm suddenly getting 409s" and it could've become a general "how to handle 409s / api limits" with an answer like "cache, queue or batch, it depends on ..." But, it's marked off-topic, because it's asking for debugging help and the OP didn't describe the desired behavior and provided no code? (I mean, really? it's unclear what the desired behavior is, and some random snippet of code is required for an answer here?? :)

Comment: @xs0 I had a similar case a few days back, but it went differently. A new user asked an unclear question. It got closed. I commented with what was missing. User edited their question, it got reopened, I answered. The system works ;)

Comment: Yeah, with the really huge number of questions in it, I think we each experience the site quite differently, because we each really see just a tiny fraction of it.

Comment: @ModusTollens One more thing occurred to me.. When you said - _Do you have any idea how much time that takes? Time that could be spent answering good questions?_ .. In other words, you want these excellent questions, expect the posters to invest "enough" time into producing them, but are definitely not willing to invest even a small amount of your own time to (help) raise the quality? What if killing bad questions is not really an efficient way to go at it in the first place? (and again, I don't mean 100% of bad questions, some are definitely totally worthless, spam, homework, etc etc.)

Comment: @xs0 No, that's wrong, I absolutely am investing my own time to help users raise the quality of their questions, it's what I do mostly at the moment because I enjoy it (when it works). It's what I am focusing on at the moment. But too often it does _not_ work, because users don't want the help and don't cooperate. Each time it does work I feel like celebrating because it's so rare. So what is efficient? Try to help, but close the question if it is bad. When the user cooperates and makes a good effort, reopen the question. Otherwise leave it closed. Problem solved.

Comment: @ModusTollens OK, then I misread what you were saying and good job! :) Still, it keeps on happening (to me) that questions go away "for reasons of moderation" before any realistic amount of time passes by, hence my suggestion - there seem to be many "trigger-happy" high-rep users, and imho giving them a "less lethal" tool might help in that respect.. I have no idea what would be efficient, but of the posts I've read on meta, two sentiments keep on being stated - "the SO system is great as-is" and "the question quality is getting worse and worse". But together, they're a contradiction, I think?

Answer (score 3):

One more reason why it is bad idea for SO: right now it requires some effort to clean up one's cheating on homework/exam/competition. Having questions that automatically disappear would invite and encourage posting from people who only care to get answer and not to get caught as they no longer would need to come back and delete they posts if there is no answers.

Comment: Questions like these are very rarely actually good questions worth keeping.  It's far more important to focus on keeping questions because they're actually of value and will be helpful to people than because you want to spite someone for askinging an extremely low quality question about their homework/competition/etc.  It hurts the community way more to try to keep these bad questions around than we gain from trying to spite them in the hopes that they get caught.

Comment: @Servy I was trying to point out that lack of *guaranteed prompt removal* of bad posts serves as a speed bump (even if very minor) for people posting such questions. If we promise to remove bad, unanswered questions in 3-5 days we'd essentially welcome "do my homework" posts from single-use accounts...