# Typo in New PluralSight Blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, typographical-error

Small thing I noticed on the [second line of the new blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/06/pluralsight-stack-overflow-helping-worlds-developers-learn-new-skills/?cb=1). it reads:

> Stack Overflow’s mission has always been ***the*** help the world’s developers

Should this be "to"? Double FHC with arrow for style:

[image]

not a huge issue, but it was the first thing I noticed..

Comment: Stack Overflow's mission has always been the free hand circles, they probably just missed a few words while merging that mission with the other good sounding fluff in the paragraph about helping the world's developers.

Comment: @DavyM they must've missed it [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/16/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal) I say we vote for an amendment?

Answer (score 3):

We'll fix it now. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: this has been fixed. Should this be tagged with `status-completed`?