# What is gained from closing out questions if they aren't asked perfectly?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I just spent significant time writing a detailed response to a perfectly valid newbie question. The question wasn't asked perfectly, but it was absolutely clear what the newbie was asking and what is problem was.

In the time I spent preparing an answer, which involved writing code to test everything I was doing, someone decided that because the question wasn't asked well enough, he was just going to close it.

To what end? Who is served? I get it. We punish the people who don't ask their questions to standards. That's really friendly to newbies and teaches them what a warm, friendly place StackOverflow is.

It also punishes people who spend time preparing answers. It tells us that, at the whim of who knows whom, our time writing careful answers can be made worthless. We can't post the reply.

Why in the world would we continue to spend more than a few seconds writing lengthy responses to reasonable questions if someone else is going to close them out. I now have a horrible taste in my mouth. (In other words: I'm angry at having my time wasted when I was trying to be helpful.) I'll be taking a break from answering questions. And maybe I'm far from a top performer here, but should that matter?

What is served by closing out answers if they aren't asked perfectly? What is served by removing my ability to answer it anyway?

In this case, it was a perfectly valid question. The guy wanted to know why he couldn't create a in C++ a std::vector. He didn't provide code, but he provided enough info it was clear what was wrong.

I didn't need code to know what he was doing. But someone decided "tough".

Done for a while.

What is served?

Comment: Fix the question and reopen it. It'l only take 3 people to agree with you that it needs to be reopened.

Comment: Closing isn't about punishing. It's about ensuring that the question gets edited before answers start rolling in. If you understand what is being asked, great! Edit the question *first* (before answering it) to clarify it for others. Because if others extract a different interpretation from an unclear question, then you'll end up with a bunch of answers that will be invalidated by a subsequent edit, and that's confusing for everyone.

Comment: Validity isn't a quality metric.  It doesn't matter how legitimate the problem the asker is having; what matters is if the question meets our standards.  If it does, then it can stay.  We're serving the greater audience of everyone who comes after the asker, not just the asker themselves.  While it's understandable that it feels like wasting your time to try to answer those questions, I applaud you attempting to help contribute to the library of knowledge we're trying to build.

Comment: For context, [this seems to be the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220328/cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-c-error-happens-when-i-try-to-create-a-v).

Comment: I'm surprised that question isn't closed as a dupe.

Comment: I haven't looked at the,question, but so many developers manage to create a std::vector<> just fine?

Comment: Does your chewing gum lose it's flavour on the bedpost overnight?

Comment: @fbueckert - I hope not... extremely basic  https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+vector+abstract+class … gives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160920/why-cant-we-declare-a-stdvectorabstractclass. I can't see why Joseph would so blatantly answer duplicate which already have decent explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

Comment: You could have posted a skeleton of an answer quickly, then improve the question quickly, then test your code and extend the answer, then polish the question and vote for reopen if it got closed in the meantime. That's what I do if I think the question is underrated. Doesn't happen often though.

Comment: I typed too quickly -- he was trying to create a std::vector of an abstract class, which you can't do.

Comment: @Trilarion I didn't think the question was underrated, but I didn't want to leave a poor answer for people to see and give me a hard time about.

Comment: Anyway -- don't worry about it. Clearly, I'm the only one who has a problem with this. I'll shut up (and stop answering questions).

Comment: @Trilarion What you describe is a blatant, knowing abuse of the system. I have suspended more than one user who I caught posting "skeleton"/"placeholder" answers on questions that they knew were about to be closed. Don't do it. Instead, do as I suggested in my comment above and *edit the question **first***.

Comment: @CodyGray Are you sure that we mean the same with skeleton? Editing the question first or second is not so important in my opinion as long as both gets done.

Comment: I've never been a big fan of FGITW, but what I'm talking about is intentionally submitting "placeholder" answers to get around the inability to answer once the question is closed. If you *know* that the question is going to get closed, then you shouldn't be answering it. You should either be fixing the problem that's motivating closure, or you should just move on. The order in which you do things *does* matter. I cannot think of a single reason why you would not edit first, other than a selfish attempt to grab reputation. @Trilarion

Comment: @CodyGray Hmm, you talk about placeholder answers but that's not what I said or meant. I really admit that this is grey zone territory but so it is for you too. What's the difference between an answer and a placeholder answer? I didn't meant the latter but it seems not to have become clear unfortunately and I can't change it now. Second is knowing that questions get closed. That's a bit tricky and involves future telling as skill to be really sure. I don't want to dwell on the whole thing, but just want to express that I couldn't care less about rep. I'm really not here because of it.

Answer (score 12):

*Who is served?* Well, some people in the future:

[image: another brilliant xkcd: wisdom of the ancients]

<sub>[source: xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/)</sub>

If we close/remove not so well asked questions, it is easier for future visitors to find the well asked (and thus well answered) ones. I know it is hard to *not help the person asking*, but by doing that, we help *all the other people with the same question arriving here in the future*. We focus our time on the questions that will help more than one person.