# Only asked one question about one topic but closed because it needs focus on one question/problem only?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question, [Simplify a Repeating Regex Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65054703/4703819), was closed because it apparently needs to be more focused.

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

**There is *only one* issue/question being asked** and it can basically be stated as "Here is my regex. I would like to simplify it but don't know how."  I even stated that I don't know/have the correct terminology so a flag as a dupe would be fine.  In other words: **I don't know what I don't know, but a point in the right direction is more than welcome.**

Comment: *"To me, this site is about helping people"* -- and this may be a problem because the main goal of the site is not specifically this but rather to provide a high-quality, high signal/low noise Q/A site. Yes, posters often do get help here, but that is a wonderful side effect from members fulfilling the main objective. Usually, if code works but needs to be improved, then those sorts of questions are asked on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t just edit the question and remove the commentary then flag the comments as not being necessary?  In your own question you stated you don’t have a problem

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not entirely sure this would be accepted at the Code Review site. But I am also not sure why it cannot be accepted here. It's a bit silly to force users to make a contrived failed attempt. Even if it's working, simplifying it is a programming problem, no?

Comment: Edit the question *how* @SecurityHound?  I didn't say "I have no problem."  I said "this is how I got it working, but I would like to know how to simplify it and I don't know how"  I have one comment clarifying my question.  What is not clear about it?

Comment: I think this is too narrow for Code Review, and I don't see anything wrong with asking it here on SO.

Comment: A lot o people using Needs Focus as a stand-in for "Weak question." or "shows too little effort." Kind of annoys me because I like the close reason to make sense. I don't think it makes sense here. Whether this is or isn't a good question I can't comment on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But that's usually for questions of the "I have this working code, does it need improving?" variety, right? Are questions like, "I have this solution but it's unacceptable for X/Y/Z reasons, is there an alternative?" not allowed?

Comment: @Allan - By hitting the edit button.  Your first edit after the closure would throw the question into a review queue to be reopened

Comment: ["You have it backwards, I think..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601)

Answer (score 5):

Gonna be honest: I'm not seeing much to fix in this one besides *maybe* an example of what you tried to simplify the regex to.

As a passerby with little stake in regex questions but a sizeable stake in question quality overall, I'm struggling to see why this should remain closed. Someone who's more versed in regex can weigh in but I'm not seeing much merit to the closure.

Answer (score -5):

It technically **does** need to be more focussed - it makes use of the "X/Y" (I know how to do X, so I ask about a solution to X which is Y) where one asks about a solution rather than an answer.

Comment: How should it be phrased then?

Comment: In general, one should not ask questions like that. If they found a solution by themselves, they should find a way to simplify it themselves as well.

Comment: But they can't.. which is why they ask. As previously mentioned it is silly to force users to make a contrived failed attempt just to post a Question. Who has use for that? Also, what is the X-part and the Y-part of the problem? A normal "X/Y" problem is when a users asks for a regex to solve a problem where the solution should use something entirely different. I do not see that here.

Comment: @Scratte how is 'simplify my regex' useful for future visitors though? It's a very specific problem you can't really Google for the same, no? Not saying the close *reason* is the right one. But I do question how this question helps the overall goal, considering searchability

Comment: @Patrice The title mentions "repeating regex pattern". I'm not convinced it's entirely useless. If I had to create one that finds a repeating pattern, I think that's the keywords I'd use.

Comment: The XY argument here is pretty weak.  They have *a* solution that works already but they want a way to simplify that solution.  They lack the simple version.  XY would imply that they have the simple solution already and they're asking about issues with *that* as opposed to the actual issue, which is "how to simply this more complex regex".