# What should I do with an obviously low-quality question that I can't close because it does not match any close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was reviewing the question queue, and this question was being closed as "too broad": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725002/outputting-a-string-arraylist-to-a-jtextarea .

It is obvious that this question is not really valuable, and should be closed, but I couldn't find any reasonable close reason:

- I don't think this is a duplicate (at least short search didn't find anything).
- It has information to diagnose the problem, can be reproduced, and is not too broad, as I know what OP is asking about.
- It's not opinion based.

So I clicked: "Leave Open", but I have second thoughts.

So the question is what should I do in this case.

**EDIT**:

Here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725508/how-to-read-text-file-and-output-the-information-in-a-tabular-format .

OP is posting a question about how to write a simple program; he has (according to the question) no programming experience, however all points to earlier question apply.

Comment: Poor quality questions that cannot be closed should be down voted.

Comment: just thinking... a question like "how much riboflavin is contained in tomatoes?" is clearly off-topic... but what is it's close reason? its not about general computer hardware or software. its not about professional servers or networking infrastructure. it doesn't lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem - because there is no problem. its not a problem that cannot be reproduced. it doesn't ask for a tool recommendation or favourite off-site resource. and it doesn't belong to another site in the stack exchange network I think. - how would one flag that question?

Comment: @Michael it might belong on: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @jb. haha.... ;)

Comment: @jb. the cooking site says that questions about "General health, diet, and nutritional topics" are off-topic. so thats not an option :-(

Comment: If I go over the flowchart here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216192/158100  I tend to choose No on the first step, hence 'Unclear' for your second example I choose Too Broad...

Comment: Possibly related: [What should the table stakes for a question to be asked on Stack Overflow be?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254766/456814).

Comment: @Michael: You can mark a question as off-topic even if there's no SE site it would belong to.  Use the custom reason.  `This question is off-topic because it is about the chemical composition of flora.  StackOverflow is for questions about computer code.'  Done.  Although in fact that one probably is on-topic on Chemistry.SE (on topic, but too low quality unless it says something about what strain of tomato, type of soil, ripeness, I don't know everything that could affect it)

Comment: @BenVoigt I think there are more close-reasons if you have more rep. I see 6 off-topic reasons, how many do you see? They are: general computing hardware/software. server/networking. lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. a typo. recommend or find a tool. belongs to another SE-site. So for me, there is no custom close-reason.

Comment: @Michael: Based on your rep, I see you're not closing, you are flagging.  There's a difference.  I believe all close reasons are available from the moment that you acquire the "vote to close" privilege.  Since you are flagging, if none of the pre-written reasons apply, use a custom flag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the first instance bad questions should be down-voted.

Secondly, if you really think a bad question should be closed, then:

> "Unclear what you are asking"

would seem to be the most appropriate close reason.

If that doesn't sit well, just select "off Topic > Other" and enter your own custom close reason.

Comment: Note in passing that sometimes we tend to put a not-so-subtle humorous note in custom close reasons. That might work, but personal experience lends me to recommend being *straight* and *clear* in such instances.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, There are the close reasons listed and there is a custom reason which you need to search for and type free text for the most common "low quality" reason. reasonable...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how does it make sense. The question is poor and should have not being asked and so downvote it all the way to hell, so why not closing it and possibly deleting it and get rid of the low quality noise in the system? I honestly can't understand what's going on here lately.

Comment: @gdo, I honestly tried but still do not understand your comment. Are you referring to the literal `if you really think a bad question should be closed`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your first case is close-worthy. Not a great question, but not close-worthy. I'm saying this while recognizing that opinions may differ, and I'm quite rusty with Java so maybe someone who uses Java day in and day out would could convince me otherwise.

The second case is quite close-worthy. It is not okay to post a question on SO where the information which is central to the question is made available only at the end of a link. In the question that you've linked to here, the input and output formats are both necessary to answering the question but they are not in the body of the question. I usually close these as "unclear what you are asking." (There may be *other* good reasons to close it but I select the close reason which requires the least interpretation on my part.)

In other cases, you may need to use a custom close reason and be prepared to live with being challenged about it if you are a little too creative with your reason. One common case I've encountered where I chose a custom close reason is when someone asks a question which is primarily a legal one.

Comment: Well first case is a problem that my students struggle with, this question is really about: how to concatenate a list of strings to single string. So this is a problem that any java programmer should cope with. Not really sure whether this is a proper close reason.

Comment: First case should be closed, and now is. It's a simple off-by-one error.

Answer (score 3):

From the given question:

> for some reason it is not the rest of the code works properly.

'Not working' is, generally speaking, not a good problem description. So 'me have de kodez, me work not' questions are good candidates for **Unclear what you're asking**.

There's also a nice Off-Topic reason:  **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. This one is good when it's clear what the OP is asking (fix de kodez 4me), but it lacks the information what a particular problem does the OP has. No information what error there is, what is the difference between expected and actual output, no minimal example.

If it seems that the OP lack basic programming skills and even the simplest things can be a potential problem, I'd give **too broad** because the answer would have to be a programming tutorial.